# Could high-rep users help with clearing comment flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, flags, comments

I have to start this question with a simple assumption: there are a lot of comment flags raised by users:

> We get a lot of comment flags. A lot. We see a lot of comments. We delete comments all the time.

I also realise that clearing comment flags is, probably, one of the easier mod-tasks that exist, given that:

> [moderators] get two [practical] choices when a comment is flagged:
>
> - Delete
> - Dismiss (do nothing)

<sub>Both quotes from George Stocker's answer here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278823/82548</sub>

Now, despite that this is a relatively easy and quickly-handled task there may be no need for this feature-request; I would argue that the simple emphasis, and repetition of, 'a lot' in the above quote suggests that reducing the comment-flag queue would be of benefit, simply because:

1. It would reduce some of the workload on the mods (a simple task performed 'a lot' of times should be distributed further, if possible),
2. It would free moderators up to deal with other, more serious, flags and problems.

Point 2, of course, could be countered by the simple fact that moderators may regard the flag-queue as a break, or light-relief, from the 'more serious' flags; but I'd still like us to be able to help, if possible.

My thoughts on this, in terms of limitations, would be:

1. A flag should be raised by another user before that comment can be deleted by a high-rep (non-moderator) user, in order to prevent us simply deleting comments with which we disagree.
2. In the event that a flagged comment is part of a conversation that (we feel) should be addressed, we should flag those other comments; we should not be (at least in the short term) be able to nuke the whole thread.
3. Any comment-based action that we take should be available for review (by moderators only, or peers as well) and, ideally, reversible (at the very least a comment that we agree to delete should be un-delete-able).

This list could surely do with expanding, I'd imagine.

As to the level of rep required to have delete powers over comments, I'd suggest it should be high; perhaps >50k; and ideally for those users with a sufficiently high ratio (perhaps in the region of 9:1, so a 90% accuracy?) of 'helpful' to 'declined' flags; on the premise that a history of accurately raising flags should demonstrate an understanding of what should, and should not, be flagged and deleted.

With regards to BoltClock's comment (below):

> Remember that it takes no more than 3 comment flags on any single comment to cause it to be deleted without moderator intervention. A lot (lol) of these flags resolve themselves fairly quickly.

I hadn't forgotten, but while this clears many problems very quickly, I know I occasionally come across offensive comments on relatively old questions/answers, which may not attract flags as quickly as a new question that gets to sit on the front page for a few minutes.

This request is to supplement the existing strategies/solutions, not to replace them.

Further, to address Sunshine's comment (again, below):

> Comments are sensitive and situations decline rapidly in comments. It's better if mods handle such sensitive disruptive content, instead of high-rep users.

I disagree, the reason that 'situations decline rapidly in comments,' I suspect (I have no statistics to back this up, it's purely an assumption) is because while the initiating comments may be flagged by one or two users, the lack of a third flag leaves those comments in sight for some time because of the small number of moderators versus the giant stack of comment-flags.

I have only one data-point to refer to, and that's based on my raising a flag, at 02:00, December 10<sup>th</sup>, and the closure of the question (and deletion of comments, which I'd flagged), by bluefeet, at 11:08; giving a turn-around time of over eight hours (in this one, statistically-irrelevant, data-point).

So, for eight hours a deteriorating situation can exist without review, until such a time as the question is seen by others and third-flags are cast. With community-members participating, this seems unlikely to happen.

Similarly, while moderators have greater authority, and power, over the community we, the community, should be willing to participate in our own governance. And it's important to remember that when a comment is flagged (as whatever) we are not simply a rubber-stamp for that comment's deletion, we should be able to dismiss flags (or skip, as in the review queues).

Comment: Remember that it takes no more than 3 comment flags on any single comment to cause it to be deleted without moderator intervention. A lot (lol) of these flags resolve themselves fairly quickly.

Comment: Comments are sensitive and situations decline rapidly in comments. It's better if mods handle such sensitive disruptive content, instead of high-rep users.

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138149/

Comment: While I am all for helping the mods with stuff like this, how would it handle when multiple comments need to be deleted?  Removing one bad comment that got flagged and sparked a whole thread just leaves a bunch of really confusing comments without context lying around.  Would we allow people to clean up entire threads?  Do we trust one person to do that?  If we need more than one, how do we come to a consensus of what gets burninated and what stays?  I like the premise of the idea, but I feel like it needs to be fleshed out a bit more before we can see how useful it would be.

Comment: @Becuzz The same thing happens now. We get flags on single comments not the whole thread and unless we feel it's necessary we don't go to the post to clean up everything.

Comment: @Becuzz: I don't know, honestly; I stayed away from requesting that a flag one comment should open up the whole of that comment thread for review/deletion by users. I think it *should*, but not with sufficient surety to request it.

Comment: @bluefeet Ok, so question 1 is is that the way we want to handle things?  Should we just look at the flagged comment or should we open it up to having someone mod the entire thread?  If it is the latter, I am wondering how that would work and what the potential consequences are of whichever way it goes.

Comment: @Becuzz Moderating the entire comment thread is a totally different story, I'd limit the request to the comments flagged at first.  If comments are removed from the thread and then it appears to be "obsolete", the other comments could also be flagged.

Comment: @bluefeet That sounds good.  I would hope that the tool would ask you after voting to delete if any other comments need to be flagged as obsolete.  Then if the deletion happens, the flags would go into effect and those would get taken care of thru the same mechanisms.

Comment: Moderator tools come in at 10K.  It would be great to see the `Not Constructive`, `Obsolete` and `Too Chatty` be handled by that community.

Comment: There's too much comment deletion. That's the actual problem.

Comment: Non-moderator users would need an option to 'pass the buck to a moderator' for situations that really do need moderator intervention (possible account suspension, etc).  Also, it is not clear whether a non-moderator could clean up several comments in a single question if only one is flagged (but the commentary indicates that a whole slew of comments need attention), whereas moderators can, I believe, do that.  (The second issue was also raised earlier by @becuzz, I see.)

Comment: I'm for this proposal because it would mean more oversight of comment flag handling, _not_ **not** ***not*** because I think comments need to be deleted more efficiently.

Comment: 50K would be too high for this, however.

Comment: @lpapp: perhaps, I'm open to negotiation on that; what sort of level would you prefer? The goal of 50k was purely to ensure that comments were handled by those that have a pretty certain investment in the site, and not open to the same robo-reviewers as the various other queues (though I freely admit that >50k users remain imperfect, and fallible).

Comment: My first thoughts were 20, 25 or 30 maximum.

Answer (score 79):

Please and thank you.

There are very few comments that actually **need** a diamond moderator's intervention:

- Abusive (rude or offensive) comments (or a pattern of abusive comments)
- Custom Comments asking that the thread be nuked

Most everything else we see:

- Not constructive
- Obsolete
- Chatty

Can (and should) be handled by the community.

One of the issues that keeps comment moderation from being turned over to the community is that once comments are deleted, we can no longer easily find them.

We do have the ability to see deleted comments by a user, but as @BoltClock points out, it is un searchable, unwieldy, and utterly devoid of context.

I think this is a great idea -- this should not be on the moderator's plate alone, and we should only be involved when we'd need to take an action more than simply deleting the flagged comment.

To make this happen, we'd first need better tooling regarding deleted comments to have evidence towards abusive behavior.  It'd also be nice if a custom flag was raised for moderator attention when a user has a high number of community flagged and deleted comments.

Comment: There's also looking at the user's full list of comments (mod-only, not the activity tab), but without a way to search or filter it's as good as useless.

Comment: "we'd first need to be able to see deleted comments in a user's profile" - if that's implemented, I hope there is a way for the user to view their own deleted comments. It's fairly annoying to have them disappear without a trace and without having any indication that anything was removed. It also does not serve to teach the user "don't post this kind of comment" - many people probably don't even realize it when one of their comments is deleted. Of course that might also be a good thing as it reduces the amount of complaints over deletion...

Comment: @BoltClock Are you thinking of after we delete the comment, what shows up in our mod activity page? I'm not sure where you're referencing.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker We can access about 500 of the last comments made by a user via mod-only tools.

Comment: @l4mpi Until users get the ability to see their own deleted posts (time-independent) in their profile, I doubt very much anyone at SE Inc will spring for letting users see their own deleted comments.

Comment: @bluefeet: Actually, we can access all of them. It's paginated by 500. (See what I mean by useless? You don't even realize it's paginated!)

Comment: @BoltClock I guess I've never needed to go through the pages of comments. I normally check recent ones only.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If this were implemented we'd also need to be able to see a history of the comments flagged for a user, similar to how we can see which posts there flagged.

Comment: @George Stocker: Yes. You *can* filter between deleted and not deleted, but that's the furthest you can go. (Also, the fact that we can see all of a user's deleted comments isn't really a secret - it's the content that should be kept private.)

Comment: Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145991/allow-moderators-to-edit-delete-comments-directly-from-the-comment-moderation-pa

Comment: Based on the comments on this answer, I think a comprehensive guide to moderator tools and features available somewhere for moderators would not be remiss.

Comment: They'd also need to get that new review queue for flags going. I don't think they have any intentions of bringing back that ratty old 10k flags queue to process these.

Comment: Gotta remember that it is the high rep users who can be very prone to actually writing bad comments (personal experience) so it would have to be some very good tooling

Comment: @Sammaye: you raise a good point, I'm well aware that my own style of commenting can be more, or less, useful depending on the time, and events, of any given day; others are, I suppose, equally susceptible. That's the primary reason, though, that I specified that we should not be able to delete comments as we wish, but only those that are first flagged by another user. Although I agree that it's a relatively minimal safeguard.