# Should you flag a comment on a post you just flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags

I just flagged a question as too broad. It had a comment that I thought could be flagged as well.

Flagging a comment means someone is going to check that comment at one point. Assuming the flag is deemed helpful (if I did not assume this, I would not flag it of course), should I just spare someone the effort and not flag the comment? Or would it be better to flag it anyway?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should flag the comment too. As long as the comment fits one of the reasons for it needing to be flagged, that is.

For example, if you see some trash on the sidewalk, and there is a trash can 10 feet away, what would you do?  Just leave it there since someone else is likely to walk along the sidewalk and take care of it? Or maybe just do it yourself?

Comment: I do not think the analogy is completely fair. If the question is removed, the comment will be as well, right? So why have two people look at it instead of one?
It would be like calling someone for a bin that is full, and someone else for the trash thats underneath it. Seems a waste of resources to me.

Comment: @g_m There is no guarantee the question will be removed. It's very more likely that the question will never be removed. Closing a question doesn't remove it from the site. Only under certain circumstances, does a closed question get deleted.

Comment: And what about the comment?

Comment: Ok, so a lot of helpfully flagged questions will not be deleted, just closed. And not acceptable comments do get deleted more often. So flagging both the question ánd the comment would be desirable because of this. If that is correct that is the information I was looking for.

Comment: @g_m Yes, this is correct. Even if the question is eventually deleted, it can take a lot more time than just getting closed. If the comment needs to be removed for a different reason, it's a good idea to flag it separately. Sometimes mods don't even read the whole question that was flagged, much less all the comments. ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard are you saying that there needs to be mod audit questions, to see if you're robo-modding?

Comment: @ChrisBaker: I think it is mod audit for responding to comment flags that might be needed.  Or maybe it is already there… Only moderators and 'team' would know. And auditing might be more important if [high-rep users are allowed to help with comment moderation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278927/could-high-rep-users-help-with-clearing-comment-flags/278928#278928), as suggested earlier this week.