# Does raising flags annoy the people who process them?

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation

Asking after not finding an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts or [Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq), or here on meta, among other places:

I recently flagged a few posts that were blatantly off-topic and recalled there were actually badges related to that (first, 80, and 500).  I think cutting down the signal-to-noise ratio would be good, but I don't have the reputation points to vote to close or mark as potential duplicate.  As there are a lot of duplicate, or otherwise in need of help, questions, and 80 or 500 seems like a LOT of flags, it occurred to me to ask:

**Does raising flags annoy the <strike>moderators</strike> people who process them?**

I'm not a hall monitor or badge whore (it seems like an "I'm telling mom" badge to me); I'm just curious, because it seems like adding to someone else's workload.  OTOH, I don't want to *not* take any action because [someone else will flag it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility)

*On edit:* I was notified in comments that flags are generally an issue handled by higher-reputation points users rather than moderators.  I think I'll have to revisit the "privileges" page to see if I can determine which flags go to whom.  If there is content that summarizes the process or flow I'd like to know more about it (I've recently become more active on Stack Overflow, so it would behoove me to know this stuff).

Comment: Note that many flags don't go to moderators (close flags for instance). Comment, Spam, Offensive, and especially "Other" flags do go to them though.

Comment: I did not know that (about who flags go to).  I will adjust my question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not a mod, so I can't say definitively, but I would assume not.  Handling flags is a core responsibility of a mod.  If you get annoyed by it, then you should not be a mod in the first place.

Comment: @iCodez Agreed, though recent meta discussions indicate that they do not appreciate mass flagging of old questions based on SE Data Explorer queries.

Comment: You do have to realize that we *volunteer* to do this. If we were annoyed by handling flags, we wouldn't be very good moderators.

Comment: @Bradley, indeed, as any human being whose job is to monitor flags would, then again the questioner did not say *mass-raising flags*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Totally, just trying to point out the one instance I can think of where they have been "annoyed" (though that would be a poor word choice) at a flag (or series of flags) being raised.

Comment: @animuson It's possible that we are just crazy.

Comment: I dunno, @BradletDotNET; annoyed seems like a good word for that!

Comment: Finally, the truth @bluefeet ;)

Comment: A nice place to know about this stuff is the [tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

Comment: A flag processor being annoyed by processing a flag would be equivalent to being annoyed with the dinner *you* **chose** to have tonight.

Answer (score 29):

> Does raising flags annoy the <strike>moderators</strike> people who process them?

## No!!

...and yes; sometimes <sup>1</sup>.

If your flags are intended to keep the site clean, lean, and mean; if they are in the spirit of community moderation (of which diamond moderators are only one part); if they are being found to be 'helpful' the large portion of the time...

*Never, ever, feel even a moment's hesitation in flagging. We love you!*

The "levels" of users above you who handle your flags are volunteering to do it. You are saving them the task of having to dig and find that stuff - by just raising a flag when you come across it, naturally.

So please; keep it up! Unless you start to see a pattern of your flags being declined, don't think twice.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sometimes, people will consistently flag 'improperly'. Those do annoy us, but they are taken care of.

Comment: I think you have your **Yes** and **No** reversed. :)

Comment: @bluefeet I think you misspelled, *"You are terribly awesome and I want to know how to most quickly transfer all of my worldly possessions into your name!"*

Comment: @AndrewBarber Do only diamond moderators handle flags on answers?

Comment: @2501 not all of them. Most go through review queues, first. However, the "other" flags only go to diamond moderators.

Comment: "they are taken care of" (dun dun dun) \*walks out of the room like a badass\*

Comment: "Never, ever, feel even a moment's hesitation in flagging. We love you!" Except when the flag type is other, not an answer, or very low quality.

Answer (score 7):

Not being a diamond moderator, I can't say for sure, but given that their job is basically to handle flags, it's a fair guess to say they aren't annoyed by you raising one :).

All comment flags (related feature request: [Could high-rep users help with clearing comment flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278927/could-high-rep-users-help-with-clearing-comment-flags)), as well as Spam, Offensive, and "Other" flags are handled by diamond moderators. (Spam and Offensive *may* go into the very-low quality queue (VLQ) as well.)

For the other flags (VLQ, [NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/not-an-answer/info), and Close), it's *great* that you are raising them. By raising a flag you are helping higher-reputation points users know what content needs to be moderated. Specifically, these flags  go into the review queues, so the community can handle them.

Note that a VLQ or NAA flag goes to a moderator if the post was accepted/positively scored and marked for deletion by the community.

Comment: it is worth noting that there are over 30,000 users eligible to review VLQ/NAA flags (2K rep), and over 20,000 ones with privileges sufficient to review close flags (3K). Rather hard to annoy few tens thousands "moderators". For the sake of completeness, this has almost happened to close flags, but that's because SE team initially failed to figure [the right way to serve these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/839601)