# Close reason: Unclear to whom?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

> [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
>
> Why should this question be closed?
>
> unclear what you're asking
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to
>   Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help
>   clarifying this question.

---

[Samuel Liew♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew), a moderator, closed this question, [Confusion about a Go for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412970), using "unclear what you're asking" as the reason.

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Nick, Samuel Liew♦

I would like to know why.

I have answered questions, where the OP has accepted and upvoted my answer and others have upvoted my answer too, and the questions have stiil been closed as unclear. Unclear to whom? So I'm asking a moderator to clarify the Stack Overflow meaning of unclear.

The specific question, that I'm using as an example, had problems. The question was written by a first-time contributor and a member since today. The question was probably not wriiten by a native English speaker; I revised it. The Go code snippet was posted as JavaScript; I converted it to Go. The Stack Overflow interface is confusing.

The question is quite ordinary; something programmers ask all the time. You encounter a snippet of code, wriiten by someone else or yourself a long time ago, that is hard to follow. After a while, if you are stuck, you ask other knowledgable and experienced programmers for help.

The question was crystal clear to me, so I provided a basic answer as a comment and voted to reopen.

The person who asked the question is unlikely to find Stack Overflow a welcoming place. Moderators are expected to set an example.

Comment: You know, apart from this question I have to say that I am getting _extremely_ annoyed by meta questions about moderation decisions mentioning "SO not being welcoming". Can we _please_ drop that? Moderation is _not an indicator of friendliness_ in any way.

Comment: @ModusTollens It's legit to ask for a clarification on why posts were closed/reopened/deleted in some cases, regardless of whether the community or a moderator took the action.

Comment: @Maroun Of course it is, it is one of the official ways to ask for moderation clarification. But it is not ok to assume unfriendliness or malicious intent from moderators, as the last paragraph implies. (Moderators are human, too, they can make mistakes and there are paths to correct mistakes - like this one.)

Comment: "*Moderators are human, too*" - My life is a lie! Aren't they unicorns??

Comment: @Maroun Well, they're unicorns when they're doing everything right. They're human when they make mistakes. The reason for this is in order to wear the [paper bag of shame](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375270/7795130), the horn really gets in the way.

Comment: @ModusTollens your assertion is wrong. The last paragraph does not "assume" unfriendliness nor malice. The OP is in his right to ask, if that "annoys you extremly", well...

Comment: @bad_coder "_The OP is in his right to ask_" - That's exactly what I wrote in my second comment. That does not annoy me, on the contrary. Please read my comments again. I just disagree with the last paragraph. Your point of view can be different, of course. (There is a bit of history here. Moderation has repeatedly been seen as unfriendly and not welcoming. I just disagree. )

Comment: @ModusTollens one of the best posts I've read on SE and that I wholeheartedly subscribe -regarding "unwelcoming" and "unfriendly"- is this one (please consider it, as it is indeed highly representative, although perhaps going in counter-cycle against the predominant power discourse). Cheers :) : https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/

Comment: @bad_coder Yeah I read that, not reading it again. Don't care about all the drama. But thanks for the link. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 11):

Before [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54412970/revisions), the question was indeed unclear.

Now the question is clear, but it's not being "specific". It's not hard to convince others that it's one of those "why my code doesn't work" questions. I think the question should be closed, maybe not for being unclear, but it's a little bit vague for me.

As for the first time contributor, we can be more friendly by commenting what exactly is not clear, or what should be improved in order to get better help.

Comment: We *can* comment about what exactly is not clear, but it should be noted that we are under no obligation to do so.  There's just so many questions that need closing that trying to comment on them takes far more time than is necessary.

Comment: "but it's a little bit vague for me" That makes it unclear...that's precisely the close reason to use when something is vague.

Comment: @fbueckert *we are under no obligation to do so.* --> IMO, you should be. The flag notice starts with  "Add details and clarify the problem being solved.". This is a call to action. So the OP should be told which details are missing or are unclear.

Comment: Take this active example:     https://stackoverflow.com/q/63716888/. I'm a maintainer of the project and there is no ambiguity or missing details in the Q. I diagnosed the issue in comments a few days back, and today I find that a couple of voters with apparently no experience in this domain (based on their popular tags and null results for keyword search of their activity) have closed the Q as 'unclear'. There aren't many active posters for this project and so it's unclear if there will be enough votes to reopen it, besides mine.

Comment: @Gyan I've noticed this too. A lot of Questions are also "close"/"leave closed" by users not seeming familiar with a tag while "leave open"/"reopen" by users that are familiar with it. I find it to be very unfortunate, since there are always more users **not familiar** with a tag, than there are user that are.