# Who handles comment flags?

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags

Besides automatically handled flags, is it done by moderators only or is it done by all community members (with a certain amount of reputation)?

Comment: Only Mods have the ability to explicitly handle flags, however, some flags will be "automatically" handled by the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) User, if enough people flag the comment the same way (such as as spam).

Comment: Or if they contain certain keywords: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266161/why-do-comment-flags-sometimes-take-immediate-effect

Comment: ... or with a single flag total if the comment matches one of several patterns, such as short "thanks" comments, certain rude comments, and other NLN comments

Comment: Note that comments on meta are different, and that we allow comments which have a lighter side.

Comment: Unless you are using dark mode.

Comment: [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/571958)

Comment: But there is no (official) Dark Mode on MSO, @Yivi, so *all* my comments here have to be on the lighter side. :)

Comment: From my understanding of [the numbers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404558/2020-a-year-in-moderation), moderators handled 269,372 comment flags in 2020, and the community (i.e. non-mods and the Community user) handled 177,751 flags. In other words, moderators handled about 60% of comment flags last year.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Me! OK, well, me and [the other diamond moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Only diamond moderators can see and handle comment flags.

*However*, it is possible that multiple flags from different users on the same comment will cause the comment to be deleted automatically, without the need for a diamond moderator to ever see the flagged comment or decide how to handle it. The [current formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags#comment388189_138168) for the number of flags required to delete a comment is `(score / 3) + 3`, such that a zero-scored comment requires 3 flags to remove it, and higher scores demand more flags.

*In addition*, there is a fairly simple regex-based matching system that allows comments containing certain patterns to be automatically deleted by a *single* flag. This is intended for expeditious removal of comments containing expletives, short comments saying only "thanks", and so on. The details of these matches are, for obvious reasons, kept secret. See: [Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266161/why-do-comment-flags-sometimes-take-immediate-effect)

It has been [previously proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278927/could-high-rep-users-help-with-clearing-comment-flags) to allow high-rep users to help handle comment flags, but this has not been implemented. (And is problematic for various reasons, in my opinion.)

I should also note that diamond moderators abstain from handling flags on *their own* comments, due to the obvious conflict of interest, unless they decide to just go ahead and delete that comment (which would implicitly mark any flags on that comment as "helpful").

Answer (score 6):

- If a comment attracts three flags it's automatically deleted. Upvoted comments require more flags.
- Comments containing certain words can be deleted with a single flag. The exact list of those words is not disclosed by Stack Exchange.
- Otherwise it's moderators handling comment flags.

For more information see the [Meta Stack Exchange article on how comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)