# Can we please do something to reduce the "please accept this answer if it was useful" comments?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I have seen it frequently enough, and I wanted to know what your opinion was. Here is sampling of these :

> You're welcome. You should accept this answer.

> @eugenn Glad it was useful. And feel free to accept this answer then :)

> Go ahead and accept this answer anyway. ;-) ...

> No problem! Glad to help! Btw - if you accept this answer, we'll both get rep points. Thanks! ...

> That's great. :) You can accept this answer. I think that will earn you a badge and me some points. :)

> Out of curiosity, why did you unaccept this answer? Best regards. ...

Are these comments noise, a benign reminder?

Doesn't the system already tells new-users to accept answers?

Perhaps sometimes people forget to accept answers, it's true.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can flag them and they'll typically be deleted.  There's so many ways to word it that trying to prevent them from being posted in the first place will be rather hard.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, if there is actually a good way to prevent people from posting them it'd be nice, I just don't see a simple word filter being a particularly effective deterrent.

Comment: @Servy - Recall how we banned the phrase "what have you tried' ? I honestly think banning "accept this answer" would be more meaningful. Because the "what have you tried" is trying to get meat on a post , while the "accept"-noise is simple greed

Comment: @Servy - I can see that . I think we just have to put up with some of it for now.

Comment: Any suggestion more specific than "something"?

Comment: _Recall how we banned the phrase "what have you tried' ?_ - I see that question all the time. Is there supposed to be a filter catching those?

Comment: @BSMP Yes but it is really easy to get around.

Comment: [There are currently 3768 matching %accept this answer% which are posted by the user who posted the answer.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/339878) I'm sure there are some false positives and plenty of false negatives, but it's one filter option.

Comment: be aware that flagging comments from naïve sede queries is frowned upon by moderators...

Comment: See also: [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/4639281)

Comment: @Coffee rene means that the query has lots of false positives, so just blindly flagging everything that the query shows is not conducive to moderator mental health.

Comment: BTW comments containing the word "accept" are deleted with a single flag.

Comment: Flag 'em and move on, go for a walk, do some volunteer service, swing on the swings, sing an opera, write an epic novel, put a pair of boxer shorts on our head and go mad...that's what I do

Comment: @user000001 That is not correct. "accept" is not a single flag deletion. "accepting" and "accept rate" are single flag deletions. I do think "accept" , "upvote" , and "reputation" should be added to single flag deletion list, but doubt they will add them.

Answer (score 6):

If it is a new user that has never accepted an answer and they comment "thanks it worked".  Then I leave a comment "If that was the answer you can indicate so by clicking the check".   But if they have ever accepted an answer then they clearly know what the check is for and I leave them alone.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. **It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer**, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

While it may happen that no answer is perfect for the OP, in many cases such kind of comments is a reply to a low-rep OP who says thanks for the help.
So you feel he doesn't know about the site policies and start worrying about your deserved 15 points.

This is perfectly fine, that filter should not be added.
But, if you see them while playing around, you are welcome to flag the conversation as *obsolete* because it will be useless to future readers.