# Detect "thanks!, wow!, fantastic!, that worked!" comments

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

I get a lot of comments on my answers that are similar to the above listed. There have been [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300157/can-we-please-do-something-to-reduce-the-please-accept-this-answer-if-it-was-us) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364132/upvote-answers-where-new-users-dont-accept-them-themselves) trying to address the issue from different angles.

It shouldn't be too hard to detect these kinds of words and suggest to new users that they have the option to upvote or accept the answer if they haven't already.

Could we potentially tokenize words in comments from newer users and provide a pop-up instructing them on how to show their gratitude?

Comment: thanks!
wow!
fantastic! **Edit #1:** Heh, I was sure a filter was already in place...

Comment: This seems like a double-edged sword.  On the one hand, upvoting content is important.  On the other hand, for every one person who says "thanks", two others typically *would* upvote.  Not sure I see the benefit to a warning system like this as much as I did once in the past.

Comment: Well, to say that Stack Overflow is not a rewards based volunteer system would just be ridiculous. There are badges and reputation and all kinds of stats. That being said, it makes me less likely to keep on answering if I spend 3-5 minutes answering a specific uncommonly asked question just to get "thanks".

Comment: That's cool @Conner; you don't have to answer those questions...

Comment: @Makoto But how would you even know it's "that type" of question, until after you answer it and receive the response?

Comment: @Makoto it's the uncommon or unique questions that I find benefit from on this site. If it's commonly asked and everyone knows it then its probably not very helpful

Comment: Comments like [these](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/930931), you mean?

Comment: Don't see why we need this. It seems perfectly appropriate for you to respond in a comment pointing out that the way to thank you for your answer is to upvote, accept, whatever the user is allowed to do. New users cannot upvote but the big blank checkmark is often invisible to their newbie eyes. Nothing wrong with teaching them how to use the site. And as you rightly say, reputation is the coin of the realm; it's good for both parties. Plus acceptance closes out the question, as it were. Some object to such comments but I always delete mine after a short time so no harm done in my opinion.

Comment: I vote for a CreditCard payment system, where users show their gratitude in monetary rewards. True story

Comment: @TheGeneral *Heh*, just like a "Buy me a beer" link. (Or coffee for some).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i like your mind, default beer

Comment: *Cheers!* @TheGeneral ;-)

Comment: Reddit does the "I see you thanked someone... " bot responses, like https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/9z4f1h/green_lizard_body_is_about_9_inches_long_found/ea6mrbb/

Comment: Heh, some new users show their gratitude by simply deleting their question once they get their answer.

Comment: Just an FYI: AFAIK, SO has changed the flagging slightly, I believe they weigh the comments worth by certain words within it because if you flag a plain '*thanks!*' or close variants to it, they get removed instantly.

Comment: It is not a  bad idea... just as long as it is phrased in such a way that people don't start to think the content rating system is a reward and punishment system. There are already too many angry posts on meta about being "punished with downvotes", we have to be careful not to misinform people on a larger scale with these kind of suggestion boxes.

Comment: Than ks! Wo w!!

Comment: Is this really a problem?

Comment: If this is implemented, it needs to be pretty lax eg. just "thanks" should be removed, but "thanks, it worked by doing xyz" is not. The latter could help future viewers (I know comments like those have helped me before).

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thats too much "feel" in the blanks :'( Y Dey du dis, I cri eyeritym

Comment: @almo It's not "spam" or something, typical new users would not "obfuscate" it like that. /// If they *intentionally* leave "thanks" comments and not follow the rules then it may be necessary to take some stronger actions

Comment: @broman https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376898/detect-thanks-wow-fantastic-that-worked-comments/376903?noredirect=1#comment648897_376898

Comment: @khanp In that case, splitting the answer to multiple parts and let everyone upvote each individually would be better...

Comment: @scr It has been like this a long time ago.

Comment: @mattWhy do we need to do it **manually** while a machine can do it? What is automationfor?

Comment: @user202729 That seems overly complicated for what a simple comment does easily by itself no?

Comment: Hey SO why does it say next to the OP's name that they are a "new contributor" yet the have 22k rep? :D

Comment: @Script47 you forgot "that worked" ;)

Comment: [Similar, related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260477/feature-to-address-the-thanks-youre-welcome-protocol-without-leaving-comm)

Comment: It is about the *one* kind of comment I never dislike seeing.  It has actual useful feedback, proves that the OP actually tested it.  They almost never post "Ugh, looks good but I decided to not do this".

Comment: That worked or similar from the OP is an extremely helpful comment for both me as an answerer and to other users.  If I get that comment from the OP and there aren't other good answers, I will usually remind them they can accept the answer.  Upvotes from people passing through, sometimes years later, are helpful for me when I'm looking for answers but that's a totally different situation.

Comment: I like these comments. You can tell the problem is solved when you see them. Due to an accessability bug, one of the things I can't do is tell if there's an accepted answer or not, but even if I could, the "I'm done, accepting to shut this up" strain is too strong for my taste.

Comment: Note that I never suggested deleting or filtering the comments. I was only suggesting that instead of the myriad follow-up comments informing them on how to upvote or accept and answer we could provide some in-place education.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Could we potentially tokenize words in comments from newer users

TL;DR **This could not only *be* done; this is *already* done**, but only rolled out to comment flagging. And I agree with you, this should also be rolled out to comment writing!

When I flag a comment as "no longer needed", it disappears instantly when it contains certain gratitude keywords ("+1", "thanks", etc.) (or starts with them, or something; haven't figured out the exact pattern), whereas it goes to (mod?) review when it doesn't contain those keywords.

Exhibit A: Here's me flagging a comment starting with `+1`. The comment then vanishes instantly.

[image]

So, evidently, the machinery is already there. And it's there because of an already existing perception (with which I agree) that these comments have no lasting value.

I agree with you that we should deal with the problem at the source i.e. at the time of writing the comment, rather than requiring later flagging to deal with it. Low- and no-value content shouldn't be left lying around pointlessly for any length of time, and those writing them shouldn't be left to move on without haveing received some sort of feedback about this.

> and provide a pop-up instructing them on how to show their gratitude?

This would be a constructive way forward!

Comment: More than the issue of leaving comments lying around (which I still don't see as a big problem) there's no education for the commenter if the comment is just silently flagged away.

Comment: So if a comment has "thanks" or "+1" in it somewhere someone can just single-handedly wipe it with a flag? Somewhat concerning if you ask me.

Comment: @SeinopSys yet another reason to warn people not to put such words in a comment. If it is not crucial to the comment it should not be included. If it is crucial to the comment then the comment is a thank you comment and should not be posted.

Comment: So if I mark a comment as not needed and it contains just "+1" then it goes away, but it doesn't go away automatically? Well, that's what software is all for, ain't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I detest clutter. Superfluous comments take up real estate and push following answers further down and out of view. So for me, it's both.

Comment: @SeinopSys Why is that concerning? I'd be more concerned if we *weren't* allowed to sweep up litter. I'm not sure what the exact algorithm is, but it works fine: in my experience, only those very obviously superfluous comments can get wiped out in that way, while others still go to review.

Comment: @DaniSpringer The human review element is key to this whole enterprise

Comment: Doesn't appear to be true. I just tested it on `Ain't that right! +1 Thanks << because it's meta`, and it's still there.

Comment: @SeinopSys Not in all cases; only if the comment is below a certain length threshold, has no code tagging, and typically beings with "+1" or "thanks". Neither of the two comments in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSZB5.png) auto-delete when I flag them, for example, but they both contain +1/thanks.

Comment: cc @DaniSpringer ^

Comment: @OrangeDog Oh, it's true. Try on a large enough sample of comments, and you'll see what I mean. Though admittedly: 1) I haven't tried it on meta, so don't know it it works here. 2) Haven't figured out the exact pattern. Maybe it's when the comment *starts* with one of those words, maybe something else, I'm not sure.

Comment: @OrangeDog Added some evidence for your viewing pleasure.

Answer (score 95):

I, as a new user, felt very identified with this post , as I was totally unaware that we had the option to upvote or accept the answer...

It would be great for the new users to get a pop-up instructing/reminding us on how to show our gratitude...

Comment: I see you have not taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). When you created your account you've got a notification inviting you to take the tour and learn about the site. You should take it.

Comment: True. In the rush to formulate my first question, I didn`t take the tour...Thanks to your message and the provided link to it, I was able to do it just now...Thanks again!!!

Comment: Nobody takes a tour (or read manuals ...). That is a fact of life and if possible, the workflow should still try to help the users to work as smoothly as possible.

Comment: @Suma all the people with the badge did it ;), but arguably they did it for the badge. (I confess!)

Comment: @Suma That's wrong and can be insulting to users who do read manuals...

Comment: @User202729 I'm a nobody and proud of it!

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Or they have just scrolled down through the text to get the badge? (I admit of being guilty of that).

Comment: @Suma but you don't have to re-read the (same!) tour on each new section of StackExchange to get the badge, so I suppose it's not something to be ashamed of :)

Comment: Info: Currently a notification item is shown in the reputation tab to link to the upvote help page when the privilege is obtained. --- Definitely not "instrusive" enough.

Comment: There is a tour? What are the winter hours?

Comment: @JoséLuisMartínez Didn't you get a huge banner (called a 'hero') telling you to take the tour when you joined? Admittedly, we can't expect everyone to click the link, but... for those complaining/asking for guidance that also just hide the guidance given to them, how else/additionally should the site guide them?

Comment: @TylerH If I didn't click it, may be the "hero" banner wasn't as huge as you think it is...Honestly: I don't recall having getting it now... However, thanks to yivi 's kind message I realized there was a tour and took it. That's why I agreed with Conner suggestion that getting a pop-up instructing/reminding us on how to show our gratitude would be a fantastic improvement to this site!!!

Comment: @user202729 "That's wrong and can be insulting to users who do read manuals... " Correct, in that anything can be insulting to someone.

Answer (score 10):

"Thanks" is often used as part of comment followed by something more useful. I say [thanks, but ...](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=thanks,%20but&UserId=1997232) sometimes ;)

The identification should be more "smart" (machine learning?).

Maybe a better idea would be to let other users to flag comment as "thanksful"? This flag shouldn't go to moderator, but processed automatically. E.g. show the poster a message

> You have posted a thanful comment [link], consider to delete your comment and upvote [question/answer] instead.

The comment can be even deleted automatically (obviously without upvoting anything) if 5 users used this flag.

---

Another thing are those *chatty* responses `You are welcome!`, which I see very often. They are *nice* (be nice) and absolutely useless. If we do something to "thanks" it might be a good idea to do something to those, e.g. detect them and show a hint to a poster, that he can flag comment as "thankful" instead of responding.

Comment: Jean-François Corbett claims that your suggestion is already implemented; flag the "thanks!" as "no longer needed"

Comment: That is my claim indeed! Arrived at empirically, mind you, and not from any knowledge of SO's backend.

Answer (score 8):

While under the site "rules" I can understand the suggestion, I'm not sure it's a good idea, for a number of reasons.

1. As someone mentioned in comments, these terms could be used in a way leading into further discussion ("Thanks, that helps, but..."). We see enough annoying messages repeatedly - no need for yet another.
2. Flashing additional messages to new users, especially ones telling them their social skills are unwelcome, may make them feel unwelcome or unsure. I've had good experience with replying to this kind of thing with a "you're welcome. Since you're new to the site..." And when a vote or response comes through I go back and delete the comment exchange.
3. On a personal level, getting a "Thank you" once in a while with some additional information makes me feel good - despite the site rules. Perhaps it comes from working in low traffic tags where 50% or so never respond in any way: once in a while it's nice to know that the effort put in is appreciated and the person can be bothered to take the time to express it.

Answer (score 2):

I see @planetmaker's point on commenting something about how specifically an answer helped you, but also @Conner's one: people often make a bad use of the platform and end up writing useless things from a pragmatic point of view.

Given that, I support the idea of detecting those tokens and displaying a banner or something indicating the right way of showing gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

I agree completely with this suggestion. I think the key is in:

> It shouldn't be too hard to detect these kinds of words and suggest to new users that they have the option to upvote or accept the answer if they haven't already.

It doesn't mean that we have to delete or block those comments, because maybe there is a valueable message after the thanks, but it would certainly be a good moment to pop up a brightly colored box below the comment field saying something like

> "If this answer helped you, upvote it, and consider accepting it"

.. with the appropriate links for explanation. This doesn't have to be limited to new users, I think, and it doesn't mean that the comment itself is blocked.

Answer (score -10):

It's detrimental to block comments. Reminder to use voting ... not sure:

Completely new users are already barred from using comments, so we see answers in the way of 'thank you'. The voting system with acceptance of answers is pretty obvious - and there's always the option to tell people to use that when you have the feeling that they "only" say 'thank you' in response to a nice answer which helps them.

However, a 'thank you' comment is more effort than an upvote click or an 'accept answer' click. So in essence a user went to more length to say 'thank you' in a comment than by a mere upvote and acceptance.

That said, I frequently use comments in addition to an upvote and acceptence to comment on how exactly an answer helped me or what had to be done or considered additionally to the given answer in order to solve my problem.

Comment: *Completely new users are already barred from using comments* With one very, very important exception, especially for the question here: **not when it's their post**. New users can comment on their own question and answers thereon.

Comment: *"However, a 'thank you' comment is more effort than an upvote click or an 'accept answer' click."* - maybe so, but it is the difference between a second and a few seconds of effort. In other words: its all the same, almost no effort.

Comment: Useful comments may get buried in such kind of comments. I also find it distracting when I am trying to learn from the post with aids from the comments. A user will look at the comments for additional aid, and the upvote count to see how many people agree with this. Use the right tools for the right purpose, it will help the reader to focus better.

Comment: It may be marginally more effort to say "thank you" than to click an upvote, but I can tell you right now that as long as Stack Overflow gives out reputation and privileges for upvotes and not for comments, I will always prefer upvotes. I bet most other users will, too. Not even considering the fact that that's the intended method for thanking within the system and that it helps keep the site/page clean.

Comment: Sure, it helps keep the page "clean". "Thank you" is such a dirty word.

Answer (score -10):

I do both. I up vote, check answers which solve my problem AND say "thank you" to those who helped me. I think it's important. My parents taught me that it was important, I'm teaching my kids that it is important. We're humans, not robots. If a popup tells me not to say it, I'll ignore it. If an automated system stops me from saying it, I'll find another way of saying it.

Comment: It's important to show gratitude in appropriate contexts. But I'm sure if you were writing a Wikipedia article and someone made a helpful edit, you would not add a message of thanks *to the article itself*, for example. Clearly there are some contexts where it is not correct to write a "thank you", even though in general it is good to show gratitude. People mainly come to Stack Overflow looking for an already-existing Q&A that solves their problem, not to create a new one, so it helps the vast majority of users if the Q&A pages don't contain information-less comments they don't need to see.

Comment: Very good point. But Wikipedia articles take on the form of one single page, even if several people contributed to them. SO pages start a bit like that, but then they take on the form of a discussion. "Thank you" takes less than 1/10th of a second to read and is not information-less. To whom did the poster say "thank you"? If the poster thanked several people, it means that several answers contributed to solving his problem. You can only mark ONE answer as being the solution, but sometimes you find the solution by combining information given in several answers.