# Can I have a dump of rude/abusive comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

We already know [it is possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically) for a machine to be taught to classify comments automatically. This incredible post used machine learning techniques with an initial training on known good and flaggable comments in order to classify any comments.

[One of the answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280554/1743880) of that post mentioned that it would be even more useful to identify rude / offensive comments automatically with a very high success rate. This is what I intend to try and to output these comments in chat for human to review.

To do this, I started to use a basic identification technique with a regular expression on all comments that are posted on SO. This generates many false positives, and, like the linked post, a machine learning algorithm is needed. However, this means I need a lot of rude / offensive comments to train a classifier.

Bottom-line: I want lots (> 3000) of rude comments. The dump should contain comments deleted by a moderator that has at least one rude/offensive flag.

Also other users would be interested in this dump:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31044541#31044541

Comment: It's unlikely SO will honour your request, but I have a better idea: let's start creating data right here, right now! (brb, Googling Yo Mama jokes)

Comment: Would this include comments that were deleted via flags with no mod intervention? Remember that it takes 3, sometimes 1 depending on the content, to remove a comment.

Comment: I would prefer only by moderators (hence we trust in them), but if complicated all dumps are welcomed

Comment: This must be a first: a question is blatantly *asking* for a rude comment and I find myself tongue-tied. 

Comment: My knee-jerk response was: "who in his right mind would want to invoke the 'summer of love' disaster all over again?".  Looking a little closer, ah, it is the SOCVR chat room whupping themselves into a frenzy again.  We can tell the cosmologists to stop searching, the mysterious dark energy that accelerates the universe into a bleak emptiness has been found.

Comment: @HansPassant just to clear this is not an official SOCVR project, true I asked Undo about this in the SOCVR room. I think in general this could be good for SO as SmokeDetector is good in finding posts that does not belong to the network, but maybe we should just stop caring.

Comment: It would be great if you could get info relating to the number of flags on a comment too. Perhaps that could be fed into your classifier to determine "how rude" something is? FWIW I think it is good that you care about these things, Peter!

Comment: I'm not interested in training a classifier, but I would like to see such a dump just for personal amusement.

Comment: @halfer, thanks lets "move on" and leave that battle (which I have no really clue what it is about, I guess old grudges), My idea was to trust the moderators, not users, I'm not so sure number of flags really reflects "how rude". But since it's not only me that would be interested in testing this all additional info certainly are welcome.

Comment: I don't know what battle you're referring to - I am unfamiliar with SOCVR history. Hope you get your data `:-)`.

Comment: @Pekka웃, my thoughts exactly :P

Comment: I'll catch the fat from eating all the popcorn as I read through your dataset.

Comment: One problem with this would be in anonymizing the comments. You'd need to strip out the user who left them, but the system would also need to anonymize the @ names within them. Even then, you're not going to get all the names, and many of these were targeted insults at particular users. The last thing we want is for dead and buried fights to be unearthed. Also, there have been instances where users have been doxxed in comments as part of targeted threats against them. Those comments were deleted by moderators with the assumption that they'd never be visible again.

Comment: @halfer - It's rare for a comment to receive more than one flag. There's no review queue that motivates looking over them, so typically only one person will notice the rude comment and moderators or the system will delete before anyone else does. When more than one flag comes in, it's typically due to the visibility of a post and how many people are actively commenting, not necessarily that it's more rude than other comments.

Comment: @BradLarson maybe trust a moderator (if I can find one that is willing to do the work for free) to clean up what is not to be unearthed?

Comment: Thanks @Brad, interesting. I imagine the most obviously nasty items are caught by the instant-delete feature, which is what stops these contributions from getting multiple reports.

Comment: I wonder, if there is a worry about _perfectly_ anonymising these, that users can apply to download them, with the assurance they won't pass them on to anyone else. Perhaps if it requires 5K and an email application, it'd filter out all (most?) users intent on malicious action.

Comment: You could not guarantee all personal information would be gone. You could scrub address (street and mail) as well as other things automatically but you would need someone to read them all for this concepts candidacy. Not sure if someone would be willing to do that (or should).

Comment: @PetterFriberg - In the last 30 days, moderators deleted over 20000 comments. Not sure how many of those were flagged as "rude or offensive", but I'm guessing 500-2000. If these all have to be manually reviewed for redaction, that would be a bit of work for the last month alone. No tool currently exists to go through these and identify bad ones, so that would need to be developed. Longer timeframes would be impractical without automation.

Comment: @Brad, Yes I guess you should have a discussion among moderators to understand if the work involved of manually checking 3000 comments for classification is worth the benefits that SO could have from it. I would volunteer but I understand the issues with unearthed.

Comment: I've built document classifiers with over 30 categories using tools like Apache NLP and this would be relatively simple to accomplish provided that you have a mostly pure source of good and bad comments.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Yes, we are looking into similar libraries and you are welcome to help us, we are developing in java (you can find the chat rooms I'm present in my profile). Naturally it is possibile to get data in other ways, this question was to get data in official way with correct evaluation (moderator). Lets see how SO evaluate the "importance vs work load need" to create a good dataset for anyone who is interested in this.

Comment: I know I saw something like this on one of the Kaggle competitions (one of the ones that aren't for money)... oh yes, it was the one where you analyze comments on Reddit. That corpus and the related algorithms should still be there. Might want to have a look.

Comment: Uhhh, should we amend that close reason to include the Stack Exchange team? This request is very obviously directed at the staff - why should they not be able to answer questions intended for them on meta?

Comment: @BoltClock the close-vote culture on Meta is very counter-productive. But hey, if it gives the robo-reviewers the feeling that they're being useful, well, good for them.

Comment: I'm guessing this would be a problem unless they are willing to delete all usernames from the comments so that there's no PII included.

Comment: @TylerH `string.Replace("@[^\s]+", "");` problem solved.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Only for comments where people prefixed a name with the @ symbol. A lot of the time they might reference a user like Jon Skeet and say that he smells or another one like Technik Empire and say his feet are hairy.

Comment: This is a non-problem, stop wasting your time. For every thin skinned wimp who cries in a corner for an hour every time they are insulted, there are 10 others who got enjoyment out of it - see the 142+ upvoted "personal amusement" comment for reference. (Let's see if this one ends up on the list!)

Comment: The A+ answer would be a multiclass classifier that also categorizes insults into insulting OP for lack of effort, lack of general intelligence, knowledge, reading, typing, formatting, compliance with SO rules, not searching for dupes, programming language-specific disses, ethnic/religious/obscene insults, insults their mother or family...

Comment: ...insinuates the OP is a serial banned user or troll, insults the OP for low-rep or rep-hounding/ their general motivation/ communication skills/ insults the cosmetics of the OP's code/ their mental wellbeing/ sexual insults/ religious insults... oh what a taxonomy..

Answer (score 78, accepted):

After discussing this with the community team, we decided that we'd give a sampling of comments that were deleted after getting flagged as rude or offensive.   I pulled some comments (far less than the > 3000 you asked for). This was done for a few reasons: 1) there is a character limit for posts, 2) because we need to manually review them to make sure there is nothing identifiable in it - either user or post info and this takes a significant amount of time and 3) we're busy and we don't know how successful you're going to be.

Rude and offensive comments are a problem on Stack Overflow and on other sites.  Over the past 90 days, there have been almost 4k rude or offensive flags on comments, so finding patterns in them as [Andy did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/426671) would be very helpful to the community.  We do request that you don't use this as a witchhunt to find users and harass them. On that note,

[image: Keep calm and test on.]

**Comments placed in a snippet to protect the innocent**

> ```html
> Of course it's code you insensitive clod! Raytracing or geometric definitioan can be solved by doing recursion not that it _has_ to be but it is one way.
> +1 ExceedsThreshold -1 first example. If you think you're being clever you aren't.
> Mexican police takes a random african animal and pour soda with chili into its nose until it admits that it's an elephant.
> Ever heard of Ebooks?
> You're not a real developer if you've never left an apology comment for the next person! :P
> Pure science? WTF does that mean? You think NaCl doesn't come in a 1:1 relationship?
> Seriously? Did you even bother to look at the documentation for UIButton?
> Just remember that they hate you http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001065.html
> Care to explain why?
> You are welcome!
> agreednext up what does SET stand for in SQL and var in C#?
> Don't worry **** what you said makes sense.
> Yes and you can find it in any SVN manual or book; which you really should read so you use SVN right.
> I like the obfuscation in your answer text.  Makes it very hard to read.  Ever heard of the Enter key?
> You must live in a box then.
> Yeah im a baby give it to me in a bottle lol.
> I think we've reached a new low of laziness.
> youre funny dude :P
> I find it quite charming actually
> Did you think I was talking about some other Rails framework that's written in a different language?
> While you did a wonderful job of restating the problem I'm afraid that doesn't constitute an answer.
> Suddenly your avatar makes sense.
> Damn the MICROSOFT. Thought I love it it never follows what the world follows. They are proud of it but sometimes it becomes pain in the ass.
> Since it's Thanksgiving I'll thank you for bothering to read my question. Your answer on the other hand is worthless.
> the curly quotes fsck with the code parsing
> Your syntax is junk.  Is that the problem?
> I second the beatings.
> Wouldn't you want the default value to be zero for it to be as fast as possible?  Sounds like a good default to me.
> Let me guess are you a perl programmer?
> Oh Lord.  There was an earthquake in Haiti you know.
> Why wouldn't you have already checked the manual?
> Don't waste your time trying to make this work it isn't worth it.
> Agree but -1 for answering a dupe.  You should know better.
> Because ******* is mildly insane.  `espresso-mode` is the Javascript mode for sane people.
> -1 useless answer
> Works on my machine.  Somebody is blocking you.  Are you Chinese?
> Most probably **** gave it to me because his code is perfect.
> Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm for sorting algoritms to be able to sort your data as efficient as possible
> This is pretty fec-ked up.  There's no reason to have to deal with clock disparity these days.  Post to serverfault.com to figure out how to setup a time server.
> Why on Earth would you want to imitate something this butt-ugly?
> I would upvote this answer but I just hate this oh downvote me you senseless clods bullshit.  Especially repeated twice.
> shut up sir.....
> There are stacks of examples out there. Try searching...
> I'm looking for a Klein bottle with some wine in it. Any suggestions?
> Its called your brain. If you can't competently review code ask someone else to do it.
> ANYONE??? HELLOOOO???
> Step one: turn off your caps lock key.
> you can convert it into seconds and then compare. I believe you've learned that in your school.
> there is a very good reason not too. But thanks for the reply.
> gaand phat gai sabki koi nahi bata paaya.
> [Get a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Forget you know Java you'll never learn C++ that way.
> taking a couple hours to start on a 3ghz cpu is hardly good to just wait once.
> You asked: can u tell me which one is better to use to fill a datatable dataadapter... and now you say you said one or the other... goddamnit Novice is not the word
> Where exactly does it say jQuery in the question? jQuery != JavaScript and in any case he asked an HTML/CSS question not a JavaScript question.
> Your professor's a retard.  Not that strange really.
> Haha what a retard yeah if I tried to build then I would have realized that :)
> Stupid solution he's don't need that
> Do not clone my post
> «my program explodes in a spectacular blaze and I weep» — awesome.
> Are the typical dangers not enough?
> jesus I thought i was going mad thank you!
> Maybe b/c people like you that don't make useful feedback are the reason...
> Everyone who thinks he can wiggle around writing a real parser by applying regex instead needs his nose wiped in the shit this inevitably ends in.
> hey thanks for the help...so what was this dependency for commons-io..i read a tutorial and it told me to include this one
> Your quotes are inconsistent. I recommend single quotes for JavaScript and double quotes for HTML attributes and JSON.
> With a reputation > 7000 you might know where the Python documentation is.
> there is no need of downvote. huh wht to do with this kind of people.
> Request for answerers: point to a place where **** can get a really good string sanitizer instead of coding it himself.
> 1) im not stupid
>
> 2) Thanks for the answer
>
> 3) I think stackoverflow.com was for asking questions if you dont want to answers.. just.. dont answer!
> suggest another alternative
> There is no programming question here.  You have an invalid entry in your file.
> omfg what is that?
> here comes an Exception object reference not set to an instance
> Is this a troll?
> wow i am a retard :) thank you very much. been trying to fix this for the last hour
> look can you please stop posting such unrelated rubbish. Posted 1 hour ago cannot accept for another 2 days IF **I** think this is the best answer
> I did not **** and I want't angry or anything like that. Did I said something offensive? :)
> -1: Admittedly iphone camera on google doesn't give you any useful links but spend an extra 30 seconds and google for iphone camera tutorial and you're done.
> Okay this one gets my funniest post of the day.  :)
> shut up............
> Even if the aplpication si running ocal it is called remote debuging sigh! Look at the answer below it explains it.
> That means that you have fucked-up the routes. Come on new question!
> To add onto that there's also now an hqdefault.jpg for the HQ version of the thumb
> This shows remarkably little effort.
> Wow what a terrible mess.
> Its the number of fucks will not reduce the gestation period
> `sql-server` AND `oracle` tags? And an explanation as well? It's homework isn't it?
> If somebody asked me that question I would want to punch them in the face. And then answer Apples and oranges
> is there any reason for word `issue` in the topic?
> +1 Good answer to a poor question.
> ⌘+W... [9chars]
> So I just make my iPhone storyboard english and translate every ViewController on `ViewDidLoad`?
> Huh.  Odd workflow (not saying it is wrong... just different).  I'd suggest opening the console output in a separate window or pane.
> man this is a programming forum not trig.
> wtf? how is this a real question?
> Stupid question: Have you set the UIWebView's delegate to `self`?
> I select already exist ABPerson using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.
> Oh! ok thanks! I will try it out tomorrow! :)
> Have you bothered to actually look at the PHP docs and see how to do it or do you just want somebody to spoonfeed you the codez
> In the addressbook?  There could be hundreds depends on the user.  In the XML attachment file it will be about 20 max
> Right.  You're doing arbitrary lookup which is what hashes are for.
> So you can add `google` if it's your favourite search engine...
> blog post my foot. a whole function to resemble original function's behavior unknown to authior
> here's a pojo:  public class Pojo{}  You should totally copy that and use ctrl-v in eclipse whenever you need a pojo.  Or are you talking about generating Java Beans?
> And maybe taking a class on databases. Or even just reading all the way through a tutorial.
> You should not use w3schools as reliable.  See www.w3fools.com for the reasons why.
> This shows zero effort on the author's part.
> wow now that is lazy... I can't believe people are actually willing to help you? :S
> +1 for being second :)
> I would beg to differ.  This site (and platform) is massively successful...
> God bless you you improbably thorough m*****f****r.
> In Excel there is a magic key which very few are aware of (**unfortunately**) :( And that Key is `F1`
> I did it *** thanks for all the help! Final solution finished thanks for all the help Everyone.  Cant believe those Aholes -1 repped me
> Probably a lot of java programmers like me that tried Hello .trim() before trying the internets.
> learned a fake-language' was that javascript or BASIC?
> You should really learn the basics of web-programming before creating a web page if you don't even know the difference between client-side and server-side script languages.
> Is this homework?
> hypercrypt it is a client's requirement.Client is female and she hates all the URL and website address stuff. :)
> Old question but wouldn't UDP work better for this?
> Wow didn't know you can convert HTML tables into Excel files...
> nvm got it.  No thanks to you.
> He likes to ask questions
> If API documents are hard for you to read then you should *learn* how to read them first.
> And the award goes to the Asp.net team for most retarded class name...
> Read the documentation -- **** is correct and the documentation will tell you how to do this.
> RTFM or ask a new question.
> You never asked a question.
> For anyone wondering how you call this function. Do this ... if([self hasConnectivity] == NO) { // not connected } else { //connected do your stuff}
> *a bit lost*  Seek 'jtextarea+javadoc' and 'jtextarea+java+tutorial' to find yourself and so much more.  Always try that before asking on SO.
> witch! burn him!!
>
> ..it worked for me though thanks
> Yeah. Post the real error.
> Do you have any objective-c programming experience?
> damn it... u just beat me to it
> Please don't answer old threads that have accepted answers given years ago. Use your energy to help in current questions instead
> lack of research effort
> Take your other questions you asked and mark the answers you think is right.
> my eyes!!!!.............
> Is there a live page with this code that you can link to?
> Read a C++ book.
> Don't post question for silly mistakes. You actually wrote the code to get the text from the edittext in the oncreate() itself.
> You're an idiot.
> R u crazy ****??I will give you -1 for this stupid answer.I am not asking for this.Please read my question carefully...
> a ton of research eh ? this is the second hit on google: http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/postcodes.shtml
> Downvoters don't have a cow... what do you want?  Sometimes you just want to take the first item from a dictionary whatever that item happens to be.
> +1. Thanks.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
> Did you consider reading the documentation?
> The answer links to the docs what more would you want?
> Why do you even care?
> nut-searing pain - couldn't have said it better.
> WTH? TIA? This Is Awkward? Typical Ignorant American?
> I know this great site you can go to find tons of stuff like that. Here's the [link](http://google.com)
> I don't think this is even worth asking.. a small google search would of given you the answer.. or just stick with trial and error and experimenting.
> The downvoter probably never wrote a well-behaved C program with any kind of resource.
> Pls add a comment atleast for a -ve vote :)
> ever try google?
> Doesn't work because all of the fragments are marked as visible. Please read the other answers more carefully.
> sorry can't help myself: **** reputation: 1
> What the hell is that `d1_utc` thing for? You've got `d1.getUTCHours()`/`d1.getUTCMinutes()` already and `d1_utc` will be a different datetime
> We don't magical stick and ball to understand your word. Post code
> Try to switch on the thing between ya ears before spamming and make people waste their time.
> If you take a `public` `super.shit()` then you'll be `add`ed to a very special `List`...
> This is the preferred way. No dependencies and much more cleaner. I don't know wtf does async.whilst() and I don't care. +1000 to recursive solution.
> To lazy to check the parameters for `CGContextAddArc()` or am I not understanding your question?
> can u figure out how to do this stupid crap?
> [Try and ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)!!!
> Wow! You are so smart!
> Ask all those people who you've always heard this from.
> It was the first result on the exact title as mentioned in the comment. Now it isn't. The first hit is now tragically this stupid question.
> Lacking an OO interface is a non-argument in this discussion.
> So what's the question? What's the code? Or do you prefer us to provide you with magic out of the air?
> i post same thing..bt ur confused again?
> 15 votes 2 favorites... My time to shine! Why is it harder to pick an element by it's index from list than from array? What a brilliant question huh?
> Naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. thanks alot.
> I have already done that if you look at my code at the top invoking the ggplot. did you notice the + theme() + ???
> Have you even ***considered*** looking at the [freely available very extensive SQL Server Books Online documentation?!?!](msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx)
> What a crazy idea to close this question! Jesus holy Chirst!
> What have you tried so far?
> **Bloody fool people don't try to give down vote without knowing the answers.. Give Down vote with justification.
> Thanks man.!!!!! Great Coding..... Thanks a lot again.... **See other bloody fool people instead of interested to give down vote.**
> So why don't you just do it? I don't see a question here.
> oops..sorry.. Have voted up
> This question shows zero research effort...
> If you're running windows and **** answer throws an error try it this way. Worked perfectly for me.
> No we can't. What u have tried ?
> just wtf... closevote
> Thanks for time wasting.
> lame shit. i simply want to assign multiple error callbacks when a $http.get throws an error. how do I do that using chaining? Can I do it with `then`?
> Much easier in android...
> How to delete this question?
> Maybe should read about Accessing array values?
> Google is a hell of a drug.
> Or check the source. You know since it's open source.
> you have to read. the problem is a link to the picture of it.
> Don't work in the tutorial project THANKS :)
> Get a good operating systems textbook.
> Geez a beginner is no excuse for not learning at all.. You can search it easily in google..
> Use Google to find one of the numerous tutorials on how to build a library from C source files. This has nothing to do with Rcpp.
> OMG! You really want and should write down such novell for one easy thing? Seriously man You should do some more research - workarounds usually end up badly..
> like your comment?
> Copy paste from the below answer
> This is the most useless answer I have ever read on stackoverflow.
> +1 Thx helped a lot
> haha this one's still funny !!!
> Which is interesting but doesn't actually answer the question.  See the accepted answer.
> Moving along.....Please refrain from taking any jobs at nuclear power stations....
> its a valit.. i don't need to worry about it.. and i want exact answer
> Thanks for choosing an answer equals as mine which I posted 1 day earlier.
> What exactly do you expect? **** is correctly putting out the relative path to your image. Do you need somerhing like Base64 encoded/inline images?
> Maybe go wash that greasy finger.
> congrats! you got a muppet upvote.
> yeah right we can debug without a line of your code. what did you try where did you already searched ? we are not debuggers.
> This question appears to be off-topic because it's a duplicate but I can't be arsed to search for it (much like the OP)
> Shit ok thanks :) If the amount of content is variable how can I then make the height according to the content?
> You just saved my ass :D Thank so much
> What the hell is `sub` anyways..?
> Your use case is flawed. Reading a tag from the phone to which it is permanently attached is silly
> I think your putting down votes for my all questions? Why? What's your problem?
> I wonder why this answer is still showed up despite of the comment above.
> go away!!!!!!!!!
> this is a crappy question  what have you tried? is there something wrong with your code we won't know unless you show us?
> Maybe you should learn Java before you try writing an Android app.
> I've downvoted as you've had several responses and not replied to any of them.
> Where for witch targets ?
> Didn't help. While main project's ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH set to NO Pod's project has ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH set to YES for Debug which causes compilation errors.
> You could fix it by not using TortoiseGit at all.
> Where does the `images/backgrounds/` path come from? It's mentioned neither in config nor in code. Do you expect **** to be telepathic? :)
> Yes but i don't think so 5.0 and 5.1 has too much differences in them. Apple should keep track an indexing. And there must be some way to use the old ones.
> http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101
> You trust Stackoverflow users more than the vendors own API documentation? So sad.
> Wow that's a first
> I hope you are not a DBA
> Sometimes I wanna shoot myself in the head.
> What the hell is wrong with you ???? :D Seriously ? Comic Sans ???????
> unclear is waaaaaaaaaaay too polite.  Flawed or crippled would be more like it.
> Asking for a working example is off-topic. This isn't a coding service or a recommendation engine. You're supposed to exhibit an attempt for comment.
> It's a shame that someone doesn't know how to use keyboard shortcuts or how to read
> Read the manual that comes with the application.
> how about doing a Google search. That's where you can ask. Everyone else has spent at least 30 minutes doing their own research first before asking questions.
> If someone is experiencing this problem and using CocoaPods this is likely the correct solution.
> Taught to do it this way at uni... Apparently it's bad jew jew haha
> Answeru wa totemo oishi desu yo!
> Why am i getting down votes.. i'm just asking a question... Dumb idiots some ppl r
> cool. where did you get it from?
> how to solve it with C# - by writing some...
> Solved it for me too! When it comes to python packages apt packages usually really suck monkey thingie.
> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being incredibly impatient with the App Store.
> Awesome you found the answer within 8 minutes. Quick :)
> Want to -1 that shit-tier code style in that last comment but sadly (or luckily for you) stackoverflow doesn't have such a feature.
> Thanks for linking Rails 4 docs to a Rails 2 question from 4 years ago. Thanks so much!
> The person who down voted and marked as close if you're a man enough explain why you did it so we all know otherwise we all know what you're!!!
> Google is the answer of your problem bro..make the google bestfriend also the stackover flow..
> ........go away
> Awesome linking
> A thoroughly pointless question. If it did come before you would be asking why it didn't come after.
> lovely and you specified that you are using centos
> Wrong. There are 14 of each.
> Very elegant answer Thanks.
> Don't worry about it. No one cares about your code
> Is there any wrong in the code? - it is 2014 and you're still using IplImages
> It wastes my time to try this solution. The right answer is the one that **** wrote.
> Need based coder as in I need the code that someone else will provide because I can't be bothered to learn the language?
> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading comprehension.
> This question appears to be off-topic because OP clearly has no clue how to handle/manipulate and array
> Have you tried oh I don't know using the variable?
> how about reading some documentation before posting such questions?
> Did you actually *try* what you claim to know? Why would you expect two calls to `list` to do different things?!
> +1 RTFM and a link to TFM
> Haha no offence but over the course of a couple days shouldn't you have added a recursive call for your 'recursive' function?
> take a look to my answer perhaps you can use it in your code to avoid going your shoulder to scratch your ass :)
> fail opinion based question
> And it shows only the javadoc for the current function not the hovered over object too. Really bad answer.
> Mormon programmers FTW
> wtf??? how can I exit telnet???
> f*cking thank you no where did someone mention that values can not be null although my keys are <null> rather than null
> That's the most pathetic answer I have ever encountered in Stack Exchange.
> This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow is not a developer-finding service.
> this should be selected worst answer
> Have you tried this yourself? By the way it doesn't work.
> So why don't you do your own homework instead of dumping it here?
> Explain what else you expected and why. How does this have +33?!
> I am not asking abt what u r saying I have given the link to help u remove ur ignorance of telling my answer wrong... Ever heard of autoreleased object?????
> This question has potential but is a [violation of MCVE](/help/mcve) if I ever saw one. Remove the `NEQWIN` crap and you might have something.
> **** wins this thread over the pompous jerk who told her she doesn't get it.
> It's cool that jsoup is smart enough to autocorrect your misspelling of chidl!
> Patronising _and_ wrong. Nice.
> Was writing this question easier than pressing enter? :)
> Thanks for sharing your experience. But please try to focus on the relevant parts in future answers not telling everybody the story of your life..
> I have a few words to describe Magento and none of them are kind.
> lol very mature. My not knowing the np.nanmean command must made your miserable day
> JFC! You must have _really_ good drugs
> This is stupid. An implementing class should be able to choose what to expose outwards while providing internal functionality of the interface.
> The link seems to not present any information at all ... Please do not troll if you are ...
> Add explanation or don't post answers to such questions.
> How is this related to coding / programming?
> i am not at all interested in your meaning less crt baby reasons. some one as you with no morals and common sense make my blood boil
> :sex <-- And this is a sex symbol!
> Sorry coding jokes don't come along very often.
> man enough is enough i m not telling bad i m just saying you are annoying more than a 2 year old baby
> Why does this question get so many upvotes when it it considered off-topic for this site (request for external resource).
> Ha or `sum = 0; array.each { |x| sum += x }; sum`
> The worst answer ever!
> No exception -- the guy is just fishing for reputation points by posting bad questions and immediately self-answering them.
> OP asked for a C++ solution. Not for a C/C++ solution and neither for a C solution. Let's try to make one's life easier by not providing C solutions where none are asked.
> Serious question: why do you imagine a google search done by one of us is better than a google search done by you?
> nobody can answer my question？
> Which WebBrowser are you referring to in the code? The OP asked about WPF WebBrowser. Please stop fooling people.
> So what did you ask? answers?
> Uuuuuuuuuuuugggghhh.
> Seriously did not even try did you. Please at least search Google if not stack overflow before posting a question.
> What is the question. The forum is for english speakers ;)
> http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/614/722/f9f.gif
> http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/
> yes 100% duplicate. but this issue remains unsolved and perhaps needs other to make it solved.
> I downvoted because it seems that ***** *****'s answer below is the correct answer.
> doesn't work......stupid solution
> Did anyone else but me /facepalm after reading this answer?
> Have you read the [numpy tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)?
> It could also clean your house cook some food and do all your work for you. That's a possibility.
> *****: Do yourself and everyone else a favor and use ui-router.
> Hahaha this is f****** absurd :D!
> Screw you to the guy who voted down. No research effort? Really? For someone new to Linux getting as far as I did most certainly took a look of research effort.
> Your teacher really does let you work with CI still...? That men must be like 80 years old?
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it skirts on the edge of legal advice.
> We're not here to do your work for you...
> Reading comprehension fail.
> This is just wrong. Why would anybody upvote that?
> I'll do it in a few minutes thanks for your advice.
> Anyone have any idea why **** has to be an ass about it?  I came here to find the answer so it must not be THAT crazy to post it on SO loser.
> Cogratulation. This is your second downwoted question today. Keep up! :)
> The only possible explanation is that you are a terrible person and regularly beat small dogs just for fun.
> If you cannot understand the problem jsut ask me I will edit the question. Why yo make downvote? It is really a childish act!!!!
> Who made me downvote you're really damn idiot!!!
> Yes very Annoying every time I post a question comment or reply comes much later but down voting comes first I think there are some fools who has only work of down voting
> downvoter should take care of adding comment as reason.
> Who asked for a jquery solution?
> I always upvote a question that elicits a good answer no matter how dumb. +1 for you.
> that code is a mess!!
> Thats works like a cunt when you are also doing Django pagination!
> Format your code properly first. It looks ugly.
> This forum is about problem solving not dodging
> `<pre><a href=<br />>Hey</pre>` and you're fucked. You better use html5lib to parse your HTML and modify your DOM.
> if you werent such a knob you'd have given a worthwhile answer.
>
> Always use single quotes around your class names as properties inside the object.
> **** Can you explain this to me? I also get the error _plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default invalidated_ and I cannot figure out what your answer means
> In entire Stack Overflowthere is not a single programmer to solve this query?
> No one cares what is freaky or annoying. Just ask the question and skip the gratuitous emoting please.
> Ok you cannot bother.
> Man I fucked the editting of this post it's supposed to be http.post either way none of the calls work anymore and they did before.
> Well it works in iphone / ipad size but now the fullscreen is fucked because it is no longer at the bottom of the page but instead of the content.
> What's the point of digging up this questions ? If not for a boost of reputation ?? The OP goes back in 2011...
> I am sure through some pretty complex Math he can get his solution from this.
> I love this answer so much. The symbolic logic approach is damn sexy.
> Is this an answer or a question?
> It's difficult to tell whether you're answering or asking a question when your answer ends in a question mark.
> I don't see how this passed as a question back in 2012.  RTFM
> dafuck? That's the most important part. The rest is useless without it.
> I wish I could up-vote this more than once.
> Emacs terminal is a dumb terminal so it's no surprise that many things break.
> That's retarded. I would never have thought of having to enter those other positional args before I could view help for a subcommand.
> include the resulting image properly
> Android Studio sucks install IntelliJ. I have spent so many time with Android Studio some AH is managing this project at Google.
> Haha ... removed your comment huh ? well i guess we all know who's right then...
> My other aliases especially my favorite `alias fuck='sudo $(history -p \!\!)'`  show up though!
> http://bit.ly/1EdE5aC
> Fuck... Info... I think not works... Why what do you see? What is the error? Do not work... How to help if you say just that?
> i will kill you!!!
> you black dog where is your face huh?
> Did your numerous solutions include searcing Stack Overflow where you would have found an answer?
> I have a big problem lol... :)
> Do you know why or is this homework?
> this works but looks awful :D
> libwebsockets is shit!!!
> Fuck im completely stupid man.. I had a huge range. I should use offset for the list so to add on line for every new line.. Thanks a lot..
> Man shut up ****.
> Did you create these images yourself or did you borrow them from some unnamed source?  Please give credit where credit is due.
> How can something which doesn't actually solve the problem be most useful?
> Goddamnit.This is hopeless.
> When I ask you a question what I need is an answer. Not two more questions.
> Is Google not installed on your machine?
> You're too sensitive to live.
> I have upvoted your contribution in order to engage and to award your stupidity.
> Oh shit! I guess that's my problem. Thanks I'll see if that helps. Lemme know if anything else comes up!
> Answering and asking for more..
> I honestly think you are just trolling me at this point. Good luck with your problem I hope you find a solution.
> Have you tried [this new awesome search engine](http://www.google.com)? Is new but efficient.
> It's not that bad but yeah... I've seen prettier girls.
> Fuck both of those things. They don't matter at all in the general case. They only even come into the picture after your profiler told you where to put them.
> Where is the spelling mistake? And again revert the formatting I dont want to keep manually undoing your mistakes. I dont want to have to ask you again.
> liar! this doesn't work
> StackOverflow: The correct answer is there but the prick who makes the most fun of the question no matter how incorrectly gets the most votes.
> Oh dear you don't want to have it so complicated do you?
> What have you tried so far? Did you do any research on the topic yourself?
> attempt your assignment you lazy person!
> utter rubbish.....
> Study Basics...start with [WPF-MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee)
> There is no magic. Do you actually know how to use a scroll view? Have you ever used one? Do you understand what makes it scrollable?
> Huh?  How do you currently _install packages_ ? That is what this function is for and I answered your previous question.  Feel free to do `help(install.packages)` too.
> lol read a book
> I'm flagging this as a duplicate of [this question](http://bit.ly/1Tqcwn7); please don't cry
> Note: if your C header `#include`s any `std*.h` headers you're fucked
> That wasn't the question. But it's easy enough for anyone to figure out and if they can't then perhaps they shouldn't be coding.
> If everything is synchronized why the fuck even care to do threads? -- My Old School Master
> yup  i forgot to undo some change to another script and basically fucked myself over  i didn't find my solution but atleast i found my error  thx .
> This is a decrypt method that you stole from an illegally decompiled source for all we know you are trying to hack into a crypted system with the unfortunate help of SO.
> write some code. also congrats on the muppet upvote. dodgy as.
> I got the same fucking issue like this: after a day coding a REST API file then save then re-open Eclipse again all my changes go away.
> If you have to ask this you're not fit for the job sorry.
> .equals() does the trick! fuck yeay stackoverflow is the shit!!! :D :D :D
> Reason for the downvote coward!?
> down vote for no explanation - i don't like magic here like  orig and other similarly
> http://blog.gofenice.com/uncategorized/get-current-user-id-prestashop/
> You are the problem with the online support community.
> Don't ask a second question create a new question or better yet Google it!
> Since you a being a grammar nazi you should have spotted the `if you doesn't`
> Welcome to 2000
> Uhmm then something else i fucking it up - with .submit() - it's not working at all. Neither in chrome or firefox.
> You can't. I just call my forced div `<div id=fuck-react>`.
> You can't fool me - that's a JPEG and it doesn't have any transparent pixels.
> Okay error gone! Got the html being dumped in via the file_get_contents now the scraper is fucked however you have been a great help so far!
> Same answer as **** one just worse...
> IMO git rm should just remove the file(s) from the git repo not the filesystem...so so stupid
> i did this allready. I even tried to copy& paste some examples from the Jquery API into a text document on my computer AND EVEN those don't seem to work!?!? what the fuck
> It does help. You are just lazy to use it in your openquery.
> You tha real MVP
> That's not going to happen.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
> Do you have a variable `sc` defined at all?
> What has this to do with the question? Are you astroturfing?
> Looks like your cmd.exe comand is fucked up does Win+R -> cmd.exe work?
> what the hell is this code?? where is the func of OutageViewModel.Id()? or   AfterSavedAll()??
> what you said was so inspirational in 2009 such a shame  you didn't dig it further otherwise node js could be yours
> WT? does not work did you tested?
> your moms a terrible mess pal...................................
> Your swift code is not pretty…
> The one who downvoted me please don't be a kid. If you don't understand the question just tell me in a kind way. I don't like stupid people.
> Thank you for helping me. I AM NEW TO PROGRAMMING and I simply wanted an answer. Now I know that this site does have a******* who are not very understanding individuals
> ...so wtf is then going on?
> the one who downvoted me I cannot find any word to say to you. Dictionaries are not enough to describe the title for you.
> My problem is in my code i wrote 2000 lines working with argv like char and now if i put it tchar my whole programm is fucked up...
> :) always there is someone who gets negative votes even when everyone is getting a positive point.
> got to love people who provide the laziest permanent fix ever
> I don't see any code. Did you bother trying to google it on your own? Because I literally googled `java string replace after index` and it returned 800000 results
> I tried posting my Logcat but it keeps saying there's a formatting problem. I spent about 20 minutes fucking around with it. I gave up.
> Lol The JLS uses iff?
> welcome to the internet.
> This is not Instagram help desk.
> i don't know why eitherjust did.. - best logic ever. I predict you'll have a long and successful programming career.
> You posted a lot of unnecessary irrelevant HTML.
> Could you also provide a pure Javascript solution?
> holy fuck it all works now!
> *I'm too low status to rep you it seems:(
> Oh fucking crist! I can put an IF inside another IF? Thanks <3 Jesus bless you brah!
> Someone is in a shitty downvote mood today without explaining the reason for the downvotes...
> please question related answer not .. other.
> unfucking believable!!!!! i was using fragments so I needed to add the dummy surfaceview to the main layout. thank you!!!
> Checked POM contains single version of Spring Framework and <tx:annotation-driven /> is also there.
> Seriously bro? do you even java?
> This post is hilarious.
> Removing the code has made your already obscure question completely meaningless.
> Crap. Idiots ...
> There are a lot of books with such kind of OOP bullshit. But why developers do such poor design of their systems (OOP design  too) using all this theoretical stuff?
> Wow. I'm fucking stupid. Thanks **** it's been a long day!
> Your question doesn't even make sense. Please try to write in a somewhat decent English.
> **This is not a duplicate of How to compare Strings** Read the question properly before marking it.
> Thank you so much 50 variable checks later I found out it had null because I fucked up in another place in the code .
> Lol copy paste my answer
> Yeah its obvious until I get the commenting privilege I will post answers the way I want.
> Thanks. The `box-shadow` provided by bootstrap fuck this up. The issue was solved after override the `box-shadow` to `none`
> if you use directive to set default value then may god blast me .
> Did you tried anything ? SO is not a free code service we're happy to help on code with problems not doing your work/homework for free.
> It's a copy and paste of my answer..
> This has to be the most ridiculous way of going about solving the problem.
> Apparently you need to add some booty pictures to change your downvotes to upvotes.
> Ha. I mentioned it because your solution didn't use LEFT JOINS. Don't pretend otherwise! Also will your DISTINCT also count NULLS?
> search on google .
> Use your mind...Don't ask this type of silly question.
> If you cant understand the question than get the hell out of here.
> You're using the TTS in a very weird way.
> You don't know enough SQL to create a `SELECT` query?
> If this answered your question please accept it.
> Happy new Year CYA!!!
> Imo the google result fetching request and terrible question all together is more offensive than the word fucking. -1 nonetheless
> If this solved your problem you might consider accepting this answer.
> hahaha jsperf you fickle bitch... http://jsperf.com/periodicstrings/3
> he said he wanted simple i gave him an approach what is your dysfunction?
> Common sense!!!
> I'm about 90% sure you're the same person as the one who asked the question.
> non of your business. are you english teacher?
> It does fucking compile -.- This is not the whole fucking code listen retard...
> You found the documentation... did you read it? What's not clear?
> Thank you **** however if you not prepared to help keep your stupid comments to yourself.
> again mind your own business and stop bothering me.  if you don't want assist then stop wasting space on the site with your comments.
> Did you try anything at all? Did you search for this? Do you even *know* JavaScript?
> No this is stupid. Not even close to a generic solution. It could easily be dangerous.
> Err... [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) maybe? Use `PREG_GREP_INVERT` as the 3rd parameter.
> Which book are you using to learn C++?
> you may want to check the stfu i aint politically correct policy. Oh wait it doesn't exist since it's given by nature.
> I DONT GIVE A SHIT WRITE PROPER WORKING PRODUCT
> What's the _question_? Just ask it and stop please. This is SO not your blog.
> Didn't you already ask this question  twice before?
> You have to create your own `WhatsApp` First
> Are you trying to answer the question or be a smart ass? Really I can't tell by your comment.
> What the fuck do you think I'm doing here asshole!? Research. Jesus christ! Why does the world have to include schmucks like you!? BTW happy new year
> fuck everyone who downvotes
> How would providing any code here help? Instead of being a code monkey how about look at what the issue is - that is what it means to be a computer scientist.
> Im also voting to fuck off my post
> because he is frustrated trolling in first day of new year
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it follows the pattern *<false statements> - Assuming this is true why is it in common use?*
> Are you retarded?
> http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/
> No error no excepted resualt i'm fucked up :)
> Seriously ? It's the easiest programming task I've ever seen. Juste read some doc/tutorial about arrays
> He's asking how to set an element in an array what do you think he has done so far ? Nothing.
> Please answer as soon as you can because I would like to finish and work on other things.
> Just because two languages start with the same letter does not mean they are the same.
> next question will be I dug a hole and want to fall in tell me how
> Take it to the psychiatrist.
> yes N0b to sql ! u didnt help much lol
> This should be the accepted answer not some xor crap.
> You look so confused.
> no.i just want to decode this shit
> **** I haven't told you a code transtation service.if you know then answer if don't then skip.
> yes thank you anywans look if you can help me not telling for stupid mistakes
> Indeed not equals is the non-idiotic way of coding a relational exclusive or.
> This is not a spoon feeding service! Show some code and learn [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
> F*cking hell this is actually a good question. What SE site should it go to so it doesn't get downvoted to oblivion?
> People are helping you for FREE you ungrateful little shit.. be respectful and follow the rules and people will help you..
> You mad? It is the same thing that my code contains.
> then up vote :( :) bitches
> You think I didn't? And the duplicate post does not contain the answer for my question.
> you two guys want to suck my dildo?
> fuck off **** asshole
> I m going to fuck your mother **** fucker
> fuck off **** fucker sucker
> su.. my di.. ****
> Im gonna fu.. your mother
> Well try something. This isn't letuswriteyourcodeforyou.com .
> Oh come on DataTable seriously?
> I've been telling it trillions of times on this site. Searching shouldn't be hard. There's a textbox on the upper right corner that could be used for this purpose.
> Huh?...........
> This looks like ***guess work answer***.
> Wtf is a dynamic pointer? Read a basic textbook
> It still won't compile. You can find a lot of Articles & Tutorials related to Recursion in the Internet. I am afraid SO is not the place to ask such generic questions.
> This answer is wrong. I have this problem in 2.48. Giving nonsense answers you will not gain reputation on Stackoverflow.
> Found a workaround that doesn't seem to fuck up the rest of my program and does the job. Although I guess your way is still the correct way to approach this issue.
> Thanks in advance.
> Who uses the G-WAN web server? The G-WAN website and that's about it.
> You seriously don't even know how to write code? **Kindly check out the [tour].**
> Pop it in the oven on 200 for around 15 minutes
> Who is the IMBECILE who deleted all the comments to this question???
> skip learning if you don't like it (and stop wasting our time).
> Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book tool software library tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow
> Don't be a dick about it. C++ provides you plenty of ways of working with ostensibly unrelated objects: see std::min. My question is reasonable. This answer isn't.
> There are a sure load of prats on this site.
> I assume you later on want to ask is lamborghini a vehicle?
> And this does not do that?    You are beyond helping and I will remember to not try in the future.
> I suggest looking at any of the thousands of calculator app examples out there. Have you even bothered trying to debug your code?
> So you want us to google search for you now as well? Anything else you need? A sandwich? Some coffee?
> `steam music android java` guess what happens when you google that? How stupid/lazy are you?
> Real life must be a shocker if you think this is rude...
> Sure in stackoverflow I really didn't understand why so many people post answers or downvote without a basic understanding of questions. lol
> I have an easy suggestion: teach your developers your environment.
> Yeah sure couple of SO users are already working on writing this code for you should be delivered soon ;)
> you want fries with that?
> what is this suX ?
> if you had learned it you would have posted an answer ... so go learn it you too
> SO isn't a free tutorial / guide service
> hot. I mean the question this is interesting.
> Looks like you lack basic OOP knowledge. I'm afraid you can't get help from here.
> For saving image path first I've to upload the image right and then only i get image path to save into the table. wtf does that mean?
> Try googling resize runtime winforms or change name to ilietopeople. Really.
> vote or die madafaka
> or you could just contribute to the community and mark **** answer. Credit the poeple that help you don't just turn around and start deleting shit..
> why are you so vicious?
> ...and I want a cookie.Thanks for letting us know what you *want*.  What's your *question* though? What have you tried?
> And I still want a cookie. I'd still like to know what your question is and what you've tried.
> So give us a url then so we can see this not working.
> Sure we'll just whip up something so you can spam your garbage app... Would you like a snack while you're waiting? Something poisonous perhaps?
> I will get it I am determinated ;) so stop your stupid comment and just click - reputation ;)
> lol. can't believe this answer gets 3 votes. must be all from your accounts. lol.
> Could you be any more lazy?
> Learn how to program before attempting anything as complex as a multi button GUI.
> If you don't know the answer keep your mouth shut
> Why you cannot use `each_with_index` ? Its some kind of homowork ?
> thx for the downvote smuck
> Google try and then ask questions.
> Yeah well fuck your mother you retarded autist you should kill yourself you fucking skinny ass nazi.
> lol fuck you puppy youre an ugly nazi anyway you fucking clown nerd ass bitch.
> Lol you're probably a nazi anyway that's why you won't help a good jew like me.
> Strictly speaking I'm an ugly nazi clown nerd ass bitch who knows the answer to this question.
> Yeah you got that right you fucking nazi clown nerd ass bitch. Get a life maybe the only way you know the answer to this is if you have no life.
> Screw you **** I already know your full name and I will not take measures to ruin your fucking life. Find it in your heart to hide yourself.
> Thanks **** for another RELEVANT answer.
> no need to be such assholes
> Nope not at all. Check my answer I did it on my own.. No need for any of your comments telling me to combine all your posted pages which is ridiculous BTW.
> Please capitalise punctuate and paragraph this mess.
> Heh... :D Then what are you offering for me to do sir ****?
> What a nice person have a good weekend :)
> I have to stop SQL Reporting Services because dumbass Apache can't figure it's crap out on its own.  Why does open source stuff have to suck so much ass?
> Sorry “change your platform” is shit advice.
> lol i tried that yesterday and still doesn't work the way i want thanks for coming out as a brick though next time maybe don't try to help someone in need a-hole
> I want a textview inside a relataive layout or any layout read the question first before answering dumbass
> complete garbage
> because `var ls = fs.readdir(process.argv[2]);` is undefined how the hell can we know why
> whoa what the fuck guys all im saying is dont use a dot at the end only commas and semicolon are you guys fucking autistic?
> sorry i cannot post more character over here. If you  have time  can you please look at the line from 365 - 413 .
> and clean my room wash my car and do my laundry...
> kya le ke aaye the kya le ke jauo ge comment main dala hota :D
> Well sucks to be you then :)
> yeah stupid analogy you do things better than me blah blah blah. Go ahead talk with them smartass : ****
> fuck you son of a bitch
> I'm not sure we can help you with mental health issues ?
> holy shit thanks I found out that I had a row with 5 columns instead of 4
> You are a fucking legend. Thank you so much!
> Is google down?
> +1000 for Cargo Cult Programming. When combined with the H1B issue you get Coolies to lift your Cargo too! :-)
> All telepaths are on vacation now - can you show some code ?
> Hello nobody cares about your life story :) get to the point
> phewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww. I wish sarcasm was more apparent in text format.
> Clearly he hasn't answered it by your comments below you're simply wasting people's time by being to stubborn to provide any reasonable information.
> [links](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create+time+limited+trial+java+program)
> did you really asked this question?
> Really? You don't know about String.Substring ?
> If i would've done that i wouldn't be asking here. The thing is i don't know how to approach to get the desired result.
> Those who care IE is fucking dumb developers. :) just sayin' :D
> Are you sure that you understand VBA properly?   In the code Find returns :
> you can show pdf in your app without calling another application so why do you want to open other application.
> i´d start by reading through a basic java tutorial...
> Sucks to be you.
> fuck fuck fuck fuck
> fuck fuck fuck fuck fukc
> POST YOUR CODE.. WE ARE NOT CLAIRVOYANT.
> Blah blah blah blah...
> Get the f**** o** from here. this is not portal site.
> [why my question is getting downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)
> oh thank you for opening my eyes on this amusing fact!
> Stop cheating. You're not going to get that job.
> that would never work
> Ok who the hell are you to edit my stuff
> All I need is this code fixed or at least some help if you're not going to get the hell off my question and go to the next one
> And **** about the Google search may be you need to use this link : https://goo.gl/GzjTG6
> if you can't help don't tell shit
> That's called a `UITextView`.
> Oh ya zébbii ...
> Duplicating existing already linked answers and calling people names is what's not constructive. I think it just makes it clear what you're going for in these answers.
> without any explanation & what the user is using is not mentioned so can you please justify this answer ?
> hire a developer. stackoverflow is not a place to get your work done for free.
> So is a pencil  paper envelope and stamp an alternative
> Wrong. You don't understand Spring. Did you even read my answer?
> Really you can't understand the error statement?
> if you cant help ..atleast dont piss off anyone..idiot...
> I'm flagging this question to be closed as too broad because it is merely a Gimme the codez question the likes of which are not welcome or encouraged on Stackoverflow.
> nice copy of mine and **** styles :)
> I found what you're asking in the documentation of Localytics in less than 2 minutes... Did you even bother to look ???
> `(laziness stupidity... ` Well aren't you just an arrogant arse.
> Too dumb long read?
> when someone don't have answer he tried to degrade and get points.
> Gentleman i think you miss understand what I am trying to do.
> Stop trolling and get a job.
> Fart sound. not free
> just answer the question
> Try not to be helpless type default.rd.xml in the Google query box.
> Why are people being cunts? Voting me down. I said I was a newb. Tossers.Thanks for the feedback.
> I've helped loads of people over the years even when a question wasn't perfect. People on here are 'question fascists'. The site attracts assholes.
> Oh really? It turns out I tried that and it didn't work! Do you think I'd post a question on here without trying to refresh the session?
> An array is not a pointer and vice-versa. And please RTFM. See the `printf` manpage.
> you need to move the whole title part to the top of the loop.. come on common sense
> Thanks for being a published asshole
> Sorry forgot to say - a Jerk also
> Down-voting your answer until the property update behaviour gets sorted out. Will undo the vote once we clarify this matter.
> That's why I am asking. If you don't know the answer then be quiet.
> _italic_ usually sucks
> Yes go ahead and delete it and don't ask such questions here again.
> *I know PHP Storm is built on Eclipse* Yeah right. That explains a lot!
> Top SO Google result filled with useful information closed by some fuckwit moderator who probably doesn't even know what XML is. Gooooo SO!
> ne pas être intelligent
> What exactly are you doing here? This program reads like someone spliced random lines from some very strange spanish c program together.
> une personne stupide essaie d'être intelligent si je l'ai fait .
> hell to your comment idiot.
> hell to your Zend certifications RASCAL
> sorry forum nazi
> this is wrong . your solution will create a list from [5  num+4]
> Fraction is not the same as remainder. But maybe that techno-speak is too  complicated. Too bad programming is a techno-thingy.
> Have you *tried* to do it with streams? Don't just expect Stack-Overflow users to refactor your code for you...
> WHO THE FUCK DOWNVOTED?????
> Finally answer that makes sense I got bored -1-ing every other attempt to answer this one.
> So what if it worked perfectly before? They changed something in their vendor build of android and perhaps it doesn't work now until they patch it... ?
> I voted as too broad did not vote dup.  Not much point in bitching at the only person that is trying to help you.  Focus on your object design problem to get somewhere.
> Hey **** are you always such a pedantic c.u.nt? Why don't you go f.u.ck. yourself you pseudo-intellectual elitist b.it.c.h
> What the actual fuck can you just please help me. I tried a lot of others forums. Seems this one could be my savior.
> Well I don't want to use the letter i in my code. How can I declare main?
> Why even use DateTime if you're going to still use date and strtotime? Get rid of them and clean this up.
> I fart in your general direction!
> This is a genuinely terrible answer which you should be ashamed of giving. Don't answer this kind of question again.
> The answer couldn't be simpler. You are of course using Unity's UI right? Simply look at the `.text` property of the `Button` and of course you have your answer.
> WTF vote to close. Point me in the right direction.
> He didn't ask for your opinion; the timing depends on the receiver; and you haven't addressed the major fallacy in his question.
> Professional developers hate him!
> MongoDB is 'awesome' is a pretty terrible answer. Furthermore your lack of experience with Cassandra does not qualify you to answer this question.
> Are you retarded or what? If the problem is not in your table you should put the fucking code where you do the insert.
> Do you know what templates are and how they are spelled? What exactly is the problem?
> who downvoted me ?idiots
> RTFM? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177677.aspx
> Please don't badger me with rules.  I only made a stackoverflow account for this one question because I've tried for literally about 2 months and nothing works.
> yeah i'm about to turn 13 next week. you got beef son?
> It's essentially the same code you use to exclude all questions that don't show what you've tried.
> This is not a code translation service. There are no [tag:c++] scripts. What is this for? If it's a commercial project I could help you if you pay.
> If you can't answer the question you're useless keep it moving. If a moderator wants to edit anything he/she can I don't have to an intelligent person will understand.
> What in the heck does this answer have anything to do with the question?
> well you can't tell me what to do so suck my balls
> English probably
> all the forms input always should be inside the form tag don't you know that??
> The idiot who downvoted obviously didn't read the bold marked text *rolls eyes*
> **He always brings the same information** who is this?? And unclear your question !!
> how about you stop munching curry?
> Oh! Yes. Don't relieve it to anybody. Eat yourself.
> That's a pretty arrogant statement don't you think. Perhaps Stack Overflow is not the best place for you.
> IT WORKS!!! THERE IS NO COUNTER STATEMENT SECONDLY IF I PUT != IT DOESNT DO ANYTHING THUS IT WORKS LISTEN BEFORE YOU SPEAK
> Step 1: Go to school and get a CS degree
> First of all you need to learn the human language to understand the What topics can I ask about here? help site of Stack Overflow.
> asked the moderator to move it and got downvoted. This is some shit.
> Links can die post the actual *relevant* code here
> You're dumb don't write me anymore
> Fuck off the code works
> Okay special snowflake. Yes I only downvoted you because I'm too stupid to write code as awesome as yours.
> have you even thought to look at the JavaDoc for `AtomicInteger `?
> Although I appreciate you pointing me towards a great resource. I was hoping to actually receive a response like hey in cases like these i.... so honestly. Screw you.
> I have sovled this problemthe same as you said netstat -abn.
> what a fuckIt does not listen localhost:80and can't access itsef by domain name.
> Thank you captain obvious! ;-)
> You are really an idiot.  Now I see you down voted my other question.  Get a life.
> **Read** the question...
> You don't seem to understand what the word *override* means.  Try a dictionary please read it carefully.
> Hey smart guy even so you stopped for looking and lose time answering it get a life nerd
> Please show code.  The OP asks for code.
> use a bloody search engine!!!!
> Also which muppet upvoted?
> So you don't really understand any of this code?
> You don't need to say that buddy. If you can't help then Fish off and stop acting like you are the CEO of Stack Overflow lol.
> I HAVE NOT GIVEN ANY CONNECTION STRING ITS CODE FIRST TO NEW DB DEPLOYMENT SO BY DEFAULT ON MY PC IT IS **creating** database but on client pc not creating
> You should read a manual first.
> You know what else you can do? You can go **c* yourself. You fill in the letters and let me know if that violates something else.
> wtf this is off topic?
> how is it off topic wtf
> Javascript people don't give importance to archtecture subjects unfortunatelly. It's different from Java people.
> fuck you i can swear as much as i want you cunt btw thanks
> it's very good idea to harash new people that trying to enter your world thank you a lot... i am trying to understand sth but as i see u are not supposed to help me...
> We provide a service of reading error messages for people too busy to read them.
> Why don't you try it instead of letting us debug your code. Or better - search first
> Sorry but I have to say you have no clue what you're doing. Your code is full of nonsenses. Throw it and learn how to program first.
> Only ignorant people can downvote a question without any explanation in comments
> I love how you call the bullshit American time normal.
> I run a Seattle Website Development firm is this your standard business practice outsource your work to Stack Overflow?
> done that already... I'm not here to waste time...
> That is kind of nonsense. The user needs to authenticate silently without having to enter a username or password I guess ?
> use a search engine?
> SO is not a code writing service.
> Sorry again I fucked up badly. I corrected it again.
> If my solution had a simple error there would have been barrage of downvotes.
> true ... though better make sure you know the rules of what kind of questions to ask around there ...
> if you cannot differenciate then better dont comment
> if you can't look at an algorithm for 1hour to find out what it does then you should probably quit being a programmer....
> That is much ABC worpdress I know all that already in which none can achieve my needs.
> yes but OP says it doesn't make any difference so you might wanna remove this as an answer.
> I hear google can find all kinds of things or so I've been told
> **** get a life! And don't ever answer to any questions that you don't have anything to give. You are a smartass without and only waste this Web site's topis.
> While I agree that you are still learning to post good questions why do the rest of us have to suffer?
> Jesus. This is supposed to be an interactive community. I could care less about formatting I want to ask other coders for some advice. That shouldn't be a problem.
> oh and if you're trying to be cute your account could be banned. So think a little.
> You weren't sad. You deleted my email accounts and screwed over my team. Go fuck yourself.
> I think **** downvote me cause i downvote him :D
> Please add some more info about what you are getting. Shame you got a downvote without a chance to edit it first. Cheers
> I think this is the most edited answer today. You should gain a badge lol..
> What does It doesn't work mean?! FFS You get an exception? The world ends?
> OR operator is `||` not `or`
> ITS FUCKING WORKING!
>  I think you need something better to do.
> Please start by reading a Python tutorial. Your code isn't even close to valid Python.
> Fuck off. Idiot.
> Mother fuckers like you are destroying SO.
> Is your mom off topic too?
> You can get a path like c:\one\two/three ... And it fucks shit up.
> not working you canst it here: https://regex101.com/
> This is not the place to get your homework done. At least convert that text to ASCII rather than posting a picture. Lazy bone.
> Actually my code is perfectly formatted.  Two other people were able to tell what I was asking so stop bitching.
> ill put you on hold
> Thanks I got the answer on my own. If you know employee schema you should have got my question.
> can you give any successful code.........because I don't have any idea about this...I read the documentation but is not enough for fresher
> Doesn't meet *your* imaginary specifications and wrong are two separate things.
> yep you go it.bright guy
> Oh...... What stupid a question! I'm sorry to waste you time ...
> Offtopic: This is ridiculous. I hit Submit and in less than 5 seconds a -1 vote is here. You cannot even have read the whole question.
> When you even don't know that selenium webdriver can handle the file upload then please keep silent ..
> Before giving minus points please read properly or ask what I am asking for
> Bullshit answer. how this even selected as answer?
> What have you tried to solve your problem? Have you tried to print any string with that 'format' function?
> As it stands this question is too broad.  Do you have a more specific programming question?
> You're not even using ARC? Really?
> Links rot. You don't know that?
> So you found the solution by yourself just after reading it on my answer. Fair play to you.
> did it take a lot of research to count the sides of the +?
> Edited...  Please don't make me regret answering this.
> Seriously useless morons I didn't ask for an opinion. This site has gone to the dogs f u.
> Only a stupid developer would do that.
> Perhaps you could start by learning Python's base types before asking the obvious ?
> As per my guess those who cleared mongo university course very well know about **[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)**
> I think is clear enough.... I think i explained clearly enough what i have allready try. if you cannot help just leave...
> 3 dislikes wtf guys  this community is slowly moving to asshole level 9001
> fuck this shit why i am even bothering i will write my own generator -.-
> Possibly but does it matter.  You recently duped one of my answers that didn't have any relevance to the duped one.
> _Please help! I am not good in regex related things._ you don't need RegEx. Use `indexOf`.
> Thats OK Take your time We have nothing better to do.... Oh! Yes we do!! Moving on.
> Why would you take an assignment if you don't know how to do it?
> ***who gave me -1 is one cannot understand the question if you find yourself one of them please leave my question now!***
> Wanna bet about it?
> please cut out your fucking fingers!
> [*dynamic iframe loading javascript library pym.js*](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/tnnwi0x6d9u8gin6k2z4.jpg)
> Never use `fopen` to a remote resource unless of course you are self-employed or has a willing to become one. N00b.
> Very poor showing by seasoned SO users that such a ultra-duplicate question is not closed
> Then fuck you guys!
> No homework questions please unless you show what you have done
> if i am able to i would have not posted it. And it should be a one liner answer using some regex or something else. If you cant answer it don't post useless comments
> don't post useless questions. All i read here is Here's the problem. Do it for me
> that's how you get by on this site. Yes I do. If you want to post questions your way then go to yahoo answers
> anyways leave it i have fixed the issue i am not here to fight with a person who can't dare to right his own name and uses (Registered User). lol
> More like + 1105 points for asking SO. #standard
> fvgbhnjmk.kjmc nm
> RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php `$key => $value`
> Too lazy to read a manual better write a SO question.
> You have obviously get very confused. Start again and this time check in with the manual every now and again.
> wow...I don't mind you not helping but don't make it impossible for me to get any answers...the tags clearly say admob and android...I don't know what your problem is
> P.S. Your obsession to prove me wrong on everything I say is getting tiresome.
> You should find a way to inspire your boss to get you some training.
> ..............................
> Thanks for the downvotes kids but I just want the answer is this safe not your unlikes.
> You've managed to include everything *irrelevant* to the problem and absolutely nothing *relevant* to the problem.
> I am using the `batch` command with a file on Linux from time to time. So trust me.. Or STFW
> sorry but this is *pohtaytoe pohtahtoe*.
> This is a cut down version of the solution I posted 14 minutes before you posted this.
> Great thanks for letting us know. Come back when you have a question.
> by the way your code is horribly formatted
> Awful as clickable area differs from highlighted area.
> I do not see any answer explaining `String#match` here.
> why the down-votes? I'm just asking for help for something I don't understand how to do.. if you don't know either just leave me alone no need to bully me.
> So which tutorial was this copy+thrown up from?
> Wow people on here suck. Why down vote without leaving a comment?
> oh come on dude you cant even do your coding part???its soo simple..
> Ok since you have 59 reputation points can you please show me how I should have answered I also need to learn probably I am new to answering queries.
> `didnt study prototypes yet` prototypes are what make javascript the ugly duckling of coding
> Go has a clever and novel concept of loops here called `for`. This might help here even if not obvious and pretty advanced fancy stuff.
> Who the hell are you to talk? An Arabian terrorist? Fu*k off.
> Were you looking for someone to code that up for you? Or were you planning to share what you've tried and how that failed?
> To those voting to close this question because `This question does not appear to be about programming` what exactly is not about programming here?
> google don't have the answer if it does i wouldn't ask here and i didn't ask for YOUR help so zip it man.
> That isn't very helpful.
> You rewrote my question and change the entire meaning. That's terrible.
> Such a ***** community.
> _you'll most likely see many more questions from me soon =)_ Hopefully ones of better quality than this one.
> punch of noobs -_-
> **** hooly shit brainfreeze thanks haha
> Problem 4: You can answer without to be arrogant. no one force you to answer.
> This is slower Oh what nonsense.
> If you didnt wanted to answer why fucking bother? This is a comment and not an answer. Stop wasting people's time cunt.
> It is a dumb pointless question and voting to close it as such.
> utter lazy rubbish
> Oh very easy! [Here](http://google.com) you go
> Shit! My bad sorry!
> i dont want to downvote it.. i suggest you delete your `answer`. you have no idea what we are talking here. you just are embarassing yourself.
> Instead of marking unlike please give some relevant link or Answer.
> Actually you wanted to be the first. You could provide the final answer directly :D
> How `1+1=2` works?
> Please don't do people's homework for them.
> You will help him a lot more if you help him understand to write his program for himself.
> Ya I know its a common sense issue.
> Why the downvote? I would be very good to know why... Show your self you bast..rd!!! ;-)
> You should test it before saying bullshit ;)
> **** Yes you have showed us regularly that the correctness/quality/readability of code are not something you take seriously.
> Thanks! Thought I would have to click 433 times after selecting commit for the first time.
> The guy just removed his Not An Answer and downvoted me. Well done.
> Funny that works even though it's not a string. What a fucked up object. str(f) works
> that shit don't work devil
> Can you answer the damn question?
> Please don't encourage people who ask questions like this by taking them seriously.
> dude you are lame. forget it
> You all are fucking retards. This question has not fucking been answered. Fuck you all.
> Try reading the fucking prompt. I want a way to kill the task without killing the current program that is running it. If there's not a way say it.
> That's awesome help..Hope someone hires you. :P
> Editing an answer to change a locked-in vote is an abuse.
> Thanks. But don't forget to click [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#newwindow=1&hl=en&q=learn+php)
> Instead of duplicating your whining to game the question form show the code of your attempt.
> becaus no possible short circuit.
> I hate Apple! This bug is present in 7.2 also.
> If u can't help don't interfare. Get away from my post
> are you stubborn or just stupid?
> Shut the fuck up!
> Let's have EXTREME sex in front of your children
> Please provide some explanation to help other users of the site.
> I read: I have an error. I am not going to tell you what it is. Please fix my code.
> Stop arguing and answer the friking question!!!
> If you had bothered to read the stack trace you would not have wasted your time typing the question.
> A keyboard and your brain...!?
> If you don't know just shut...
> Are you thinking your smart??
> really you called yourself coder ??
> Fine **** actually its not your job its something who can do extra ordinary see I got almost two levels.
> Thanks for your extremely polite reply its like no one would have understood what you wanted to say if you had said it in some other way. Moron.
> Please learn the basics of Java. A `return` statement is made to return the result of a function. These `return` statements are really classic. What's bothering you ?
> This is what you call a quality answer to a difficult question  :O  Whoa.
> I wouldn't have to get verbal if you were polite in your reply.
> Everybody here is a jerk. -1ing is like trolling but nobody laughs.
> now its -2 because a horde of nasty people have decided that anybody they don't know is a monster.
> NOW ITS -3 YOU ALL ARE IDIOTS
> Well not only the first answer read you must #yoda
> wtf you talking about?
> and If U don't know how to read u would probably put weird answers !
> Why do I always get down voted may be I really hate this site not coding
> What have you tried ?
> poor guy asks a question and you give him an unjustified -1?? +1 to offset some prick's ego.
> because the answer is simple your just to suborn to understand it.
> Lol *Angry German Thrift Committer* is this the new *Techno Viking*?!?
> Angry German Thrift Committer [disapproves](http://i.imgur.com/wfvNKTM.jpg)!
> I am very much a beginner in ... programming: go back to reading the books - you have no reason to be posting  here
> Did you even try looking at the tutorial ?
> Ok I have looked at it
> Didn't know this website was full of elitist dicks.
> You show a really poor mind!
> Funny how people dislike my question without giving a reason or an answer. I swear to god I hope those guys have cancer and die.
> it fucking worked
> Of course it's not the end of the world. It's also not the end of the world if you pee on my rug but you're still a dick if you do.
> Show me where you took the problem from (so that I would know you are not trying to cheat in programming competition) and I will give you a solution.
> This is a simple issue with _hoisting_ and awful ordering of imperative operations.
> Holy shit. this is a null pointer exception now AS I MENTIONED ABOVE IF YOU GUYS CAN READ IT PLEASE.
> google gives you link that leads to this site though. stupid
> You should get some courses in an elementary school for adults
> you just rephrased my comment. stupid. I'm looking for some solutions coz I'M NEW TO ANDROID . So if you don't have some suggestions/solutions shut your old mouth.
> If you've only been debugging for five or ten minutes then you _definitely_ haven't worked long enough on this problem before asking for help.
> Keep those streets clean or flip the burgers.
> Then get your grubby mits off our source code ta.
> I am probably missing something - Probably education - but then again you not are into that
> **** in the same was as people can conclude you are an offensive homophobic prick.
> You are ***** genius I love you no homo thanks for help !!!!!!!!!!! xD
> You tricked me into spending time on making that then never responded. If you don't want to help don't put demands on me to do A and B for you. That's mean and vicious.
> Well it's a log.  Before his changes it fucking printed NULLLLLLLLL.  After I appled his changes it PRINTED WHAT I WANTED
> Apparently it is not the documentation but your reading skills. Read **carefully**!
> I guess that's douchebag for as far as I know that doesn't exist.
> Yes but without everything else like method and action and inputs putting it in form tags will do fuck all
> 100 is less than 50 you idiots
> yes i am but thats gay
> thanks for the sarcastic comment neck beard. May all your friends think your the coolest person ever.
> You're kldding right? You're writing a computer program that relies on predicting the future? I have a bridge for sale ...
> read whole question if you are going to answer
> Ok you didn't try to see what it outputs or this one :/
> Have you heard of Google?
> fuck you  you bastard  hippo-crate answer it or other wise shut your fucking mouth ! you racist
> go fuck ur self with the 10k i don't even bother about them
> fuck you all. tell me the release date
> lol are there any computing scientists on this website? QA? What a joke
> i don't balm it because you have a very small mind  your jealous or something  you could eat the  10k at lunch time for free. am paying :) cheers
> how helpful this one ?
> What's your budget?
> dhur bal chera giye
> Learn more Java skills
> OP in response to your request:
>
> No. Spend some time thinking why people smarter than you marked the question as a duplicate instead of complaining.
> So what's the problem you don't understand slicing?
> If you want to correct me at least read what you're doing and I might be able to take you seriously...
> Why? Your answer is clearly wrong. I don't think you are fit to answer questions if you do not understand even the basics of probability. Go back to basics my friend.
> Is this question a part of your assignment/homework. Learn about `JOINs`
> Are you from Iran ?! ;) That's totaly not a good idea because in some cases i prefer to use the 0 value **Refigh**
> just answer the question. If you don't understand it leave it. Somebody else will. I saw a lots of over-exited  around stack overflow. :/
> Seriously you edited the title but didn't change then to than?
> bro u change ur msg
> Very stupid idea to pass db statements via angular but you just want to move  }; some lines lower.
> Fuck all who me down vote!
> A fuck you man!!!!!!!!
> You are entitled to your opinion. However thinking that you know what is impractical if you can't even write your own working solution without help is hubris.
> if you have mind then answer itdon't read my English. Whatever you give or not .you proved you are moron.
> Very clever to delete your comment which prompted my reaction calling my code dreadful. Good luck being suddenly moralistic I think it's going to bring you very far.
> Haha you're a joke.  Keep showing the whole world that you can't communicate respectfully.  Let's hope this question gets lots of views - you might even become famous.
> Why not set this as an answer then ?
> Hi **** - although it's admirable you wanted to help just click Close on questions like this. There's a huge problem with low-quality questions in the Unity tag
> Is that a question?
> Example 9 in what? I probably don't have it. Who do you think we are?
> if u can't help then what you are doing here?
> `will sort_using_ptrs be faster than sort_using_ptrs`? huh? when will A be faster than A?
> Ok listen boy  I dont hunt points.I've already have a job that I love.U voted  good night now.Let the user decide...
> Not even remotely similar **** go troll somewhere else dumbass. If you don't want to be called an idiot then learn to read and not ACT like an idiot. Try again.
> please help me immediately  - hahaahahahah
> your a bunch of cowards
> Admit it that you can't do it?
> Loved your comment *.. tried your nonsense suggestion*.
> fuuuuuuck. I will have to dig deeper then into AOP
> I can't believe I couldn't find a dupe to link this to.
> Is google broken today?  Why can't you google what a form tag does?
> Anonymous coward downvoter care to explain?
> You are wasting everyones time - that is a ridiculous restriction which you should've stated upfront.
> Ahh fuck IE....
> Why'd you even take the time out of your busy schedule to write the comment.
> Go fuck yourself ****. No life virgin
> You saying PuTTy is not an IDE is irrelevant go troll somewhere else. The warning is fixed now. You mad bro?
> What does this have to do with Java?
> This is a pretty stupid thing to do.  Making it shorter will actually reduce its readability (as seen in the answer below).
> Easy to answer that after reading the comments
> http://www.justfuckinggoogleit.com/
> Note: I'm not downvoting.
> Don't post C# answers on question tagged only VB.NET please. It wouldn't be accepted the other way round.
> way to avoid the question. Good luck handling milliones of records with access
> This OP is bad thusfor we downvote and flag it. Please provide what you have tried maybe some HTML css....
> SHUN THIS NON-PASTAFARIAN! :))
> I did it by myself now. It tooks me  2 min. You bunch of fucking idiots. Even don't know how to develop simple code....Go home
> **** U SOUND LIKE ANUS
> who cares about the research effort if it was a direct question ? fuckin retarded community
> If you haven't understood what `String` is after a couple of months I seriously would suggest you look into a different field.
> Please refer Changing my Major to Arts
> Please do not run this into production... never
> If you write your code in `C++` in similar way so I have bad news for you :(
> Read some books and do not troll for information!
> I swear it's like people just don't even try any more.
> Why would I do that? Don't post the question if it's not really what you're asking.
> Seriously your question is completely different now and this gets asked all the time. Why do you need personal assistance with such simple matters?
> You don't need to know how to do it to use Google. So the question remains why do you need personal assistance with such simple matters?
> Yes a monkey would find this terribly complex.
> You can choose today to start anew and not rely on others to perform the most simple tasks for you. Consider it a small step toward manhood.
> how much ...shut the fuck off
> Did you read the question?
> But Not working I tried. I dont knw why people are so stupid to mark my question as duplicate. I have writen that I seen many posts but didnt get the answer
> Please post working code that reproduces the problem otherwise you are just wasting others time.
> It's hiding so it's still open... I did not say he has to use the hide thing.. It was a suggestion. You can give a solution instead of bitching at my solution.
> I'd leave you to complete this quote by yourself:.....Empty barrels make the ...........Hopefully you know this one.
> How did this get upvoted as a good question?
> it doesn't compile because it is a code sample with missing thing (like the array for example). 
> Only an idiot would expect this to compile
> This user should be banned from SO
> The title alone hurts.
> yeah sure also you should add `for(int i = 0; i < 666; i++) Multidex.install(generateRandomContextFromInt(i));`
> Go fuck yourself
> **** more like 51 year old virgin
> ****? More like dead-wood. ;-)
> Your banter is about as shit as your sex life
> your banter is as bad as your sex life
> Get back to your tool porn you ugly virgin
> I challenge you to compile this code.
> Well it's a C++ question so I'd expect code provided in an answer to be correct. It's not very useful otherwise.
> No professional uses Wordpress. So I guess by default that includes you :)
> Vote how you want.  I'll just ask another.
> Ok. That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions not a place to dump your to-do list.
> calm down champion.I am a new in this area and have a lot of question.when ı read question in this form write my problem.you don't need  being rude!!!
> To whoever down voted my question it'd be nice if you left some sort of comment explaining why you down voted my question so I don't think that you're just being a dick.
> Please don't shout.
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it works and belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
> go home man you're drunk :\
> Read [ask] again.
> why are people downvoting my question.
> If you have a problem then gtfo scrubs thats why forums exists you dumbfucks -_-
> You're right it didn't go well due to that idiot who turned it into a chat about SO rules. I'm deleting it.
> Doctor my stomache hurts. Sorry we are no clairvoyants. You don't even give details.
> I just wanted an answer to my question not a sermon . Who are you anyway the question polizia?
> And PS i dont give flying fk about downvotes :D
> Guess who is the stupid one.
> Bro you have something to add here  add it if not fuck off it's that simple and thanks
> *the lines print properly with regular print statements* - Then why don't you just do that?
> U R Welcome. That would be nice if you try to understand the environment before using it.
> So what was that hard reading the compiler error message?
> yay for old f*rts getting back into coding!
> If you don't know the answer to this just don't answer at all. You're not helping at all ****
> Dude get a bloody life!
> actually i have been trying for two hours know and thanks for being a d*ckhead
> learn how to join tables
> fuck off man i asked a serious question
> But much more useful than your comment
> this has been asked a million times to get random-no-repeats YOU JUST SHUFFLE.
> having these problems with Azure in fucking 2016 and it doesn't help
> Use your brain and read [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) or ask your instructor.
> You said JSON. And you said regex. Now see the contradiction. Finally continue by using a JSON parser.
> that's shame to know even **SO** don't have answers to some questions.
> There is a way but it is almost impossible to find it because python has no documentation and the web has no search engines.
> EITHER NORMAL FORM POST (PAGE REFRESH) OR FORM POST WITH AJAX. NO OTHER POSSIBILITY
> my eyes hurt on seeing this code
> i can read it maybe you should get your eyes tested
> This is really an faked up community
> Your code invokes undefined behaviour at multiple levels. It is plain awful and useless. Use inline-assembler.
> stupidity at its best :3
> Maybe the problem is that pipe you're smoking in the facebook cover photo you just posted.  If you lay off the weed you might be able to concentrate better.
> `What do i do ?` Study find tutorials buy books watch videos ...
> Keep being a total dick. You still have to look at yourself in the face every day.
> you need to properly implement one of those algorithms. if you dont know that then you are going back to school!!
> sorry but this answer is completely out of sync with the question i.e it's a load of rubbish ;-)
> ***** cunt
> Stick to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
> Also whoever up voted this should have their voting rights suspended.
> Let's not.  I'm not interested.
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a homework site.
> simply spamming your sourcecode somewhere wont get you any help - nowhere. Go and ask your teacher.
> **** 1 v 1 me anytime any place
> StackOverflow is not here to do your code writing.
> well gee i would think exact output and source was detailed enough i guess im not up to your standards should i post memory dumps too? that detailed enough for you?
> How can you help others being dumb
> Would the retarded monkey that downvoted this working answer please explain why?
> Please fuck off
> **** go fuck yourself idiot
> You fucking morron!!!
> This is not a jQuery issue. Your variables are not magically reactive.
> You've been here long enough to know you have to show effort.
> **or something** the kids theses day seem incapable of actual thought
> c'mon now really? or is this some kind of code golf?
> Dont make negative vote it is reliable question and i face this issue in many devices so stop this headache and if anybody knows than comments it
> I think it is not ur business. I did not want the whole solution. I wanted the way to do it.
> Please check if the below solution answers the question.  If it does consider to accept the solution by clicking on the tick mark next to the vote.
> what of load of shite!
> Four star programming wow!
> Dude its a psuedocode not supposed to work unlike just talking in gibberish
> Four star programming wow! This must be really good code!
> OKAY BUT WHAT DOES THIS HAVE TO DO WITH PHP OR MYSQL? - See it just looks stupid don't use all caps.
> POST THE CODE YOU'VE WRITTEN!
> *sigh* read a book on it dude it's like something you learn in Comp Sci 100.00001
> This whole QA is embarrassing and sad.
> some trolls even downvoted **** just because he answered my question:)
> why do you still have the bizarre array-whatever thing there bra ?  you realise that's going to sit around on the net for like 10000 years  :O
> Then you need to say how or just be cranky like you're right now.
> Don't bump old crappy questions unless your intent is to actually improve them (adding backstory or complaining about a downvote is not improving your question).
> Don't nag me please. That's just annoying. I'm not your servant. I don't owe you anything. Now I don't feel like helping you.
> Uugh A 3 star programmer!
> Fuck off.Delete my questionI didnt get the answer I wished.So delete the fucking post **** BLACKASS indianfucker
> I want my post deleted indian black ass idiot
> delete the fucking postI didnt get the right answer
> Just fuck off indian black bitch
> DELETE THE FUCKING POST
> DONT FUCKING REVIEW MY POST WITH - IDIOTFUCKER
> And list refers to READING a list in the resultset.  I don't wipe the ass of the programmer.
> go away!!!!!!!!
> sorry didn't know about your stupid website roles
> Please use the mass in your head! **setting** does not mean **using**!
> utter rubbish...
> I fixed it so your simple mind can see through the MUD.
> Yes it is very clear. You are asking for someone to spend there time free of charge to coding it all for you.
> ... WTF IS THAAAAA ISSSSSSSSUE
> So you are asking others to write the code for you? What did you try so far?
> nice did you scribbled your gf/ex gf name?
> fucking missprint ! Thanks dude :)
> Terrible answer and terrible choice of date as an example!
> [First hit](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-May/132846.html) when googling your error message. This question does not show any research effort.
> I just took out the upvote given to you as there is an unfair downvote on my post.
> YOU ARE A WANKER FUCK OFF
> You have 50 databases and you don't know much about dba work... Poor you.
> WTF? OP edited the question with comment `Wordpress added as Tags explained the error`. Where is the explaning?
> Poor you indeed.  Transfer in Excel?  When there are real ETL tools out there?
> Isnt easier as write an question just google for `bash arrary tutorial`?
> i don't know because probably he is god or devil or angel or some spooky scientist who can see the future edit.
> Very fucking user's on this site never read the question always try to down vote new comer even they leave this palate form.
> Yes you can do it. But you have to make a good question and right format.
> Rod kinda kindergarden issue
> Switch your major to the humanities.  Programming doesn't seem to suit you.
> need? no want against their terms your a bottom feeder go back to the hole you came from.
> I do hope you are doing this as a infant school project and not for a company that is actually going to offer loans.
> Your a f'in Bitch
> my problem is now soloved   ......funke all of you no one help me this is fucking websit
> It is for you. Stop to act as child.
> From your general behavior not particularly this case.
> Why you chatting shit
> I do not understand what did you expect?! Or I did not need to answer at all that you click down vote button!
> serious minus 2 ? so you know that its not good question??????????SO TELL ME THE DAMNED ANSWER THEN GENIOUSES!
> you suck dude..
> Are you high?  
> ontopic: Please add your html code and what click event are you talking about?
> you're **very** weird ... just saying
> If you're constantly tend to have typos or incomplete statements (just like in your question title) no wonder you'll receive such errors.
> Do you know something named singlton?
> Great title - will really help others.
> .....I'm absolutely fucking retarded. I didn't include a main - ugh...just following and copy and pasting the provided code made me blank out. Thank you.
> nice homework assignment
> What part of Google is your friend don't you understand?
> Oh please. Try harder. And What part of Google is your friend don't you understand?
> Try asking a clear question. And:: What part of Google is your friend don't you understand?
> Please reply ASAP
> And naming it like this instead of using the proper API to decide on the folder is smart because of?
> This is to show you the error  why do you keep -1'ing all of my questions? =[
> Because you sometimes need a loop in a loop. What is your problem? Maybe you learn programming from a book not by looking at code?
> What good are tutorials if you don't make the effort?
> Oh and also please format your code it's hurting my brain.
> OP didnt say that. Take off you downvote please
> THIS IS FUCKING SHIT AWESOME TO KNOW THAT YOU KNOW SUCH IMPORTANT BULLSHITS
> *Groan* it's f'ing typo in your form. Off-topic.
> If a genius puts a -1 to the question the question doesn't need an answer. The answer doesn't need to be accepted.
> Backand Is A Horrible Framework. DO NOT Waste your PRECIOUS Time On Backand.
> So one  clarifies things how?  Microsoft telepathy update?  moron.
> How the hell would that work?
> Wishing it away got it big man
> You're going to be a great programmer some day.
> One bad question per bad question please.
> CAN I SAY A BAD WORD BECAUSE HOLY FUCK YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM WOW LIKE THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!! I WAS SO CLOSE TO GIVING UP!!! IT WORKED. THANK YOU!!!!!!
> **** Anyone with answers as this would have pressing reasons not to reveal their real name ...
> have you tried it yourself yet?  if so have you encountered a problem accomplishing your goal?  Or do you think SO is a do-your-homework-for-free site?
> All right! Have a good time ;)
> Who is the coward who downvoted my question without revealing himself?
> Thanks will figure it out F U
> i have showed what i have done now tell me and you ****r stay in your limits
> please fast reply so I can complete my work
> this is fucking awesome
> I used CREATE TABLE () to make the table now i'm trying to add another row to the table...  Is my question really that repulsive to you guys?
> You have a problem counting to three.
> thankyou atleast some one knows what I mean and isn't a whiner
> Someone with no idea how to do this might not be suitable to write this app.
> *..So I would like to know if I can call a php page* ~ Yes You Can Do It.
> The question on my mind is can you help yourself? If so don't tell me just post the MCVE. Otherwise stop wasting my time.
> How would you be able to answer your own question if you saw it tomorrow after a heavy night of drinking?  When you can answer that get back to us.
> This website is filled with a bunch of a*holes who are only great at critiquing instead of helping.
> every day the same question
> You can go to hell **** dam ass I am trying to learn not make money of a stupid question why would you think I want to take credit for this code?
> How the hell do you know if i put effort or not. Idiot
> It must be a joke. Now it's even worse.
> Hey smarties. I have java in the PATH. If you never encountered this error then you ain't helping me.
> Spare me your feeble attempts to think.  You're on your own on this one.  PS - the possessive is its.  Your English is as poor as your math.
> You updated(after deletion) the answer seeing my one. Better to upvote the answer which is correct.
> all you asshol** got me to loose points. go suck some cocks!
> utter rubbish...
> go go go downvoting :)
> maybe you should visit a doctor :-{  because we cannot see into your head
> You don't seem to have any idea about anything. Why would you think you can create something like this?
> vertical alignment ! similar issue. rest was CSS basics
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort. (One should atlas search stack overflow)
> i get that your answer is to fuck with the client's website dom which is a bad idea.
> And why arent you reacting on the other comments? The one with the firewall and other things?
> And what was the ip of your android device? You cann post the full ips as millions on earth have the same. Dont think its worth to keep it secret now.
> They are usually evaluated as 'fire this programmer' or 'assign a grade of F- '.
> And this helps how?
> Unsized array? Did you smoke pot before asking this question?
> **** doesn't have comprehension skills.
> This site is shit
> What did Google tell you?  There are plenty of articles on how to do that.
> You literally just copied and pasted that from my answer :) But I guess that's okay.
> Yeah **** i updated my Post. Its only one question now happy now?
> what have you tried so far?  You wont' be able to get help until you post some code for others to evaluate.  Also what the hell do you mean by rankings ?
> Well I appreciate you wasting my time.
> _Could some one help me as soon as possible with this._ Post a [MCVE] and maybe someone would be able to help you within the next 6-8 weeks.
> Why are you still breathing. Like seriously you're the dumbest fuck wad I know
> Shut up you stupid idiot.
> yes above solution not work
> Thats for your concern i just got a solution...
> [edit] your question and paste the code in the question - this looks like spam
> Where is the code you have tried?
> Wow nice design. What is it by the way?
> if your instructor told you to use eclipse for android programming change instructor.
> is there a way to get a textarea to stretch to fit its content without using php or javascript? - English do you speak it?!
> Are you trolling??
> Vote down if you are gay or just stupid...
> Do Not Learn Backand. Its piece of crap. Learn Firebase. Firebase is actually made by a good company(Google). About Backand? Um some trash company
> Because you don't understand pointers apparently.
> I posted a solution.  Please check if that helps
> Buddy if you're not sure and don't know the answer then comment instead of posting an answer !
> don't fucking downvote if you don't know the answer. If you know the answer then please help.
> SHOW US .H AND .M OF CUSTOM BUTTON ALSO WHERE YOU USED IT.
> Why don't you read an introduction to Objective-C? SCNR
> Why did you give minus to this post idiots. If you have a solution post it otherwise f.ck off.
> hahahah.....yeh.....copy cat..!!!
> proble proble yeah.
> What is this check how to ask a question on stack:-  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
> baby ? seriously? how about you stop munching curry? i'm a guy.
> ALT+F4 maybe? ;)
> Can you propose something reasonable instead of talking?
> If you dont know the answer  MOVE ON
> you must have a sad life to sit here to comment on unnecessarily questions :)
> To the morons who voted it down you haven't even read it in 30seconds that it took you to click the down arrow.
> this is like a middle school problem please dont post this type of question again
> cause i do shutup
> http://www.givemehope.com/beta.htm
> Another person who can't operate outside Eclipse.  It means you WAR packaging is incorrect or the URL is wrong.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404
> stop typing in your Indian accent.
> Look => `right syntax to use near 'long` <<< *Learn to read those and research the error*. It's part of coding.
> So the TA is dead?
> And I want a new car. Trade?
> Please someone be nice and write all my code for me so I don't have to do anything.  And oh yea contact me even though I didn't leave any contact information.
> A downvote huh?  cool!  F you buddy!
> what are you talking about idiot ! we have already established it is less.... get a grip !
> You normally SAY THANKS around here once someone helps you.  Did you get it working champ?
> I guess it does not help you. But then again ...
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just silly.
> He probably meant a lot instead of all could be because English isn't his first language.
> do you have a program to analyze here dude?? then cut the crap
> fuck you community and coding and stack!
> he probably forgot to login with his second user;)
> Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?
> Write Good code?
> If you have problems understanding the question please comment not answer!
> If you cannot use a debugger IDE or no you cannot develop software and you should stop trying until you have attained that necessary basic skill.
> if you're stuck in the US with crap bandwidth just move to switzerland or sweden!  mfg.
> It SHOULD of been posted because its my last option. Go take your 5 points and fuck yourself mate.
> If it means one less terrible question with the `unity3d` tag then its well worth it
> If you are going to ask for help with your homework you should atleast tell us what you have tried so far.
> Even though my comment has been removed (that's too bad). **** my sincerest congratulations I really mean that.
> Especially because it does not. Seems **** does not read before answering.
> thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot. I still trying to figure out why my first query didn't worked and why i have this fucking error on the filter operator
> I think OP can speak for himself if he wants something different. Mind your own business.
> why the fuck is this marked as solved?!?!?!?!?!!?!?
> OK now you have (implicitly) told us via the screenshot that you are doing this on Windoiws.
> Seriously disturbed people vote me down - but this is good code nevertheless. :)
> Why the fuck someone would close this thread as NOT CONSTRUCTIVE???
> The example is supposed to be *minimal* don't dump your homework here for others to debug.
> Because I need to know what that logic is --- so you don't know what you need to implement?
> Post code. Build a fiddle. Are we supposed to dig through your vague description and just guess what is happening?
> I HOPE YOU BURN IN HELL !
> CHILL!!!!!!!!!!!
> thank fuck I'm an atheist
> why not i see every one ask about xss  so why the fuck i can't get the answer?
> bhag ja beta abhi.. ladki ne bhi bol diya abhi ..Google Translate: Be part of girls also launched the beta right now .. now ..
> The f%#k voted for SuperUser???
> Ok then you go and help
> Here is one upvote for you to encourage making good examples in the future.  I am fair and balanced in voting (unlike somebody)
> It is interesting who is that idiot who down-voted the question?
> Er how did you post the question? Are you a bot? Answer please?
> Dont put images of the error message for f*ck sake! Copy/Paste it!
> Then do it right. OP is not helped with 'almost working' code.
> Nothing useful in this shit
> I don't see Java here.
> What the actual fuck is this?
> then go to hell bro
> This is 2016. Don't use `File` use `Path` and `Files`. Also there is no guarantee that this will work anyway. Why don't you just delete the file yourself?
> Try this link: http://tinyurl.com/gmpeyat
> What is a shits count? Number of toilet visits?
> Wrong. Do not post your answers without trying once.
> Yeah... 'How to access content of a folder's file in c?' as the title then blatantly writing C++ code is not going to go down well at all:(
> <sarcasm>You should pick some more unrelated language tags</sarcasm>
> Very bad code please hire someone or follow some tutorials on google.
> I'm voting for you guys to mind your own business and let other people get the information they want.
> My question is very specific and only about a small part of the posted code. You obviously did not read it. Pull the stick out of your ass.
> Then don't use code highlighting.
> I'm really familiar with Excel and this logic would be working perfectly in that... don't know why java has to be such a dick about it...
> HERESY! BURN THE WITCH! :P
> Buy an Windows computer? It's better anyway ;')
> So you found the answer but it doesn't fit you? What?
> and he answered himself so he doesnt give the answer to me! :D great user.
> What the hell... what do you mean? Please clarify your question
> put more memory (not into the computer but into your head) if its not clear enough :)
> I have uploaded whole code...pls help me..!
> Actually it was a question from the contest held today people who appeared posted their questions. Can you help solve this instead of joking around?
> YOU HAVE ALL IN THE EXCEPTION(do you know how to read?) notification is not a JSONArray but JSONObject
> You must be kidding this answer is plain wrong. Returning from one of the functions certainly does not affect whether the next ones are executed or not.
> `can't quite understand` what part did you not understand? How are you a code junkie??
> You proclaim yourself to be a code junkie and has been on SO for 4 years yet your last few questions demonstrate no effort on your part so no sympathies from me.
> `int main()` is the recommended and only official program entry. `void main()` is for losers.
> not very helpfull ... means only it does not work more or less ! A bit arrogant comments are not nice !
> Nobody here cares about opinions; state facts or nothing at all.
> look up a class library.
> then what do you need mr.know it all?
> It depends on what you're trying to do with your code mr. know nothing.
> I'm getting kind of pissed off. No-one knows how to do something so everyone downvotes? Go f*** yourselves. Pricks.
> Yeah i did!
>
> But the language files are cached.. This is fuckin shit!
>
> I have to change the locale path every time I did some changes..
> This is not learning center or we are not doing here educational projects. Do your own work and if you face any problem then come here to consult by showing us your work
> https://xkcd.com/327/
> well no need to be a dick about it. people over validate all the time assuming people dont know their own name etc.
> Have fun being rejected by Apple =)
> taught* lol sorry for not saying FUNCTION my bad
> Obviously you didn't have anything to contribute to this for help so I'm not sure why you're still here............
> That's the opposite of what he asked! DOn't people read!?!?!
> are you afraid of new lines and spaces? make your code more readable
> post some quality answers
> Nobody accepts the answer if it is OffTopic. I Think you need to consult a good doctor.
> You ask What am I missing? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve voting to close
> Can you actually answer the question or are you solely trying to dispute how relevant the question is to django?
> I don't know.. would it work? :| you should try it before asking here.. that's how you learn programming.. to answer you shortly: yes
> FUCK JOU *****
> What the silly question
> My suggestion is read how to ask a question and get your acts together.
> I've heard rumors that similar things can be achieved with a language called `JavaScript`  (It's supposed to be the new shit the cool kids use ;)
> If someone could give me a golden toilet I would be very grateful.
> Actually you missed an occasion to shut up. If you not going to help you are not obligated to respond. Just disappear.
> Shit one second
> My *chief* relief is you not coming to grief with this question.
> DONT EVER DO BACKEND Guys!!! Its the worst! Try firebase or Node.
> Why are you even using Backand..... The worst choice
> Why are you using Backand? Please use firebase or Node.
> ........ http://tinyurl.com/gtkkmaw
> Oh yes down vote more. I searched stackoverflow nothing. I searched google nothing. I make a question and now I'm an asshole. Cool!
> Not sure if I'm more impressed by the cheekiness of the poster or the stupidity to think that someone would answer such a question.
> With more of them such as `-vvv` :) And if you are no more clever post the output to the edited question.
> how the f*ck this connect to my question? really...... lol
> If you don't know the answer just say so or don't comment. don't give empty advice and mark my question duplicate you dumb cunt  ^ ^
> My Question is above your Low IQ level ; U don't have the neurons to solve it  even after spending lifetime in coding  u snitch
> So u gathered ur fagot low IQ army and reported my question .... U fucking looser ... You probabily suck in your real life to faggot ..
> God why is everyone on this site such a dick ! Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth .. well im fucking sorry .. sorry im trying to learn.
> If this is illegible .. then get your eyes tested. The only waste of time and bandwidth here is your unhelpful unneeded worthless comment.
> lolllllllllllll fuck you for deleting my answer bitches
> a) run a clustering algorithm b) get a result.
> Don't cast your mallocs is something people say on stack overflow to make themselves feel superior.   It's the least of your worries whether you cast it or not.
> your problem is: you don't care. you blindly copy shit from the internet.
> Nobody sees your code.  Perhaps what you need is a psychic.  Call 1-800-MYPSYCHIC for an appointment.
> Read he site rules. Any maybe you should go to the basics - once you get out of school you are expected to know your stuff not cheat around.
> seriously the SHIT advice you get on git is so much. thanks
> Enlighten me on where OP states that it is an embedded resource
> Give a man a fish
> Please don't try to over smart just by giving a negative. either Solve or stay away.. such a noisy and nasty thing u have done..
> some code maybe?
> can anyone help me to solve this asap ????
> wtf is the downvote for?
> this site is so fucked.
> What the fuck is your problem guys? Issue is pretty well documented (visually and in text) just didnt bother copying the longass code here.
> English must not be disrespected too.
> I suppose you're not populating it in your garage I mean WHEN and HOW WHEN in the lifecycle of the page.
> Goddamn. Stop copying and write your own codes. Did you expect to completely understand the codes of someone else if you can't even write up something similar yourself?
> awesome. if that's the answer you needed pls tick it to keep this damn site tidy.  rock on
> The question is why the fuck you can't use this??? They inject 'b' on the 'this' in regular javascript it works but on angular no way
> Dude if I haven't have found your post I would have been jerking off on this issue till i drew blood..
> No your mom.​​
> phir tum logo ne apni maa chudai downvote karke :x
> What don't you test ?
> Are you all nuts and hypocritical? The OP wrote I want my iPhone5 App to scale (fill the screen) properly on iPhone6. My answer is exactly an answer to the question.
> do you think i am a slave to you ?
> Somebody has a huge thirst of reputations no matter the way to obtain them.
> Please search before posting.
> thank you  you helped me a lot. unfortunately I can't give you score since some gays give me -1 for all of my questions !!! anyway  thank you
> Strong pong of processed meats...........
> So you can get 8 upvotes for telling the OP his question doesn't deserve answering. Lots of dicks on this site.
> So your dummy'ness prevented to read the full Q&A you've already found?
> ...and who a those people to read that sht?
> half? are you serious? what is the point of asking a question then? first you are claiming it to be a duplicate and now you are referring half solution.
> Even that is nonsense.
> Please make your own homework instead of putting it up here
> You Sir are seriously lazy and should learn to do your assignments by *yourself*.
> Thanks for sharing.  Did you have a specific programming question?
> Go find some work dont waste time here
> It does not work is a truly useless thing to say. What happens or doesn't happen? What have you done to try to diagnose/fix the problem?
> Please read my original post before commenting.
> Alright so I just got destroyed on my third encounter with Stack Overflow. I refuse to believe that I am this incompatible with the community.
> To gain experience or do you wish us to do your homework?
> As a moderator I feel like you should know better than to answer terrible questions.
> you just went and edited your code after I posted my answer and I stand getting downvoted for it. and you didn't mark it as an edit. gee thanks. never mind I deleted it.
> You're a fucking asshole.
> sorry if it bothers you...solution please!!!
> Go back to school!
> Oh wait... :P
> Come on then bruv fight me!
> Meet me market gardens! Me and **** will bruck you up fam!
> Don't use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  It doesn't really make sense and you are using a MySQL (mis)feature that you probably don't understand.
> Is this a joke question? Look at the `if` condition!
> I'm afraid that you need to understand stuff first.
> Would it even allow me to? And is it that hard to click two links?
> O yea
> You are everything wrong with this site and I'm sick of reading your drivel along with your code.
> NO! FOR GODE SAKE! If i wrote standart swift file it means in a .swift file
> how should we know? we have nothing to do with this repository you're using...
> obviously yes. Thats a dumb question
> stfu bich answer the question or gtfo.
> GO fuck youself. idiot.
> Why are you trying to write network code when you cannot handle basic string operations and cannot debug?
> as well as being syntactically broken
> delete this comment now wat the f**ck
> `MapViewOfFile` and `UnmapViewOfFile` -- I suggest you actually read what these functions do.
> I' m asking how to parse essentially...if you won't help then go.
> Yeah i hope you email is ready for dick pics
> `...` Unexpected tolken `...`undefined `...`wtf?
> Is Google down again?
> Of fuck that simple.. thanks man!
> I'd like a toilet made out of gold but it's just not in the cards
> So you want to avoid a recursive approach to traverse a data structure of arbitrary depth and composition?
> you know what... why dont you go fuck yourself and edit the question towards closing the account. fucking superfly anyway... the fuck
> Your momma is a replacement of $nbsp;.  SNAP!!!! :)
> No because your implementation sucks
> It would be nice if you marked your own answer as correct so that others can see the solution.
> The upwork question is a shit?
> That's also true. BTW I wasn't missing this sh*t really. It took two months after the suspension to get back to the feud :D Gonna downvote randomly pretty soon
> didn't please check the answers you say is this post an answer? you could ask for more details in comments  not to post something instead
> Study a grammar book first?
> Does not change anything from what he said the OP
> Please leave this site.
> Have you tried [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)?
> now who's copying others ....
> You want to sort an array? Have you tried searching for a solution? There are literally thousands of examples of how to sort an array on the Internet.
> **** Feel free to not reply again.
> Uh-oh. He knows about the grey screen.
> What part of worked for button for me for button Background is not clear?   Were you harmed by giving it a try?
> Then your task setter doesn't have a fuckin' clue what he's doing and the best thing you can do is to find a new task setter.
> NO this is YOUR interpretation and it is wrong. The only thing clear is that he doesn't want to code it in the action and don't you dare downvote the answer
> I'm not gonna answer your question but here's a bunch of shit to read.
> I can promise that it will break.
> Actually the questions is for people that know about the topic no for beginners like you man
> Try this System.out.print(Goat Meat)
> ik can't except this answer. stackoverflow is a fucking lier. at least tell me something i can use.
> You're joking right?
> Let us not.  You've already wasted too much of my time.  Go think of something useful to do.
> I couldn't give a fuck about bounties they are stupid.  Are you serious?
> What are you taking about??!? READ [ASK]!
> Sorry I don't have any more time to feed the trolls.
> I didn't downvote some asshole did. Anyway thanks man I get it.
> You should've editted this answer instead of posting twice
> Are you really want help or just ask a question for entertainment or time-pass?
> What *is* your question?
> Alright chill out
> ```

Comment: I hope they pay you enough.  Well, surely they do.  Is constantly being forced to look at the toilet bowl how you want to spend the next 10 years of your life?  It is just money.

Comment: Mmm... are we sure those are "rude"? Maybe I have a serious thick skin but how is "How to delete this question?" rude?

Comment: @Braiam I'm not judging the content, this was pulled based on the flag type on the comment.

Comment: I don't look at that on a daily basis @HansPassant if I did, then I'd question my decision making skills. This was a one-time request and other CMs pitched in on the review to minimize the impact.  But now, I'm going to have some rum.

Comment: There's also a `+1. Thanks.` in there. People been misclicking their flags.

Comment: Perfect, thanks this is a good start, as you may know we are already testing with twitter comments, but it mostly find typo question, still wondering why, I will build a model this week and we see what it bring to SO.

Comment: I don't suppose we can get them conveniently delimited or escaped so that they're all on one line? As it is, there are several (I think) which span multiple lines, and since this would be fascinating to train a bot on I'd like to have something with clear beginnings and ends.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I have no problem with them in current format, I think the job that they have done is excellent.

Comment: Probably not at this time @QPaysTaxes.

Comment: Just to show you that this can work we removed these comments (found exclusively by NLP) from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110661/how-to-embed-php-and-swf#comment63655260_38110661) , 5 minutes before you answered

Comment: @PetterFriberg But Stack Exchange questions aren't just for the original asker :P

Comment: Is it just me or do many of the comments not appear to be rude at all?

Comment: It's possible @Mysticial, as I said I didn't judge the content. But users have the tendency to get a bit overzealous when it comes to flagging comments and mods are lenient about processing the flags because they are comments and most of the time aren't necessary to keep around.

Comment: Are these by any chance ordered in any way? The ones towards the middle of the list seem to be "stronger" than the ones at the top. :P Thanks for posting this along with everyone else who made it possible. This list is amazing.

Comment: Ha! How appropriate that the very last one is "Alright chill out". I'd imagine a history of rude/offensive flags eventually has a negative impact for the user, but what about the comments that obviously aren't? Do you guys go over a user's individual comments before you put the "naughty" checkmark on their account?

Comment: @Mysticial There is no real order to the data.

Comment: There's a record of deleted comments associated with each user's account, @MikeM. If a moderator wishes to look for a history of abusive behavior, they'll check that... At which point, it's on their judgement whether or not anything happens. I'm sure you can picture the sorts of comment histories that tend to lead to a talking-to.

Comment: @MikeM. As of today, mods [now have an easy way to review all flagged comments by a user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243715/allow-moderators-to-see-a-summary-of-flags-against-a-users-comments/280681#280681).  If they find a user acting inappropriately, they will act as needed.

Comment: Wow.  I am really truly offended by the comment `You are welcome!`.  How can someone write something like that and not get instantly banned?

Comment: You tha real MVP. welcome to the internet. You look so confused. There are a sure load of prats on this site.  I think you need something better to do. yep you go it.bright guy.  fvgbhnjmk.kjmc nm.  What have you tried ?

Comment: @Mysticial - Part of it is because we lack the context these comments were made in.

Comment: People need to read more Calvin & Hobbes so they won't flag `Of course it's code you insensitive clod!` any more

Comment: The pattern Andy found was quite successful, so was it implemented in the system?

Comment: FI: This answers has a follow-up question here [To nuke, or not to nuke- that is the question:](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question), relative to the classification of this feed and particular "snarky" comments

Comment: Make a "best-of" please! ;P

Comment: _Is your mom off topic too?_ This is gold.

Comment: Could I make a book out of this?

Comment: Man, the list contains even death threats. But also some really useful false-positives such as *"OP asked for a C++ solution. Not for a C/C++ solution and neither for a C solution. Let's try to make one's life easier by not providing C solutions where none are asked.".* Good list!

Comment: That list is great fun, it's hilarious. Why do we have so many over sensitive nannies around trying to remove them? This is political correctness running wild. Don't we have better things to do with our time? Death threats need to go, though, yes.^

Comment: @bluefeet and chance for similar thing [for posts deleted as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292612/obtaining-text-of-spam-offensive-posts)?

Comment: Wow! This is crazy...
How are things like `Much easier in android...`, `Maybe should read about Accessing array values?` and `What have you tried so far?` offensive???

I see `What have you tried so far?` on so many questions, and this is often actually helpful if the question asker is new to the site.

Comment: `SO isn't a free tutorial / guide service`  -  this is a good point, what's wrong with it?

Comment: `It would be nice if you marked your own answer as correct so that others can see the solution.`. who the hell flagged that?

Comment: if this is indicative of the entire the list that they used to train with, it has already failed, there are so many false positives in here that every comment will just get flagged and deleted immediately. Maybe that is not a bad thing in the end.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371635/offensive-search-results) (TL;DR: the comments still show up in search).

Comment: @IanKemp when you're on the wrong side of the highway everyone you see is going in the wrong direction. Have you considered changing back to the correct side? On a more serious note, I see NAA flags being handled and posts deleted with record speed these days. Are you sure you're [using the flag right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak This data clearly shows that NAA flags are treated as "do not accept unless absolutely positively obviously not even the most basic attempt to answer", whereas rude/abusive flags get treated as "accept if there could be even the suggestion of hurt feelings". The answer to this is the answer to the following questions: Which is more damaging to the site's quality; irredeemable trash answers, or sarky comments? Which is more damaging to the site's SEO potential; deleting irredeemable trash answers, or nuking sarky comments?

Comment: @IanKemp let's face it: link-only crap and other kinds of garbage answers _won't_ destroy the site. The kind of posts to which NAA applies have no chance of being used by noobs, except for link-only which does get deleted. The real threat is _low-quality_ answers, which is not mod responsibility. Those have to be downvoted to oblivion and deleted by high-rep users. Now, I don't personally think that snark will ruin the site either _per se_, but comments have always been second-class citizens so you should never develop an emotional bond to them. (to be continued...)

Comment: Of course the real problem is that the border between snarky and outright rude is fuzzy, and it's sort of understandable if authorities err on the friendly side. That being said, I'm certain a few of the mods delete whatever that gets flagged. But then others are likely to shrug such flags off. It's a gamble, really. But you never see the comments of yours that _were_ flagged but don't get deleted.

Answer (score 21):

I don't have the data, but I did find some other things that should help. I find this type of thing very interesting, and I have already done similar work with [detecting recommendation question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280085).

---

### The Summer of Love

Given the importance that Stack Exchange puts on niceness, it makes sense that there has been interest on similar things in the past. [Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494/can-i-have-a-dump-of-rude-abusive-comments?cb=1#comment359271_326494) alluded to this in the comments above, and I think it deserves elaboration, especially for users like me who joined after that all went down.

The "Summer of Love" was a campaign in 2012 which looked to ensure that Stack Overflow didn't turn into one of those "old" communities that complains about kids these days (aka new users) and yells at them to get off their lawn. The point was to ensure that the community stayed nice, especially to new users, which are necessary to maintain and grow the population of any site.

It makes sense that [finding unfriendliness](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/) was one of the goals. Comments were submitted to Mechanical Turk to be scored on a scale of friendliness/unfriendliness. (Note: the link to the data was broken, but it's been fixed.) If you look at the data, it contains `@usernames`, so you may have to do some processing.

---

### Other options for data

While having "native" data sets is important for machine learning, I think that data from Twitter, for example, could be useful if you want more data. There may be false positives (for example, saying *[god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/god) doesn't work* isn't blasphemy; it's actually on-topic), but it's probably not going to be significant if you are using any decent detection method.

I have found some data on [crowdflower](https://www.crowdflower.com/data-for-everyone/) that was done on the subject of hate speech and Twitter. It's a [.csv file](https://www.crowdflower.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/twitter-hate-speech-classifier-DFE-a845520.csv) with almost 15,000 rows.

There are a significant number of academic papers have been written on the subject too:

- [Detecting Offensive Language in Social Media to Protect Adolescent Online Safety](https://faculty.ist.psu.edu/xu/papers/Chen_etal_SocialCom_2012.pdf)
- [Smokey: Automatic Recognition of Hostile Messages](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/IAAI/1997/IAAI97-209.pdf)

  - Not to be confused with our Smokey...
- [Detecting Offensive Tweets via Topical Feature Discovery
  over a Large Scale Twitter Corpus](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/papers/sp250-xiang.pdf)

  - Given the similarity between Tweets and comments (short length, @mentions, potentially relaxed language/style, etc.), this is a very relevant source.

---

### SEDE Query

I've also created a simple query for detecting profanity with SEDE (of course it will only find comments that are still around or recently deleted).

I'm using `LIKE` statements. While my real query uses actual profanity, I have toned down the language for my answer here for the sake of politeness:

```sql
Select top 100
postid as [Post Link]
,text
from comments
where
   lower(text) like '%[,.?! ]st[u*]pid[,.?! ]%'
or lower(text) like '%[,.?! ]j[e*]rk[,.?! ]%'
-- etc.
```

Of course, `LIKE` statements are more similar to globs than regexes, which are less powerful. TSQL does not support regex matching, so it's the closest thing that can be used in SEDE queries.

---

Related:

- [Make community comment moderation a more public process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213694)
- [How can we avoid comments intended to be helpful being perceived as unfriendly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141706)

Comment: Thanks Laurel, I will study all you links more in depth later, yes we have started with twitter comments and a friend is trying to contact the university of Ottawa to get data from this [project](http://www.eiti.uottawa.ca/~diana/publications/Flame_Final.pdf), furthermore charcoal has provided me with data from posts. So yes, we are trying to push forward, but I still think not only for my project but in general SO should consider to provided a dataset since the success of any machine learning system depends on data provided.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I found a great set of data (see my edit). Of course it's not perfect, but it should be a good start.

Comment: great thanks for your help, if you like to see progress come and visit me in the Finder room on my profile

Comment: I sent Stack an email regarding that broken link to the "snarky comments" data from the blog, I'll see what happens and report back.

Comment: I don't want to be the database that would process as many OR as there are offensive words in the dictionnary. Guess that's all we have though.

Comment: If anyone is still interested, I got an email from Stack saying that they've fixed the link to the dataset in the "[Finding unfriendliness](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/)" blog post, so it's now available.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you are working on a promising feature and deserve support for it. Nevertheless, I'm afraid that providing the requested list would cause too much collateral damage like many have already commented. I will try to summarize the objections here.

- Those comments were deleted for *good reason*. They were seriously hurting individuals and making them visible again risks hurting them again. In most cases, the missing context would probably make displaying them acceptable but this might not always be true.
- Comments including user names clearly cannot be made visible again for the above reason. While it would be a fairly simple exercise to censor all `@…` instances and moderately complicated to filter all usernames from the database, there will be more subtle cases (think of “Hey you armed ferret, you …” or “You … platonic solid!”) that will be understood by the humans involved but practically impossible to filter out reliably by a machine.
- Even if the offended user is not identifiable without context, those who were involved in the fight back then will be able to re-identify the posts and in the worst case re-engage in the dirty business.
- Some posts might have contained material that should never be made visible to the public again. Think of a user accidentally posting their credit card number and subsequently being made fun of. Other posts might contain material that would be outright illegal to make publicly visible.

So I think that a different solution is needed. Here are some ways I can think of that would be viable in my opinion.

- If the feature you're working on is considered valuable by enough users, maybe a moderator (or SE employee) can be put on vacations of their daily duties and join your team training the system without giving out the data.
- Although not a quick solution, maybe you can convince enough people to elect you or one of your teammates as moderator. I have supported [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/election/7#post-33617646) during the last election phases for this very reason.
- Go the hard route and do what Andy did, training your system by manually classifying each comment it processes. Given the level of community support I currently see here, you might get volunteer helpers, although you'd have to be careful not to make the offensive comments publicly available again for the classification.
- Eventually, a feature could be implemented that allows querying “Was the comment with ID *X* deleted by a moderator as rude or offensive?” Then your bot could aggregate a list of IDs it *would* flag and after some time it could use the API to verify its decisions.

However you *train* the system, I hope you will be careful about how it stores its internal knowledge. It should not be possible to re-identify personal offenses from the knowledge database.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, we are moving forward since we also have fun doing this (see my comment on Laurel post to understand how), I personally do not think it's so difficult to setup a dataset with 3000 comments that will not create fire again. Yes probably a mod needs to go through them, so it becomes more and issue is the time spent worth the effort, and in the end my meta is all about this. Does the community want a public dataset of bad comments?, is it worth the job?, can it also be useful for the community?

Comment: Just a suggestion, once the raw training data gets processed through (at least the one we're currently using) a training algorithm which produces a model, the original input is not recoverable from the generated model. Worst case scenario, would a system exclusive to mods where they can run a script that will pull in the super secret insults and run the trainer be practical?

Answer (score 2):

Per [Offensive search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371635/offensive-search-results), putting the offensive comments in a code snippet does not hide them from search results. However, since they take up *so much* space as spoiler text, I've posted this in a separate answer. Taryn can use this to edit the accepted answer or, if it's better to not have the answer be so long, I can just delete this later.

> Of course it's code you insensitive clod! Raytracing or geometric definitioan can be solved by doing recursion not that it *has* to be but it is one way.
>      +1 ExceedsThreshold -1 first example. If you think you're being clever you aren't.
>      Mexican police takes a random african animal and pour soda with chili into its nose until it admits that it's an elephant.
>      Ever heard of Ebooks?
>      You're not a real developer if you've never left an apology comment for the next person! :P
>      Pure science? WTF does that mean? You think NaCl doesn't come in a 1:1 relationship?
>      Seriously? Did you even bother to look at the documentation for UIButton?
>      Just remember that they hate you http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001065.html
>      Care to explain why?
>      You are welcome!
>      agreednext up what does SET stand for in SQL and var in C#?
>      Don't worry **** what you said makes sense.
>      Yes and you can find it in any SVN manual or book; which you really should read so you use SVN right.
>      I like the obfuscation in your answer text.  Makes it very hard to read.  Ever heard of the Enter key?
>      You must live in a box then.
>      Yeah im a baby give it to me in a bottle lol.
>      I think we've reached a new low of laziness.
>      youre funny dude :P
>      I find it quite charming actually
>      Did you think I was talking about some other Rails framework that's written in a different language?
>      While you did a wonderful job of restating the problem I'm afraid that doesn't constitute an answer.
>      Suddenly your avatar makes sense.
>      Damn the MICROSOFT. Thought I love it it never follows what the world follows. They are proud of it but sometimes it becomes pain in the ass.
>      Since it's Thanksgiving I'll thank you for bothering to read my question. Your answer on the other hand is worthless.
>      the curly quotes fsck with the code parsing
>      Your syntax is junk.  Is that the problem?
>      I second the beatings.
>      Wouldn't you want the default value to be zero for it to be as fast as possible?  Sounds like a good default to me.
>      Let me guess are you a perl programmer?
>      Oh Lord.  There was an earthquake in Haiti you know.
>      Why wouldn't you have already checked the manual?
>      Don't waste your time trying to make this work it isn't worth it.
>      Agree but -1 for answering a dupe.  You should know better.
>      Because ******* is mildly insane.  `espresso-mode` is the Javascript mode for sane people.
>      -1 useless answer
>      Works on my machine.  Somebody is blocking you.  Are you Chinese?
>      Most probably **** gave it to me because his code is perfect.
>      Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm for sorting algoritms to be able to sort your data as efficient as possible 
>      This is pretty fec-ked up.  There's no reason to have to deal with clock disparity these days.  Post to serverfault.com to figure out how to setup a time server.
>      Why on Earth would you want to imitate something this butt-ugly?
>      I would upvote this answer but I just hate this oh downvote me you senseless clods bullshit.  Especially repeated twice.
>      shut up sir.....
>      There are stacks of examples out there. Try searching...
>      I'm looking for a Klein bottle with some wine in it. Any suggestions?
>      Its called your brain. If you can't competently review code ask someone else to do it.
>      ANYONE??? HELLOOOO???
>      Step one: turn off your caps lock key.
>      you can convert it into seconds and then compare. I believe you've learned that in your school. 
>      there is a very good reason not too. But thanks for the reply.
>      gaand phat gai sabki koi nahi bata paaya.
>      [Get a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).
>      Forget you know Java you'll never learn C++ that way.
>      taking a couple hours to start on a 3ghz cpu is hardly good to just wait once.
>      You asked: can u tell me which one is better to use to fill a datatable dataadapter... and now you say you said one or the other...
>  goddamnit Novice is not the word
>      Where exactly does it say jQuery in the question? jQuery != JavaScript and in any case he asked an HTML/CSS question not a JavaScript question.
>      Your professor's a retard.  Not that strange really.
>      Haha what a retard yeah if I tried to build then I would have realized that :)
>      Stupid solution he's don't need that
>      Do not clone my post
>      «my program explodes in a spectacular blaze and I weep» — awesome.
>      Are the typical dangers not enough?
>      jesus I thought i was going mad thank you!
>      Maybe b/c people like you that don't make useful feedback are the reason...
>      Everyone who thinks he can wiggle around writing a real parser by applying regex instead needs his nose wiped in the shit this inevitably ends in.
>      hey thanks for the help...so what was this dependency for commons-io..i read a tutorial and it told me to include this one
>      Your quotes are inconsistent. I recommend single quotes for JavaScript and double quotes for HTML attributes and JSON.
>      With a reputation > 7000 you might know where the Python documentation is.
>      there is no need of downvote. huh wht to do with this kind of people.
>      Request for answerers: point to a place where **** can get a really good string sanitizer instead of coding it himself.
>      1) im not stupid
>
>      2) Thanks for the answer
>
>      3) I think stackoverflow.com was for asking questions if you dont want to answers.. just.. dont answer!
>      suggest another alternative
>      There is no programming question here.  You have an invalid entry in your file.
>      omfg what is that?
>      here comes an Exception object reference not set to an instance
>      Is this a troll?
>      wow i am a retard :) thank you very much. been trying to fix this for the last hour
>      look can you please stop posting such unrelated rubbish. Posted 1 hour ago cannot accept for another 2 days IF **I** think this is the best answer
>      I did not **** and I want't angry or anything like that. Did I said something offensive? :)
>      -1: Admittedly iphone camera on google doesn't give you any useful links but spend an extra 30 seconds and google for iphone camera tutorial and you're done.
>      Okay this one gets my funniest post of the day.  :)
>      shut up............
>      Even if the aplpication si running ocal it is called remote debuging sigh! Look at the answer below it explains it.
>      That means that you have fucked-up the routes. Come on new question!
>      To add onto that there's also now an hqdefault.jpg for the HQ version of the thumb
>      This shows remarkably little effort.
>      Wow what a terrible mess.
>      Its the number of fucks will not reduce the gestation period
>      `sql-server` AND `oracle` tags? And an explanation as well? It's homework isn't it?
>      If somebody asked me that question I would want to punch them in the face. And then answer Apples and oranges
>      is there any reason for word `issue` in the topic?
>      +1 Good answer to a poor question.
>      ⌘+W... [9chars]
>      So I just make my iPhone storyboard english and translate every ViewController on `ViewDidLoad`?
>      Huh.  Odd workflow (not saying it is wrong... just different).  I'd suggest opening the console output in a separate window or pane.
>      man this is a programming forum not trig.
>      wtf? how is this a real question?
>      Stupid question: Have you set the UIWebView's delegate to `self`?
>      I select already exist ABPerson using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.
>      Oh! ok thanks! I will try it out tomorrow! :)
>      Have you bothered to actually look at the PHP docs and see how to do it or do you just want somebody to spoonfeed you the codez
>      In the addressbook?  There could be hundreds depends on the user.  In the XML attachment file it will be about 20 max
>      Right.  You're doing arbitrary lookup which is what hashes are for.
>      So you can add `google` if it's your favourite search engine...
>      blog post my foot. a whole function to resemble original function's behavior unknown to authior
>      here's a pojo:  public class Pojo{}  You should totally copy that and use ctrl-v in eclipse whenever you need a pojo.  Or are you talking about generating Java Beans?
>      And maybe taking a class on databases. Or even just reading all the way through a tutorial.
>      You should not use w3schools as reliable.  See www.w3fools.com for the reasons why.
>      This shows zero effort on the author's part.
>      wow now that is lazy... I can't believe people are actually willing to help you? :S
>      +1 for being second :)
>      I would beg to differ.  This site (and platform) is massively successful...
>      God bless you you improbably thorough m*****f****r.
>      In Excel there is a magic key which very few are aware of (**unfortunately**) :( And that Key is `F1`
>      I did it **** thanks for all the help! Final solution finished thanks for all the help Everyone.  Cant believe those Aholes -1 repped me
>      Probably a lot of java programmers like me that tried Hello .trim() before trying the internets.
>      learned a fake-language' was that javascript or BASIC?
>      You should really learn the basics of web-programming before creating a web page if you don't even know the difference between client-side and server-side script languages.
>      Is this homework?
>      hypercrypt it is a client's requirement.Client is female and she hates all the URL and website address stuff. :)
>      Old question but wouldn't UDP work better for this?
>      Wow didn't know you can convert HTML tables into Excel files...
>      nvm got it.  No thanks to you.
>      He likes to ask questions
>      If API documents are hard for you to read then you should *learn* how to read them first.
>      And the award goes to the Asp.net team for most retarded class name...
>      Read the documentation -- **** is correct and the documentation will tell you how to do this.
>      RTFM or ask a new question.
>      You never asked a question.
>      For anyone wondering how you call this function. Do this ... if([self hasConnectivity] == NO) { // not connected } else {  //connected do your stuff}
>      *a bit lost*  Seek 'jtextarea+javadoc' and 'jtextarea+java+tutorial' to find yourself and so much more.  Always try that before asking on SO.
>      witch! burn him!!
>
>      ..it worked for me though thanks
>      Yeah. Post the real error.
>      Do you have any objective-c programming experience?
>      damn it... u just beat me to it
>      Please don't answer old threads that have accepted answers given years ago. Use your energy to help in current questions instead
>      lack of research effort
>      Take your other questions you asked and mark the answers you think is right.
>      my eyes!!!!.............
>      Is there a live page with this code that you can link to?
>      Read a C++ book.
>      Don't post question for silly mistakes. You actually wrote the code to get the text from the edittext in the oncreate() itself.
>      You're an idiot.
>      R u crazy ****??I will give you -1 for this stupid answer.I am not asking for this.Please read my question carefully...
>      a ton of research eh ? this is the second hit on google: http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/postcodes.shtml
>      Downvoters don't have a cow... what do you want?  Sometimes you just want to take the first item from a dictionary whatever that item happens to be.
>      +1. Thanks.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
>      Did you consider reading the documentation?
>      The answer links to the docs what more would you want?
>      Why do you even care?
>      nut-searing pain - couldn't have said it better.
>      WTH? TIA? This Is Awkward? Typical Ignorant American?
>      I know this great site you can go to find tons of stuff like that. Here's the [link](http://google.com)
>      I don't think this is even worth asking.. a small google search would of given you the answer.. or just stick with trial and error and experimenting.
>      The downvoter probably never wrote a well-behaved C program with any kind of resource.
>      Pls add a comment atleast for a -ve vote :)
>      ever try google?
>      Doesn't work because all of the fragments are marked as visible. Please read the other answers more carefully.
>      sorry can't help myself: **** reputation: 1
>      What the hell is that `d1_utc` thing for? You've got `d1.getUTCHours()`/`d1.getUTCMinutes()` already and `d1_utc` will be a different datetime
>      We don't magical stick and ball to understand your word. Post code
>      Try to switch on the thing between ya ears before spamming and make people waste their time.
>      If you take a `public` `super.shit()` then you'll be `add`ed to a very special `List`...
>      This is the preferred way. No dependencies and much more cleaner. I don't know wtf does async.whilst() and I don't care. +1000 to recursive solution.
>      To lazy to check the parameters for `CGContextAddArc()` or am I not understanding your question?
>      can u figure out how to do this stupid crap?
>      [Try and ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)!!!
>      Wow! You are so smart!
>      Ask all those people who you've always heard this from.
>      It was the first result on the exact title as mentioned in the comment. Now it isn't. The first hit is now tragically this stupid question.
>      Lacking an OO interface is a non-argument in this discussion.
>      So what's the question? What's the code? Or do you prefer us to provide you with magic out of the air?
>      i post same thing..bt ur confused again?
>      15 votes 2 favorites... My time to shine! Why is it harder to pick an element by it's index from list than from array? What a brilliant question huh?
>      Naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. thanks alot.
>      I have already done that if you look at my code at the top invoking the ggplot. did you notice the + theme() + ???
>      Have you even ***considered*** looking at the freely available very extensive SQL Server Books Online documentation?!?!
>      What a crazy idea to close this question! Jesus holy Chirst!
>      What have you tried so far?
>      **Bloody fool people don't try to give down vote without knowing the answers.. Give Down vote with justification.
>
>      Thanks man.!!!!! Great Coding..... Thanks a lot again.... **See other bloody fool people instead of interested to give down vote.**
>      So why don't you just do it? I don't see a question here.
>      oops..sorry.. Have voted up
>      This question shows zero research effort...
>      If you're running windows and **** answer throws an error try it this way. Worked perfectly for me.
>      No we can't. What u have tried ?
>      just wtf... closevote
>      Thanks for time wasting.
>      lame shit. i simply want to assign multiple error callbacks when a $http.get throws an error. how do I do that using chaining? Can I do it with `then`?
>      Much easier in android...
>      How to delete this question?
>      Maybe should read about Accessing array values?
>      Google is a hell of a drug.
>      Or check the source. You know since it's open source.
>      you have to read. the problem is a link to the picture of it.
>      Don't work in the tutorial project THANKS :)
>      Get a good operating systems textbook.
>      Geez a beginner is no excuse for not learning at all.. You can search it easily in google..
>      Use Google to find one of the numerous tutorials on how to build a library from C source files. This has nothing to do with Rcpp.
>      OMG! You really want and should write down such novell for one easy thing? Seriously man You should do some more research - workarounds usually end up badly..
>      like your comment?
>      Copy paste from the below answer
>      This is the most useless answer I have ever read on stackoverflow.
>      +1 Thx helped a lot
>      haha this one's still funny !!!
>      Which is interesting but doesn't actually answer the question.  See the accepted answer.
>      Moving along.....Please refrain from taking any jobs at nuclear power stations....
>      its a valit.. i don't need to worry about it.. and i want exact answer
>      Thanks for choosing an answer equals as mine which I posted 1 day earlier.
>      What exactly do you expect? **** is correctly putting out the relative path to your image. Do you need somerhing like Base64 encoded/inline images?
>      Maybe go wash that greasy finger.
>      congrats! you got a muppet upvote.
>      yeah right we can debug without a line of your code. what did you try where did you already searched ? we are not debuggers.
>      This question appears to be off-topic because it's a duplicate but I can't be arsed to search for it (much like the OP)
>      Shit ok thanks :) If the amount of content is variable how can I then make the height according to the content?
>      You just saved my ass :D Thank so much
>      What the hell is `sub` anyways..?
>      Your use case is flawed. Reading a tag from the phone to which it is permanently attached is silly
>      I think your putting down votes for my all questions? Why? What's your problem?
>      I wonder why this answer is still showed up despite of the comment above.
>      go away!!!!!!!!!
>      this is a crappy question  what have you tried? is there something wrong with your code we won't know unless you show us?
>      Maybe you should learn Java before you try writing an Android app.
>      I've downvoted as you've had several responses and not replied to any of them.
>      Where for witch targets ?
>      Didn't help. While main project's ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH set to NO Pod's project has ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH set to YES for Debug which causes compilation errors.
>      You could fix it by not using TortoiseGit at all.
>      Where does the `images/backgrounds/` path come from? It's mentioned neither in config nor in code. Do you expect **** to be telepathic? :)
>      Yes but i don't think so 5.0 and 5.1 has too much differences in them. Apple should keep track an indexing. And there must be some way to use the old ones.
>      http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101
>      You trust Stackoverflow users more than the vendors own API documentation? So sad.
>      Wow that's a first
>      I hope you are not a DBA
>      Sometimes I wanna shoot myself in the head.
>      What the hell is wrong with you ???? :D Seriously ? Comic Sans ???????
>      unclear is waaaaaaaaaaay too polite.  Flawed or crippled would be more like it.
>      Asking for a working example is off-topic. This isn't a coding service or a recommendation engine. You're supposed to exhibit an attempt for comment.
>      It's a shame that someone doesn't know how to use keyboard shortcuts or how to read
>      Read the manual that comes with the application.
>      how about doing a Google search. That's where you can ask. Everyone else has spent at least 30 minutes doing their own research first before asking questions.
>      If someone is experiencing this problem and using CocoaPods this is likely the correct solution.
>      Taught to do it this way at uni... Apparently it's bad jew jew haha
>      Answeru wa totemo oishi desu yo!
>      Why am i getting down votes.. i'm just asking a question... Dumb idiots some ppl r
>      cool. where did you get it from?
>      how to solve it with C# - by writing some...
>      Solved it for me too! When it comes to python packages apt packages usually really suck monkey thingie.
>      This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being incredibly impatient with the App Store.
>      Awesome you found the answer within 8 minutes. Quick :)
>      Want to -1 that shit-tier code style in that last comment but sadly (or luckily for you) stackoverflow doesn't have such a feature.
>      Thanks for linking Rails 4 docs to a Rails 2 question from 4 years ago. Thanks so much!
>      The person who down voted and marked as close if you're a man enough explain why you did it so we all know otherwise we all know what you're!!!
>      Google is the answer of your problem bro..make the google bestfriend also the stackover flow..
>      ........go away
>      Awesome linking
>      A thoroughly pointless question. If it did come before you would be asking why it didn't come after.
>      lovely and you specified that you are using centos
>      Wrong. There are 14 of each.
>      Very elegant answer Thanks.
>      Don't worry about it. No one cares about your code
>      Is there any wrong in the code? - it is 2014 and you're still using IplImages
>      It wastes my time to try this solution. The right answer is the one that **** wrote.
>      Need based coder as in I need the code that someone else will provide because I can't be bothered to learn the language?
>      This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading comprehension.
>      This question appears to be off-topic because OP clearly has no clue how to handle/manipulate and array
>      Have you tried oh I don't know using the variable?
>      how about reading some documentation before posting such questions?
>      Did you actually *try* what you claim to know? Why would you expect two calls to `list` to do different things?!
>      +1 RTFM and a link to TFM
>      Haha no offence but over the course of a couple days shouldn't you have added a recursive call for your 'recursive' function?
>      take a look to my answer perhaps you can use it in your code to avoid going your shoulder to scratch your ass :)
>      fail opinion based question
>      And it shows only the javadoc for the current function not the hovered over object too. Really bad answer.
>      Mormon programmers FTW
>      wtf??? how can I exit telnet???
>      f*cking thank you no where did someone mention that values can not be null although my keys are  rather than null
>      That's the most pathetic answer I have ever encountered in Stack Exchange.
>      This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow is not a developer-finding service.
>      this should be selected worst answer
>      Have you tried this yourself? By the way it doesn't work.
>      So why don't you do your own homework instead of dumping it here?
>      Explain what else you expected and why. How does this have +33?!
>      I am not asking abt what u r saying I have given the link to help u remove ur ignorance of telling my answer wrong... Ever heard of autoreleased object?????
>      This question has potential but is a [violation of MCVE](/help/mcve) if I ever saw one. Remove the `NEQWIN` crap and you might have something.
>      **** wins this thread over the pompous jerk who told her she doesn't get it.
>      It's cool that jsoup is smart enough to autocorrect your misspelling of chidl!
>      Patronising *and* wrong. Nice.
>      Was writing this question easier than pressing enter? :)
>      Thanks for sharing your experience. But please try to focus on the relevant parts in future answers not telling everybody the story of
>  your life..
>      I have a few words to describe Magento and none of them are kind.
>      lol very mature. My not knowing the np.nanmean command must made your miserable day
>      JFC! You must have *really* good drugs
>      This is stupid. An implementing class should be able to choose what to expose outwards while providing internal functionality of the
>  interface.
>      The link seems to not present any information at all ... Please do not troll if you are ...
>      Add explanation or don't post answers to such questions.
>      How is this related to coding / programming?
>      i am not at all interested in your meaning less crt baby reasons. some one as you with no morals and common sense make my blood boil
>      :sex <-- And this is a sex symbol!
>      Sorry coding jokes don't come along very often.
>      man enough is enough i m not telling bad i m just saying you are annoying more than a 2 year old baby
>      Why does this question get so many upvotes when it it considered off-topic for this site (request for external resource).
>      Ha or `sum = 0; array.each { |x| sum += x }; sum`
>      The worst answer ever!
>      No exception -- the guy is just fishing for reputation points by posting bad questions and immediately self-answering them.
>      OP asked for a C++ solution. Not for a C/C++ solution and neither for a C solution. Let's try to make one's life easier by not providing
>  C solutions where none are asked.
>      Serious question: why do you imagine a google search done by one of us is better than a google search done by you?
>      nobody can answer my question？
>      Which WebBrowser are you referring to in the code? The OP asked about WPF WebBrowser. Please stop fooling people.
>      So what did you ask? answers?
>      Uuuuuuuuuuuugggghhh.
>      Seriously did not even try did you. Please at least search Google if not stack overflow before posting a question.
>      What is the question. The forum is for english speakers ;)
>      http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/614/722/f9f.gif
>      http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/
>      yes 100% duplicate. but this issue remains unsolved and perhaps needs other to make it solved.
>      I downvoted because it seems that ***** *****'s answer below is the correct answer.
>      doesn't work......stupid solution
>      Did anyone else but me /facepalm after reading this answer?
>      Have you read the [numpy tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)?
>      It could also clean your house cook some food and do all your work for you. That's a possibility.
>      *****: Do yourself and everyone else a favor and use ui-router.
>      Hahaha this is f****** absurd :D!
>      Screw you to the guy who voted down. No research effort? Really? For someone new to Linux getting as far as I did most certainly took a
>  look of research effort.
>      Your teacher really does let you work with CI still...? That men must be like 80 years old?
>      I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it skirts on the edge of legal advice.
>      We're not here to do your work for you...
>      Reading comprehension fail.
>      This is just wrong. Why would anybody upvote that?
>      I'll do it in a few minutes thanks for your advice.
>      Anyone have any idea why **** has to be an ass about it?  I came here to find the answer so it must not be THAT crazy to post it on SO loser.
>      Cogratulation. This is your second downwoted question today. Keep up! :)
>      The only possible explanation is that you are a terrible person and regularly beat small dogs just for fun.
>      If you cannot understand the problem jsut ask me I will edit the question. Why yo make downvote? It is really a childish act!!!!
>      Who made me downvote you're really damn idiot!!!
>      Yes very Annoying every time I post a question comment or reply comes much later but down voting comes first I think there are some fools who has only work of down voting
>      downvoter should take care of adding comment as reason.
>      Who asked for a jquery solution?
>      I always upvote a question that elicits a good answer no matter how dumb. +1 for you.
>      that code is a mess!!
>      Thats works like a cunt when you are also doing Django pagination!
>      Format your code properly first. It looks ugly.
>      This forum is about problem solving not dodging
>      `<pre><a href=<br />>Hey</pre>` and you're fucked. You better use html5lib to parse your HTML and modify your DOM.
>      if you werent such a knob you'd have given a worthwhile answer.
>
>      Always use single quotes around your class names as properties inside the object.
>      **** Can you explain this to me? I also get the error *plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default invalidated* and I cannot figure
>  out what your answer means
>      In entire Stack Overflowthere is not a single programmer to solve this query?
>      No one cares what is freaky or annoying. Just ask the question and skip the gratuitous emoting please.
>      Ok you cannot bother.
>      Man I fucked the editting of this post it's supposed to be http.post either way none of the calls work anymore and they did before.
>      Well it works in iphone / ipad size but now the fullscreen is fucked because it is no longer at the bottom of the page but instead of the content.
>      What's the point of digging up this questions ? If not for a boost of reputation ?? The OP goes back in 2011...
>      I am sure through some pretty complex Math he can get his solution from this.
>      I love this answer so much. The symbolic logic approach is damn sexy.
>      Is this an answer or a question?
>      It's difficult to tell whether you're answering or asking a question when your answer ends in a question mark.
>      I don't see how this passed as a question back in 2012.  RTFM
>      dafuck? That's the most important part. The rest is useless without it.
>      I wish I could up-vote this more than once.
>      Emacs terminal is a dumb terminal so it's no surprise that many things break.
>      That's retarded. I would never have thought of having to enter those other positional args before I could view help for a subcommand.
>      include the resulting image properly
>      Android Studio sucks install IntelliJ. I have spent so many time with Android Studio some AH is managing this project at Google.
>      Haha ... removed your comment huh ? well i guess we all know who's right then...
>      My other aliases especially my favorite `alias fuck='sudo $(history -p \!\!)'`  show up though!
>      http://bit.ly/1EdE5aC
>      Fuck... Info... I think not works... Why what do you see? What is the error? Do not work... How to help if you say just that?
>      i will kill you!!!
>      you black dog where is your face huh?
>      Did your numerous solutions include searcing Stack Overflow where you would have found an answer?
>      I have a big problem lol... :)
>      Do you know why or is this homework?
>      this works but looks awful :D
>      libwebsockets is shit!!!
>      Fuck im completely stupid man.. I had a huge range. I should use offset for the list so to add on line for every new line.. Thanks a lot..
>      Man shut up ****.
>      Did you create these images yourself or did you borrow them from some unnamed source?  Please give credit where credit is due.
>      How can something which doesn't actually solve the problem be most useful?
>      Goddamnit.This is hopeless.
>      When I ask you a question what I need is an answer. Not two more questions.
>      Is Google not installed on your machine?
>      You're too sensitive to live.
>      I have upvoted your contribution in order to engage and to award your stupidity.
>      Oh shit! I guess that's my problem. Thanks I'll see if that helps. Lemme know if anything else comes up!
>      Answering and asking for more..
>      I honestly think you are just trolling me at this point. Good luck with your problem I hope you find a solution.
>      Have you tried [this new awesome search engine](http://www.google.com)? Is new but efficient.
>      It's not that bad but yeah... I've seen prettier girls.
>      Fuck both of those things. They don't matter at all in the general case. They only even come into the picture after your profiler told
>  you where to put them.
>      Where is the spelling mistake? And again revert the formatting I dont want to keep manually undoing your mistakes. I dont want to have to ask you again.
>      liar! this doesn't work
>      StackOverflow: The correct answer is there but the prick who makes the most fun of the question no matter how incorrectly gets the most
>  votes.
>      Oh dear you don't want to have it so complicated do you?
>      What have you tried so far? Did you do any research on the topic yourself?
>      attempt your assignment you lazy person!
>      utter rubbish.....
>      Study Basics...start with [WPF-MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee)
>      There is no magic. Do you actually know how to use a scroll view? Have you ever used one? Do you understand what makes it scrollable?
>      Huh?  How do you currently *install packages* ? That is what this function is for and I answered your previous question.  Feel free to
>  do `help(install.packages)` too.
>      lol read a book
>      I'm flagging this as a duplicate of [this question](http://bit.ly/1Tqcwn7); please don't cry
>      Note: if your C header `#include`s any `std*.h` headers you're fucked
>      That wasn't the question. But it's easy enough for anyone to figure out and if they can't then perhaps they shouldn't be coding.
>      If everything is synchronized why the fuck even care to do threads? -- My Old School Master
>      yup  i forgot to undo some change to another script and basically fucked myself over  i didn't find my solution but atleast i found my error  thx .
>      This is a decrypt method that you stole from an illegally decompiled source for all we know you are trying to hack into a crypted system with the unfortunate help of SO.
>      write some code. also congrats on the muppet upvote. dodgy as.
>      I got the same fucking issue like this: after a day coding a REST API file then save then re-open Eclipse again all my changes go away.
>      If you have to ask this you're not fit for the job sorry.
>      .equals() does the trick! fuck yeay stackoverflow is the shit!!! :D :D :D
>      Reason for the downvote coward!?
>      down vote for no explanation - i don't like magic here like  orig and other similarly
>      http://blog.gofenice.com/uncategorized/get-current-user-id-prestashop/
>      You are the problem with the online support community.
>      Don't ask a second question create a new question or better yet Google it!
>      Since you a being a grammar nazi you should have spotted the `if you doesn't`
>      Welcome to 2000
>      Uhmm then something else i fucking it up - with .submit() - it's not working at all. Neither in chrome or firefox.
>      You can't. I just call my forced div `<div id=fuck-react>`.
>      You can't fool me - that's a JPEG and it doesn't have any transparent pixels.
>      Okay error gone! Got the html being dumped in via the file_get_contents now the scraper is fucked however you have been a great help so far!
>      Same answer as **** one just worse...
>      IMO git rm should just remove the file(s) from the git repo not the filesystem...so so stupid
>      i did this allready. I even tried to copy& paste some examples from the Jquery API into a text document on my computer AND EVEN those
>  don't seem to work!?!? what the fuck
>      It does help. You are just lazy to use it in your openquery.
>      You tha real MVP
>      That's not going to happen.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
>      Do you have a variable `sc` defined at all?
>      What has this to do with the question? Are you astroturfing?
>      Looks like your cmd.exe comand is fucked up does Win+R -> cmd.exe work?
>      what the hell is this code?? where is the func of OutageViewModel.Id()? or   AfterSavedAll()??
>      what you said was so inspirational in 2009 such a shame  you didn't dig it further otherwise node js could be yours
>      WT? does not work did you tested?
>      your moms a terrible mess pal...................................
>      Your swift code is not pretty…
>      The one who downvoted me please don't be a kid. If you don't understand the question just tell me in a kind way. I don't like stupid people.
>      Thank you for helping me. I AM NEW TO PROGRAMMING and I simply wanted an answer. Now I know that this site does have a******* who are
>  not very understanding individuals
>      ...so wtf is then going on?
>      the one who downvoted me I cannot find any word to say to you. Dictionaries are not enough to describe the title for you.
>      My problem is in my code i wrote 2000 lines working with argv like char and now if i put it tchar my whole programm is fucked up...
>      :) always there is someone who gets negative votes even when everyone is getting a positive point.
>      got to love people who provide the laziest permanent fix ever
>      I don't see any code. Did you bother trying to google it on your own? Because I literally googled `java string replace after index` and
>  it returned 800000 results
>      I tried posting my Logcat but it keeps saying there's a formatting problem. I spent about 20 minutes fucking around with it. I gave up.
>      Lol The JLS uses iff?
>      welcome to the internet.
>      This is not Instagram help desk.
>      i don't know why eitherjust did.. - best logic ever. I predict you'll have a long and successful programming career.
>      You posted a lot of unnecessary irrelevant HTML.
>      Could you also provide a pure Javascript solution?
>      holy fuck it all works now!
>      *I'm too low status to rep you it seems:(
>      Oh fucking crist! I can put an IF inside another IF? Thanks <3 Jesus bless you brah!
>      Someone is in a shitty downvote mood today without explaining the reason for the downvotes...
>      please question related answer not .. other.
>      unfucking believable!!!!! i was using fragments so I needed to add the dummy surfaceview to the main layout. thank you!!!
>      Checked POM contains single version of Spring Framework and  is also there.
>      Seriously bro? do you even java?
>      This post is hilarious.
>      Removing the code has made your already obscure question completely meaningless.
>      Crap. Idiots ...
>      There are a lot of books with such kind of OOP bullshit. But why developers do such poor design of their systems (OOP design  too) using all this theoretical stuff?
>      Wow. I'm fucking stupid. Thanks **** it's been a long day!
>      Your question doesn't even make sense. Please try to write in a somewhat decent English.
>      **This is not a duplicate of How to compare Strings** Read the question properly before marking it.
>      Thank you so much 50 variable checks later I found out it had null because I fucked up in another place in the code .
>      Lol copy paste my answer
>      Yeah its obvious until I get the commenting privilege I will post answers the way I want.
>      Thanks. The `box-shadow` provided by bootstrap fuck this up. The issue was solved after override the `box-shadow` to `none`
>      if you use directive to set default value then may god blast me .
>      Did you tried anything ? SO is not a free code service we're happy to help on code with problems not doing your work/homework for free.
>      It's a copy and paste of my answer..
>      This has to be the most ridiculous way of going about solving the problem.
>      Apparently you need to add some booty pictures to change your downvotes to upvotes.
>      Ha. I mentioned it because your solution didn't use LEFT JOINS. Don't pretend otherwise! Also will your DISTINCT also count NULLS?
>      search on google .
>      Use your mind...Don't ask this type of silly question.
>      If you cant understand the question than get the hell out of here.
>      You're using the TTS in a very weird way.
>      You don't know enough SQL to create a `SELECT` query?
>      If this answered your question please accept it.
>      Happy new Year CYA!!!
>      Imo the google result fetching request and terrible question all together is more offensive than the word fucking. -1 nonetheless
>      If this solved your problem you might consider accepting this answer.
>      hahaha jsperf you fickle bitch... http://jsperf.com/periodicstrings/3
>      he said he wanted simple i gave him an approach what is your dysfunction?
>      Common sense!!!
>      I'm about 90% sure you're the same person as the one who asked the question.
>      non of your business. are you english teacher?
>      It does fucking compile -.- This is not the whole fucking code listen retard...
>      You found the documentation... did you read it? What's not clear?
>      Thank you **** however if you not prepared to help keep your stupid comments to yourself.
>      again mind your own business and stop bothering me.  if you don't want assist then stop wasting space on the site with your comments.
>      Did you try anything at all? Did you search for this? Do you even *know* JavaScript?
>      No this is stupid. Not even close to a generic solution. It could easily be dangerous.
>      Err... [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) maybe? Use `PREG_GREP_INVERT` as the 3rd parameter.
>      Which book are you using to learn C++?
>      you may want to check the stfu i aint politically correct policy. Oh wait it doesn't exist since it's given by nature.
>      I DONT GIVE A SHIT WRITE PROPER WORKING PRODUCT
>      What's the *question*? Just ask it and stop please. This is SO not your blog.
>      Didn't you already ask this question  twice before?
>      You have to create your own `WhatsApp` First
>      Are you trying to answer the question or be a smart ass? Really I can't tell by your comment.
>      What the fuck do you think I'm doing here asshole!? Research. Jesus christ! Why does the world have to include schmucks like you!? BTW happy new year
>      fuck everyone who downvotes
>      How would providing any code here help? Instead of being a code monkey how about look at what the issue is - that is what it means to be a computer scientist.
>      Im also voting to fuck off my post
>      because he is frustrated trolling in first day of new year
>      I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it follows the pattern  *- Assuming this is true why is it in common use?*
>      Are you retarded?
>      http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/
>      No error no excepted resualt i'm fucked up :)
>      Seriously ? It's the easiest programming task I've ever seen. Juste read some doc/tutorial about arrays
>      He's asking how to set an element in an array what do you think he has done so far ? Nothing.
>      Please answer as soon as you can because I would like to finish and work on other things.
>      Just because two languages start with the same letter does not mean they are the same.
>      next question will be I dug a hole and want to fall in tell me how
>      Take it to the psychiatrist.
>      yes N0b to sql ! u didnt help much lol
>      This should be the accepted answer not some xor crap.
>      You look so confused.
>      no.i just want to decode this shit
>      **** I haven't told you a code transtation service.if you know then answer if don't then skip.
>      yes thank you anywans look if you can help me not telling for stupid mistakes
>      Indeed not equals is the non-idiotic way of coding a relational exclusive or.
>      This is not a spoon feeding service! Show some code and learn [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
>      F*cking hell this is actually a good question. What SE site should it go to so it doesn't get downvoted to oblivion?
>      People are helping you for FREE you ungrateful little shit.. be respectful and follow the rules and people will help you..
>      You mad? It is the same thing that my code contains.
>      then up vote :( :) bitches
>      You think I didn't? And the duplicate post does not contain the answer for my question.
>      you two guys want to suck my dildo?
>      fuck off **** asshole
>      I m going to fuck your mother **** fucker
>      fuck off **** fucker sucker
>      su.. my di.. ****
>      Im gonna fu.. your mother
>      Well try something. This isn't letuswriteyourcodeforyou.com .
>      Oh come on DataTable seriously?
>      I've been telling it trillions of times on this site. Searching shouldn't be hard. There's a textbox on the upper right corner that
>  could be used for this purpose.
>      Huh?...........
>      This looks like ***guess work answer***.
>      Wtf is a dynamic pointer? Read a basic textbook
>      It still won't compile. You can find a lot of Articles & Tutorials related to Recursion in the Internet. I am afraid SO is not the place
>  to ask such generic questions.
>      This answer is wrong. I have this problem in 2.48. Giving nonsense answers you will not gain reputation on Stackoverflow.
>      Found a workaround that doesn't seem to fuck up the rest of my program and does the job. Although I guess your way is still the correct way to approach this issue.
>      Thanks in advance.
>      Who uses the G-WAN web server? The G-WAN website and that's about it.
>      You seriously don't even know how to write code? **Kindly check out the [tour].**
>      Pop it in the oven on 200 for around 15 minutes
>      Who is the IMBECILE who deleted all the comments to this question???
>      skip learning if you don't like it (and stop wasting our time).
>      Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book tool software library tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow
>      Don't be a dick about it. C++ provides you plenty of ways of working with ostensibly unrelated objects: see std::min. My question
>  is reasonable. This answer isn't.
>      There are a sure load of prats on this site.
>      I assume you later on want to ask is lamborghini a vehicle?
>      And this does not do that?    You are beyond helping and I will remember to not try in the future.
>      I suggest looking at any of the thousands of calculator app examples out there. Have you even bothered trying to debug your code?
>      So you want us to google search for you now as well? Anything else you need? A sandwich? Some coffee?
>      `steam music android java` guess what happens when you google that? How stupid/lazy are you?
>      Real life must be a shocker if you think this is rude...
>      Sure in stackoverflow I really didn't understand why so many people post answers or downvote without a basic understanding of questions. lol
>      I have an easy suggestion: teach your developers your environment.
>      Yeah sure couple of SO users are already working on writing this code for you should be delivered soon ;)
>      you want fries with that?
>      what is this suX ?
>      if you had learned it you would have posted an answer ... so go learn it you too
>      SO isn't a free tutorial / guide service
>      hot. I mean the question this is interesting.
>      Looks like you lack basic OOP knowledge. I'm afraid you can't get help from here.
>      For saving image path first I've to upload the image right and then only i get image path to save into the table. wtf does that mean?
>      Try googling resize runtime winforms or change name to ilietopeople. Really.
>      vote or die madafaka
>      or you could just contribute to the community and mark **** answer. Credit the poeple that help you don't just turn around and start deleting shit..
>      why are you so vicious?
>      ...and I want a cookie.Thanks for letting us know what you *want*.  What's your *question* though? What have you tried?
>      And I still want a cookie. I'd still like to know what your question is and what you've tried.
>      So give us a url then so we can see this not working.
>      Sure we'll just whip up something so you can spam your garbage app... Would you like a snack while you're waiting? Something
>  poisonous perhaps?
>      I will get it I am determinated ;) so stop your stupid comment and just click - reputation ;)
>      lol. can't believe this answer gets 3 votes. must be all from your accounts. lol.
>      Could you be any more lazy?
>      Learn how to program before attempting anything as complex as a multi button GUI.
>      If you don't know the answer keep your mouth shut
>      Why you cannot use `each_with_index` ? Its some kind of homowork ?
>      thx for the downvote smuck
>      Google try and then ask questions.
>      Yeah well fuck your mother you retarded autist you should kill yourself you fucking skinny ass nazi.
>      lol fuck you puppy youre an ugly nazi anyway you fucking clown nerd ass bitch.
>      Lol you're probably a nazi anyway that's why you won't help a good jew like me.
>      Strictly speaking I'm an ugly nazi clown nerd ass bitch who knows the answer to this question.
>      Yeah you got that right you fucking nazi clown nerd ass bitch. Get a life maybe the only way you know the answer to this is if you have no life.
>      Screw you **** I already know your full name and I will not take measures to ruin your fucking life. Find it in your heart to hide yourself.
>      Thanks **** for another RELEVANT answer.
>      no need to be such assholes
>      Nope not at all. Check my answer I did it on my own.. No need for any of your comments telling me to combine all your posted pages which is ridiculous BTW.
>      Please capitalise punctuate and paragraph this mess.
>      Heh... :D Then what are you offering for me to do sir ****?
>      What a nice person have a good weekend :)
>      I have to stop SQL Reporting Services because dumbass Apache can't figure it's crap out on its own.  Why does open source stuff have to suck so much ass?
>      Sorry “change your platform” is shit advice.
>      lol i tried that yesterday and still doesn't work the way i want thanks for coming out as a brick though next time maybe don't try to help someone in need a-hole
>      I want a textview inside a relataive layout or any layout read the question first before answering dumbass
>      complete garbage
>      because `var ls = fs.readdir(process.argv[2]);` is undefined how the hell can we know why
>      whoa what the fuck guys all im saying is dont use a dot at the end only commas and semicolon are you guys fucking autistic?
>      sorry i cannot post more character over here. If you  have time  can you please look at the line from 365 - 413 .
>      and clean my room wash my car and do my laundry...
>      kya le ke aaye the kya le ke jauo ge comment main dala hota :D
>      Well sucks to be you then :)
>      yeah stupid analogy you do things better than me blah blah blah. Go ahead talk with them smartass : ****
>      fuck you son of a bitch
>      I'm not sure we can help you with mental health issues ?
>      holy shit thanks I found out that I had a row with 5 columns instead of 4
>      You are a fucking legend. Thank you so much!
>      Is google down?
>      +1000 for Cargo Cult Programming. When combined with the H1B issue you get Coolies to lift your Cargo too! :-)
>      All telepaths are on vacation now - can you show some code ?
>      Hello nobody cares about your life story :) get to the point
>      phewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww. I wish sarcasm was more apparent in text format.
>      Clearly he hasn't answered it by your comments below you're simply wasting people's time by being to stubborn to provide any reasonable
>  information.
>      [links](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create+time+limited+trial+java+program)
>      did you really asked this question?
>      Really? You don't know about String.Substring ?
>      If i would've done that i wouldn't be asking here. The thing is i don't know how to approach to get the desired result.
>      Those who care IE is fucking dumb developers. :) just sayin' :D
>      Are you sure that you understand VBA properly?   In the code Find returns :
>      you can show pdf in your app without calling another application so why do you want to open other application.
>      i´d start by reading through a basic java tutorial...
>      Sucks to be you.
>      fuck fuck fuck fuck
>      fuck fuck fuck fuck fukc
>      POST YOUR CODE.. WE ARE NOT CLAIRVOYANT.
>      Blah blah blah blah...
>      Get the f**** o** from here. this is not portal site.
>      [why my question is getting downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)
>      oh thank you for opening my eyes on this amusing fact!
>      Stop cheating. You're not going to get that job.
>      that would never work
>      Ok who the hell are you to edit my stuff
>      All I need is this code fixed or at least some help if you're not going to get the hell off my question and go to the next one
>      And **** about the Google search may be you need to use this link : https://goo.gl/GzjTG6
>      if you can't help don't tell shit
>      That's called a `UITextView`.
>      Oh ya zébbii ...
>      Duplicating existing already linked answers and calling people names is what's not constructive. I think it just makes it clear what you're going for in these answers.
>      without any explanation & what the user is using is not mentioned so can you please justify this answer ?
>      hire a developer. stackoverflow is not a place to get your work done for free.
>      So is a pencil  paper envelope and stamp an alternative
>      Wrong. You don't understand Spring. Did you even read my answer?
>      Really you can't understand the error statement?
>      if you cant help ..atleast dont piss off anyone..idiot...
>      I'm flagging this question to be closed as too broad because it is merely a Gimme the codez question the likes of which are not welcome or encouraged on Stackoverflow.
>      nice copy of mine and **** styles :)
>      I found what you're asking in the documentation of Localytics in less than 2 minutes... Did you even bother to look ???
>      `(laziness stupidity...` Well aren't you just an arrogant arse.
>      Too dumb long read?
>      when someone don't have answer he tried to degrade and get points.
>      Gentleman i think you miss understand what I am trying to do.
>      Stop trolling and get a job.
>      Fart sound. not free
>      just answer the question
>      Try not to be helpless type default.rd.xml in the Google query box.
>      Why are people being cunts? Voting me down. I said I was a newb. Tossers.Thanks for the feedback.
>      I've helped loads of people over the years even when a question wasn't perfect. People on here are 'question fascists'. The site
>  attracts assholes.
>      Oh really? It turns out I tried that and it didn't work! Do you think I'd post a question on here without trying to refresh the
>  session?
>      An array is not a pointer and vice-versa. And please RTFM. See the `printf` manpage.
>      you need to move the whole title part to the top of the loop.. come on common sense
>      Thanks for being a published asshole
>      Sorry forgot to say - a Jerk also
>      Down-voting your answer until the property update behaviour gets sorted out. Will undo the vote once we clarify this matter.
>      That's why I am asking. If you don't know the answer then be quiet.
>      *italic* usually sucks
>      Yes go ahead and delete it and don't ask such questions here again.
>      *I know PHP Storm is built on Eclipse* Yeah right. That explains a lot!
>      Top SO Google result filled with useful information closed by some fuckwit moderator who probably doesn't even know what XML is. Gooooo
>  SO!
>      ne pas être intelligent
>      What exactly are you doing here? This program reads like someone spliced random lines from some very strange spanish c program
>  together.
>      une personne stupide essaie d'être intelligent si je l'ai fait .
>      hell to your comment idiot.
>      hell to your Zend certifications RASCAL
>      sorry forum nazi
>      this is wrong . your solution will create a list from [5  num+4]
>      Fraction is not the same as remainder. But maybe that techno-speak is too  complicated. Too bad programming is a techno-thingy.
>      Have you *tried* to do it with streams? Don't just expect Stack-Overflow users to refactor your code for you...
>      WHO THE FUCK DOWNVOTED?????
>      Finally answer that makes sense I got bored -1-ing every other attempt to answer this one.
>      So what if it worked perfectly before? They changed something in their vendor build of android and perhaps it doesn't work now until
>  they patch it... ?
>      I voted as too broad did not vote dup.  Not much point in bitching at the only person that is trying to help you.  Focus on your object
>  design problem to get somewhere.
>      Hey **** are you always such a pedantic c.u.nt? Why don't you go f.u.ck. yourself you pseudo-intellectual elitist b.it.c.h
>      What the actual fuck can you just please help me. I tried a lot of others forums. Seems this one could be my savior.
>      Well I don't want to use the letter i in my code. How can I declare main?
>      Why even use DateTime if you're going to still use date and strtotime? Get rid of them and clean this up.
>      I fart in your general direction!
>      This is a genuinely terrible answer which you should be ashamed of giving. Don't answer this kind of question again.
>      The answer couldn't be simpler. You are of course using Unity's UI right? Simply look at the `.text` property of the `Button` and of
>  course you have your answer.
>      WTF vote to close. Point me in the right direction.
>      He didn't ask for your opinion; the timing depends on the receiver; and you haven't addressed the major fallacy in his question.
>      Professional developers hate him!
>      MongoDB is 'awesome' is a pretty terrible answer. Furthermore your lack of experience with Cassandra does not qualify you to answer this
>  question.
>      Are you retarded or what? If the problem is not in your table you should put the fucking code where you do the insert.
>      Do you know what templates are and how they are spelled? What exactly is the problem?
>      who downvoted me ?idiots
>      RTFM? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177677.aspx
>      Please don't badger me with rules.  I only made a stackoverflow account for this one question because I've tried for literally about 2
>  months and nothing works.
>      yeah i'm about to turn 13 next week. you got beef son?
>      It's essentially the same code you use to exclude all questions that don't show what you've tried.
>      This is not a code translation service. There are no [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) scripts. What is this for? If it's a commercial project I could help
>  you if you pay.
>      If you can't answer the question you're useless keep it moving. If a moderator wants to edit anything he/she can I don't have to an
>  intelligent person will understand.
>      What in the heck does this answer have anything to do with the question?
>      well you can't tell me what to do so suck my balls
>      English probably
>      all the forms input always should be inside the form tag don't you know that??
>      The idiot who downvoted obviously didn't read the bold marked text *rolls eyes*
>      **He always brings the same information** who is this?? And unclear your question !!
>      how about you stop munching curry?
>      Oh! Yes. Don't relieve it to anybody. Eat yourself.
>      That's a pretty arrogant statement don't you think. Perhaps Stack Overflow is not the best place for you.
>      IT WORKS!!! THERE IS NO COUNTER STATEMENT SECONDLY IF I PUT != IT DOESNT DO ANYTHING THUS IT WORKS LISTEN BEFORE YOU SPEAK
>      Step 1: Go to school and get a CS degree
>      First of all you need to learn the human language to understand the What topics can I ask about here? help site of Stack Overflow.
>      asked the moderator to move it and got downvoted. This is some shit.
>      Links can die post the actual *relevant* code here
>      You're dumb don't write me anymore
>      Fuck off the code works
>      Okay special snowflake. Yes I only downvoted you because I'm too stupid to write code as awesome as yours.
>      have you even thought to look at the JavaDoc for `AtomicInteger`?
>      Although I appreciate you pointing me towards a great resource. I was hoping to actually receive a response like hey in cases like these
>  i.... so honestly. Screw you.
>      I have sovled this problemthe same as you said netstat -abn.
>      what a fuckIt does not listen localhost:80and can't access itsef by domain name.
>      Thank you captain obvious! ;-)
>      You are really an idiot.  Now I see you down voted my other question.  Get a life.
>      **Read** the question...
>      You don't seem to understand what the word *override* means.  Try a dictionary please read it carefully.
>      Hey smart guy even so you stopped for looking and lose time answering it get a life nerd
>      Please show code.  The OP asks for code.
>      use a bloody search engine!!!!
>      Also which muppet upvoted?
>      So you don't really understand any of this code?
>      You don't need to say that buddy. If you can't help then Fish off and stop acting like you are the CEO of Stack Overflow lol.
>      I HAVE NOT GIVEN ANY CONNECTION STRING ITS CODE FIRST TO NEW DB DEPLOYMENT SO BY DEFAULT ON MY PC IT IS **creating** database but on
>  client pc not creating
>      You should read a manual first.
>      You know what else you can do? You can go **c* yourself. You fill in the letters and let me know if that violates something else.
>
>      wtf this is off topic?
>
>      how is it off topic wtf
>
>      Javascript people don't give importance to archtecture subjects unfortunatelly. It's different from Java people.
>
>      fuck you i can swear as much as i want you cunt btw thanks
>
>      it's very good idea to harash new people that trying to enter your world thank you a lot... i am trying to understand sth but as i see u
>
>  are not supposed to help me...
>
>      We provide a service of reading error messages for people too busy to read them.
>
>      Why don't you try it instead of letting us debug your code. Or better - search first
>
>      Sorry but I have to say you have no clue what you're doing. Your code is full of nonsenses. Throw it and learn how to program first.
>
>      Only ignorant people can downvote a question without any explanation in comments
>
>      I love how you call the bullshit American time normal.
>
>      I run a Seattle Website Development firm is this your standard business practice outsource your work to Stack Overflow?
>
>      done that already... I'm not here to waste time...
>
>      That is kind of nonsense. The user needs to authenticate silently without having to enter a username or password I guess ?
>
>      use a search engine?
>
>      SO is not a code writing service.
>
>      Sorry again I fucked up badly. I corrected it again.
>
>      If my solution had a simple error there would have been barrage of downvotes.
>
>      true ... though better make sure you know the rules of what kind of questions to ask around there ...
>
>      if you cannot differenciate then better dont comment
>
>      if you can't look at an algorithm for 1hour to find out what it does then you should probably quit being a programmer....
>
>      That is much ABC worpdress I know all that already in which none can achieve my needs.
>
>      yes but OP says it doesn't make any difference so you might wanna remove this as an answer.
>
>      I hear google can find all kinds of things or so I've been told
>
>      **** get a life! And don't ever answer to any questions that you don't have anything to give. You are a smartass without and only waste
>
>  this Web site's topis.
>
>      While I agree that you are still learning to post good questions why do the rest of us have to suffer?
>
>      Jesus. This is supposed to be an interactive community. I could care less about formatting I want to ask other coders for some advice.
>
>  That shouldn't be a problem.
>
>      oh and if you're trying to be cute your account could be banned. So think a little.
>
>      You weren't sad. You deleted my email accounts and screwed over my team. Go fuck yourself.
>
>      I think **** downvote me cause i downvote him :D
>
>      Please add some more info about what you are getting. Shame you got a downvote without a chance to edit it first. Cheers
>
>      I think this is the most edited answer today. You should gain a badge lol..
>
>      What does It doesn't work mean?! FFS You get an exception? The world ends?
>
>      OR operator is `||` not `or`
>
>      ITS FUCKING WORKING!
>
>       I think you need something better to do.
>
>      Please start by reading a Python tutorial. Your code isn't even close to valid Python.
>
>      Fuck off. Idiot.
>
>      Mother fuckers like you are destroying SO.
>
>      Is your mom off topic too?
>
>      You can get a path like c:\one\two/three ... And it fucks shit up.
>
>      not working you canst it here: https://regex101.com/
>
>      This is not the place to get your homework done. At least convert that text to ASCII rather than posting a picture. Lazy bone.
>
>      Actually my code is perfectly formatted.  Two other people were able to tell what I was asking so stop bitching.
>
>      ill put you on hold
>
>      Thanks I got the answer on my own. If you know employee schema you should have got my question.
>
>      can you give any successful code.........because I don't have any idea about this...I read the documentation but is not enough for
>
>  fresher
>
>      Doesn't meet *your* imaginary specifications and wrong are two separate things.
>
>      yep you go it.bright guy
>
>      Oh...... What stupid a question! I'm sorry to waste you time ...
>
>      Offtopic: This is ridiculous. I hit Submit and in less than 5 seconds a -1 vote is here. You cannot even have read the whole
>
>  question.
>
>      When you even don't know that selenium webdriver can handle the file upload then please keep silent ..
>
>      Before giving minus points please read properly or ask what I am asking for
>
>      Bullshit answer. how this even selected as answer?
>
>      What have you tried to solve your problem? Have you tried to print any string with that 'format' function?
>
>      As it stands this question is too broad.  Do you have a more specific programming question?
>
>      You're not even using ARC? Really?
>
>      Links rot. You don't know that?
>
>      So you found the solution by yourself just after reading it on my answer. Fair play to you.
>
>      did it take a lot of research to count the sides of the +?
>
>      Edited...  Please don't make me regret answering this.
>
>      Seriously useless morons I didn't ask for an opinion. This site has gone to the dogs f u.
>
>      Only a stupid developer would do that.
>
>      Perhaps you could start by learning Python's base types before asking the obvious ?
>
>      As per my guess those who cleared mongo university course very well know about
>
>  **[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)**
>      I think is clear enough.... I think i explained clearly enough what i have allready try. if you cannot help just leave...
>      3 dislikes wtf guys  this community is slowly moving to asshole level 9001
>      fuck this shit why i am even bothering i will write my own generator -.-
>      Possibly but does it matter.  You recently duped one of my answers that didn't have any relevance to the duped one.
>      *Please help! I am not good in regex related things.* you don't need RegEx. Use `indexOf`.
>      Thats OK Take your time We have nothing better to do.... Oh! Yes we do!! Moving on.
>      Why would you take an assignment if you don't know how to do it?
>      ***who gave me -1 is one cannot understand the question if you find yourself one of them please leave my question now!***
>      Wanna bet about it?
>      please cut out your fucking fingers!
>      [*dynamic iframe loading javascript library pym.js*](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/tnnwi0x6d9u8gin6k2z4.jpg)
>      Never use `fopen` to a remote resource unless of course you are self-employed or has a willing to become one. N00b.
>      Very poor showing by seasoned SO users that such a ultra-duplicate question is not closed
>      Then fuck you guys!
>      No homework questions please unless you show what you have done
>      if i am able to i would have not posted it. And it should be a one liner answer using some regex or something else. If you cant answer it
>  don't post useless comments
>      don't post useless questions. All i read here is Here's the problem. Do it for me
>      that's how you get by on this site. Yes I do. If you want to post questions your way then go to yahoo answers
>      anyways leave it i have fixed the issue i am not here to fight with a person who can't dare to right his own name and uses
>  (Registered User). lol
>      More like + 1105 points for asking SO. #standard
>      fvgbhnjmk.kjmc nm
>      RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php `$key => $value`
>      Too lazy to read a manual better write a SO question.
>      You have obviously get very confused. Start again and this time check in with the manual every now and again.
>      wow...I don't mind you not helping but don't make it impossible for me to get any answers...the tags clearly say admob and android...I
>  don't know what your problem is
>      P.S. Your obsession to prove me wrong on everything I say is getting tiresome.
>      You should find a way to inspire your boss to get you some training.
>      ..............................
>      Thanks for the downvotes kids but I just want the answer is this safe not your unlikes.
>      You've managed to include everything *irrelevant* to the problem and absolutely nothing *relevant* to the problem.
>      I am using the `batch` command with a file on Linux from time to time. So trust me.. Or STFW
>      sorry but this is *pohtaytoe pohtahtoe*.
>      This is a cut down version of the solution I posted 14 minutes before you posted this.
>      Great thanks for letting us know. Come back when you have a question.
>      by the way your code is horribly formatted
>      Awful as clickable area differs from highlighted area.
>      I do not see any answer explaining `String#match` here.
>      why the down-votes? I'm just asking for help for something I don't understand how to do.. if you don't know either just leave me alone no
>  need to bully me.
>      So which tutorial was this copy+thrown up from?
>      Wow people on here suck. Why down vote without leaving a comment?
>      oh come on dude you cant even do your coding part???its soo simple..
>      Ok since you have 59 reputation points can you please show me how I should have answered I also need to learn probably I am new to
>  answering queries.
>      `didnt study prototypes yet` prototypes are what make javascript the ugly duckling of coding
>      Go has a clever and novel concept of loops here called `for`. This might help here even if not obvious and pretty advanced fancy stuff.
>      Who the hell are you to talk? An Arabian terrorist? Fu*k off.
>      Were you looking for someone to code that up for you? Or were you planning to share what you've tried and how that failed?
>      To those voting to close this question because `This question does not appear to be about programming` what exactly is not about
>  programming here?
>      google don't have the answer if it does i wouldn't ask here and i didn't ask for YOUR help so zip it man.
>      That isn't very helpful.
>      You rewrote my question and change the entire meaning. That's terrible.
>      Such a ***** community.
>      *you'll most likely see many more questions from me soon =)* Hopefully ones of better quality than this one.
>      punch of noobs -_-
>      **** hooly shit brainfreeze thanks haha
>      Problem 4: You can answer without to be arrogant. no one force you to answer.
>      This is slower Oh what nonsense.
>      If you didnt wanted to answer why fucking bother? This is a comment and not an answer. Stop wasting people's time cunt.
>      It is a dumb pointless question and voting to close it as such.
>      utter lazy rubbish
>      Oh very easy! [Here](http://google.com) you go
>      Shit! My bad sorry!
>      i dont want to downvote it.. i suggest you delete your `answer`. you have no idea what we are talking here. you just are embarassing
>  yourself.
>      Instead of marking unlike please give some relevant link or Answer.
>      Actually you wanted to be the first. You could provide the final answer directly :D
>      How `1+1=2` works?
>      Please don't do people's homework for them.
>      You will help him a lot more if you help him understand to write his program for himself.
>      Ya I know its a common sense issue.
>      Why the downvote? I would be very good to know why... Show your self you bast..rd!!! ;-)
>      You should test it before saying bullshit ;)
>      **** Yes you have showed us regularly that the correctness/quality/readability of code are not something you take
>  seriously.
>      Thanks! Thought I would have to click 433 times after selecting commit for the first time.
>      The guy just removed his Not An Answer and downvoted me. Well done.
>      Funny that works even though it's not a string. What a fucked up object. str(f) works
>      that shit don't work devil
>      Can you answer the damn question?
>      Please don't encourage people who ask questions like this by taking them seriously.
>      dude you are lame. forget it
>      You all are fucking retards. This question has not fucking been answered. Fuck you all.
>      Try reading the fucking prompt. I want a way to kill the task without killing the current program that is running it. If there's not
>  a way say it.
>      That's awesome help..Hope someone hires you. :P
>      Editing an answer to change a locked-in vote is an abuse.
>      Thanks. But don't forget to click [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#newwindow=1&hl=en&q=learn+php)
>      Instead of duplicating your whining to game the question form show the code of your attempt.
>      becaus no possible short circuit.
>      I hate Apple! This bug is present in 7.2 also.
>      If u can't help don't interfare. Get away from my post
>      are you stubborn or just stupid?
>      Shut the fuck up!
>      Let's have EXTREME sex in front of your children
>      Please provide some explanation to help other users of the site.
>      I read: I have an error. I am not going to tell you what it is. Please fix my code.
>      Stop arguing and answer the friking question!!!
>      If you had bothered to read the stack trace you would not have wasted your time typing the question.
>      A keyboard and your brain...!?
>      If you don't know just shut...
>      Are you thinking your smart??
>      really you called yourself coder ??
>      Fine **** actually its not your job its something who can do extra ordinary see I got almost two levels.
>      Thanks for your extremely polite reply its like no one would have understood what you wanted to say if you had said it in some other
>  way. Moron.
>      Please learn the basics of Java. A `return` statement is made to return the result of a function. These `return` statements are really
>  classic. What's bothering you ?
>      This is what you call a quality answer to a difficult question  :O  Whoa.
>      I wouldn't have to get verbal if you were polite in your reply.
>      Everybody here is a jerk. -1ing is like trolling but nobody laughs.
>      now its -2 because a horde of nasty people have decided that anybody they don't know is a monster.
>      NOW ITS -3 YOU ALL ARE IDIOTS
>      Well not only the first answer read you must #yoda
>      wtf you talking about?
>      and If U don't know how to read u would probably put weird answers !
>      Why do I always get down voted may be I really hate this site not coding
>      What have you tried ?
>      poor guy asks a question and you give him an unjustified -1?? +1 to offset some prick's ego.
>      because the answer is simple your just to suborn to understand it.
>      Lol *Angry German Thrift Committer* is this the new *Techno Viking*?!?
>      Angry German Thrift Committer [disapproves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8uUP.jpg)!
>      I am very much a beginner in ... programming: go back to reading the books - you have no reason to be posting  here
>      Did you even try looking at the tutorial ?
>      Ok I have looked at it
>      Didn't know this website was full of elitist dicks.
>      You show a really poor mind!
>      Funny how people dislike my question without giving a reason or an answer. I swear to god I hope those guys have cancer and die.
>      it fucking worked
>      Of course it's not the end of the world. It's also not the end of the world if you pee on my rug but you're still a dick if you do.
>      Show me where you took the problem from (so that I would know you are not trying to cheat in programming competition) and I will give
>  you a solution.
>      This is a simple issue with *hoisting* and awful ordering of imperative operations.
>      Holy shit. this is a null pointer exception now AS I MENTIONED ABOVE IF YOU GUYS CAN READ IT PLEASE.
>      google gives you link that leads to this site though. stupid
>      You should get some courses in an elementary school for adults
>      you just rephrased my comment. stupid. I'm looking for some solutions coz I'M NEW TO ANDROID . So if you don't have some
>  suggestions/solutions shut your old mouth.
>      If you've only been debugging for five or ten minutes then you *definitely* haven't worked long enough on this problem before asking for help.
>      Keep those streets clean or flip the burgers.
>      Then get your grubby mits off our source code ta.
>      I am probably missing something - Probably education - but then again you not are into that
>      **** in the same was as people can conclude you are an offensive homophobic prick.
>      You are ***** genius I love you no homo thanks for help !!!!!!!!!!! xD
>      You tricked me into spending time on making that then never responded. If you don't want to help don't put demands on me to do A
>  and B for you. That's mean and vicious.
>      Well it's a log.  Before his changes it fucking printed NULLLLLLLLL.  After I appled his changes it PRINTED WHAT I WANTED
>      Apparently it is not the documentation but your reading skills. Read **carefully**!
>      I guess that's douchebag for as far as I know that doesn't exist.
>      Yes but without everything else like method and action and inputs putting it in form tags will do fuck all
>      100 is less than 50 you idiots
>      yes i am but thats gay
>      thanks for the sarcastic comment neck beard. May all your friends think your the coolest person ever.
>      You're kldding right? You're writing a computer program that relies on predicting the future? I have a bridge for sale ...
>      read whole question if you are going to answer
>      Ok you didn't try to see what it outputs or this one :/
>      Have you heard of Google?
>      fuck you  you bastard  hippo-crate answer it or other wise shut your fucking mouth ! you racist
>      go fuck ur self with the 10k i don't even bother about them
>      fuck you all. tell me the release date
>      lol are there any computing scientists on this website? QA? What a joke
>      i don't balm it because you have a very small mind  your jealous or something  you could eat the  10k at lunch time for free. am paying
>  :) cheers
>      how helpful this one ?
>      What's your budget?
>      dhur bal chera giye
>      Learn more Java skills
>      OP in response to your request:
>
>      No. Spend some time thinking why people smarter than you marked the question as a duplicate instead of complaining.
>      So what's the problem you don't understand slicing?
>      If you want to correct me at least read what you're doing and I might be able to take you seriously...
>      Why? Your answer is clearly wrong. I don't think you are fit to answer questions if you do not understand even the basics of
>  probability. Go back to basics my friend.
>      Is this question a part of your assignment/homework. Learn about `JOINs`
>      Are you from Iran ?! ;) That's totaly not a good idea because in some cases i prefer to use the 0 value **Refigh**
>      just answer the question. If you don't understand it leave it. Somebody else will. I saw a lots of over-exited  around stack
>  overflow. :/
>      Seriously you edited the title but didn't change then to than?
>      bro u change ur msg
>      Very stupid idea to pass db statements via angular but you just want to move  }; some lines lower.
>      Fuck all who me down vote!
>      A fuck you man!!!!!!!!
>      You are entitled to your opinion. However thinking that you know what is impractical if you can't even write your own working solution
>  without help is hubris.
>      if you have mind then answer itdon't read my English. Whatever you give or not .you proved you are moron.
>      Very clever to delete your comment which prompted my reaction calling my code dreadful. Good luck being suddenly moralistic I think
>  it's going to bring you very far.
>      Haha you're a joke.  Keep showing the whole world that you can't communicate respectfully.  Let's hope this question gets lots of views
>  - you might even become famous.
>      Why not set this as an answer then ?
>      Hi **** - although it's admirable you wanted to help just click Close on questions like this. There's a huge problem with low-quality
>  questions in the Unity tag
>      Is that a question?
>      Example 9 in what? I probably don't have it. Who do you think we are?
>      if u can't help then what you are doing here?
>      `will sort_using_ptrs be faster than sort_using_ptrs`? huh? when will A be faster than A?
>      Ok listen boy  I dont hunt points.I've already have a job that I love.U voted  good night now.Let the user decide...
>      Not even remotely similar **** go troll somewhere else dumbass. If you don't want to be called an idiot then learn to read and not ACT
>  like an idiot. Try again.
>      please help me immediately  - hahaahahahah
>      your a bunch of cowards
>      Admit it that you can't do it?
>      Loved your comment *.. tried your nonsense suggestion*.
>      fuuuuuuck. I will have to dig deeper then into AOP
>      I can't believe I couldn't find a dupe to link this to.
>      Is google broken today?  Why can't you google what a form tag does?
>      Anonymous coward downvoter care to explain?
>      You are wasting everyones time - that is a ridiculous restriction which you should've stated upfront.
>      Ahh fuck IE....
>      Why'd you even take the time out of your busy schedule to write the comment.
>      Go fuck yourself ****. No life virgin
>      You saying PuTTy is not an IDE is irrelevant go troll somewhere else. The warning is fixed now. You mad bro?
>      What does this have to do with Java?
>      This is a pretty stupid thing to do.  Making it shorter will actually reduce its readability (as seen in the answer below).
>      Easy to answer that after reading the comments
>      http://www.justfuckinggoogleit.com/
>      Note: I'm not downvoting.
>      Don't post C# answers on question tagged only VB.NET please. It wouldn't be accepted the other way round.
>      way to avoid the question. Good luck handling milliones of records with access
>      This OP is bad thusfor we downvote and flag it. Please provide what you have tried maybe some HTML css....
>      SHUN THIS NON-PASTAFARIAN! :))
>      I did it by myself now. It tooks me  2 min. You bunch of fucking idiots. Even don't know how to develop simple code....Go home
>      **** U SOUND LIKE ANUS
>      who cares about the research effort if it was a direct question ? fuckin retarded community
>      If you haven't understood what `String` is after a couple of months I seriously would suggest you look into a different field.
>      Please refer Changing my Major to Arts
>      Please do not run this into production... never
>      If you write your code in `C++` in similar way so I have bad news for you :(
>      Read some books and do not troll for information!
>      I swear it's like people just don't even try any more.
>      Why would I do that? Don't post the question if it's not really what you're asking.
>      Seriously your question is completely different now and this gets asked all the time. Why do you need personal assistance with such
>  simple matters?
>      You don't need to know how to do it to use Google. So the question remains why do you need personal assistance with such simple matters?
>      Yes a monkey would find this terribly complex.
>      You can choose today to start anew and not rely on others to perform the most simple tasks for you. Consider it a small step toward
>  manhood.
>      how much ...shut the fuck off
>      Did you read the question?
>      But Not working I tried. I dont knw why people are so stupid to mark my question as duplicate. I have writen that I seen many posts
>  but didnt get the answer
>      Please post working code that reproduces the problem otherwise you are just wasting others time.
>      It's hiding so it's still open... I did not say he has to use the hide thing.. It was a suggestion. You can give a solution instead of
>  bitching at my solution.
>      I'd leave you to complete this quote by yourself:.....Empty barrels make the ...........Hopefully you know this one.
>      How did this get upvoted as a good question?
>      it doesn't compile because it is a code sample with missing thing (like the array for example).
>      Only an idiot would expect this to compile
>      This user should be banned from SO
>      The title alone hurts.
>      yeah sure also you should add `for(int i = 0; i < 666; i++) Multidex.install(generateRandomContextFromInt(i));`
>      Go fuck yourself
>      **** more like 51 year old virgin
>      ****? More like dead-wood. ;-)
>      Your banter is about as shit as your sex life
>      your banter is as bad as your sex life
>      Get back to your tool porn you ugly virgin
>      I challenge you to compile this code.
>      Well it's a C++ question so I'd expect code provided in an answer to be correct. It's not very useful otherwise.
>      No professional uses Wordpress. So I guess by default that includes you :)
>      Vote how you want.  I'll just ask another.
>      Ok. That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions not a place to dump your to-do
>  list.
>      calm down champion.I am a new in this area and have a lot of question.when ı read question in this form write my problem.you don't
>  need  being rude!!!
>      To whoever down voted my question it'd be nice if you left some sort of comment explaining why you down voted my question so I don't
>  think that you're just being a dick.
>      Please don't shout.
>      I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it works and belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
>      go home man you're drunk :\
>      Read [ask] again.
>      why are people downvoting my question.
>      If you have a problem then gtfo scrubs thats why forums exists you dumbfucks -_-
>      You're right it didn't go well due to that idiot who turned it into a chat about SO rules. I'm deleting it.
>      Doctor my stomache hurts. Sorry we are no clairvoyants. You don't even give details.
>      I just wanted an answer to my question not a sermon . Who are you anyway the question polizia?
>      And PS i dont give flying fk about downvotes :D
>      Guess who is the stupid one.
>      Bro you have something to add here  add it if not fuck off it's that simple and thanks
>      *the lines print properly with regular print statements* - Then why don't you just do that?
>      U R Welcome. That would be nice if you try to understand the environment before using it.
>      So what was that hard reading the compiler error message?
>      yay for old f*rts getting back into coding!
>      If you don't know the answer to this just don't answer at all. You're not helping at all ****
>      Dude get a bloody life!
>      actually i have been trying for two hours know and thanks for being a d*ckhead
>      learn how to join tables
>      fuck off man i asked a serious question
>      But much more useful than your comment
>      this has been asked a million times to get random-no-repeats YOU JUST SHUFFLE.
>      having these problems with Azure in fucking 2016 and it doesn't help
>      Use your brain and read [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)
>  or ask your instructor.
>      You said JSON. And you said regex. Now see the contradiction. Finally continue by using a JSON parser.
>      that's shame to know even **SO** don't have answers to some questions.
>      There is a way but it is almost impossible to find it because python has no documentation and the web has no search engines.
>      EITHER NORMAL FORM POST (PAGE REFRESH) OR FORM POST WITH AJAX. NO OTHER POSSIBILITY
>      my eyes hurt on seeing this code
>      i can read it maybe you should get your eyes tested
>      This is really an faked up community
>      Your code invokes undefined behaviour at multiple levels. It is plain awful and useless. Use inline-assembler.
>      stupidity at its best :3
>      Maybe the problem is that pipe you're smoking in the facebook cover photo you just posted.  If you lay off the weed you might be
>  able to concentrate better.
>      `What do i do ?` Study find tutorials buy books watch videos ...
>      Keep being a total dick. You still have to look at yourself in the face every day.
>      you need to properly implement one of those algorithms. if you dont know that then you are going back to school!!
>      sorry but this answer is completely out of sync with the question i.e it's a load of rubbish ;-)
>      ***** cunt
>      Stick to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
>      Also whoever up voted this should have their voting rights suspended.
>      Let's not.  I'm not interested.
>      I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a homework site.
>      simply spamming your sourcecode somewhere wont get you any help - nowhere. Go and ask your teacher.
>      **** 1 v 1 me anytime any place
>      StackOverflow is not here to do your code writing.
>      well gee i would think exact output and source was detailed enough i guess im not up to your standards should i post memory dumps too?
>  that detailed enough for you?
>      How can you help others being dumb
>      Would the retarded monkey that downvoted this working answer please explain why?
>      Please fuck off
>      **** go fuck yourself idiot
>      You fucking morron!!!
>      This is not a jQuery issue. Your variables are not magically reactive.
>      You've been here long enough to know you have to show effort.
>      **or something** the kids theses day seem incapable of actual thought
>      c'mon now really? or is this some kind of code golf?
>      Dont make negative vote it is reliable question and i face this issue in many devices so stop this headache and if anybody knows than
>  comments it
>      I think it is not ur business. I did not want the whole solution. I wanted the way to do it.
>      Please check if the below solution answers the question.  If it does consider to accept the solution by clicking on the tick mark next
>  to the vote.
>      what of load of shite!
>      Four star programming wow!
>      Dude its a psuedocode not supposed to work unlike just talking in gibberish
>      Four star programming wow! This must be really good code!
>      OKAY BUT WHAT DOES THIS HAVE TO DO WITH PHP OR MYSQL? - See it just looks stupid don't use all caps.
>      POST THE CODE YOU'VE WRITTEN!
>      *sigh* read a book on it dude it's like something you learn in Comp Sci 100.00001
>      This whole QA is embarrassing and sad.
>      some trolls even downvoted **** just because he answered my question:)
>      why do you still have the bizarre array-whatever thing there bra ?  you realise that's going to sit around on the net for like 10000 years
>  :O
>      Then you need to say how or just be cranky like you're right now.
>      Don't bump old crappy questions unless your intent is to actually improve them (adding backstory or complaining about a downvote is not
>  improving your question).
>      Don't nag me please. That's just annoying. I'm not your servant. I don't owe you anything. Now I don't feel like helping you.
>      Uugh A 3 star programmer!
>      Fuck off.Delete my questionI didnt get the answer I wished.So delete the fucking post **** BLACKASS indianfucker
>      I want my post deleted indian black ass idiot
>      delete the fucking postI didnt get the right answer
>      Just fuck off indian black bitch
>      DELETE THE FUCKING POST
>      DONT FUCKING REVIEW MY POST WITH - IDIOTFUCKER
>      And list refers to READING a list in the resultset.  I don't wipe the ass of the programmer.
>      go away!!!!!!!!
>      sorry didn't know about your stupid website roles
>      Please use the mass in your head! **setting** does not mean **using**!
>      utter rubbish...
>      I fixed it so your simple mind can see through the MUD.
>      Yes it is very clear. You are asking for someone to spend there time free of charge to coding it all for you.
>      ... WTF IS THAAAAA ISSSSSSSSUE
>      So you are asking others to write the code for you? What did you try so far?
>      nice did you scribbled your gf/ex gf name?
>      fucking missprint ! Thanks dude :)
>      Terrible answer and terrible choice of date as an example!
>      [First hit](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-May/132846.html) when
>  googling your error message. This question does not show any research
>  effort.
>      I just took out the upvote given to you as there is an unfair downvote on my post.
>      YOU ARE A WANKER FUCK OFF
>      You have 50 databases and you don't know much about dba work... Poor you.
>      WTF? OP edited the question with comment `Wordpress added as Tags explained the error`. Where is the explaning?
>      Poor you indeed.  Transfer in Excel?  When there are real ETL tools out there?
>      Isnt easier as write an question just google for `bash arrary tutorial`?
>      i don't know because probably he is god or devil or angel or some spooky scientist who can see the future edit.
>      Very fucking user's on this site never read the question always try to down vote new comer even they leave this palate form.
>      Yes you can do it. But you have to make a good question and right format.
>      Rod kinda kindergarden issue
>      Switch your major to the humanities.  Programming doesn't seem to suit you.
>      need? no want against their terms your a bottom feeder go back to the hole you came from.
>      I do hope you are doing this as a infant school project and not for a company that is actually going to offer loans.
>      Your a f'in Bitch
>      my problem is now soloved   ......funke all of you no one help me this is fucking websit
>      It is for you. Stop to act as child.
>      From your general behavior not particularly this case.
>      Why you chatting shit
>      I do not understand what did you expect?! Or I did not need to answer at all that you click down vote button!
>      serious minus 2 ? so you know that its not good question??????????SO TELL ME THE DAMNED ANSWER THEN GENIOUSES!
>      you suck dude..
>      Are you high?
>      ontopic: Please add your html code and what click event are you talking about?
>      you're **very** weird ... just saying
>      If you're constantly tend to have typos or incomplete statements (just like in your question title) no wonder you'll receive such
>  errors.
>      Do you know something named singlton?
>      Great title - will really help others.
>      .....I'm absolutely fucking retarded. I didn't include a main - ugh...just following and copy and pasting the provided code made me
>  blank out. Thank you.
>      nice homework assignment
>      What part of Google is your friend don't you understand?
>      Oh please. Try harder. And What part of Google is your friend don't you understand?
>      Try asking a clear question. And:: What part of Google is your friend don't you understand?
>      Please reply ASAP
>      And naming it like this instead of using the proper API to decide on the folder is smart because of?
>      This is to show you the error  why do you keep -1'ing all of my questions? =[
>      Because you sometimes need a loop in a loop. What is your problem? Maybe you learn programming from a book not by looking at code?
>      What good are tutorials if you don't make the effort?
>      Oh and also please format your code it's hurting my brain.
>      OP didnt say that. Take off you downvote please
>      THIS IS FUCKING SHIT AWESOME TO KNOW THAT YOU KNOW SUCH IMPORTANT BULLSHITS
>      *Groan* it's f'ing typo in your form. Off-topic.
>      If a genius puts a -1 to the question the question doesn't need an answer. The answer doesn't need to be accepted.
>      Backand Is A Horrible Framework. DO NOT Waste your PRECIOUS Time On Backand.
>      So one  clarifies things how?  Microsoft telepathy update?  moron.
>      How the hell would that work?
>      Wishing it away got it big man
>      You're going to be a great programmer some day.
>      One bad question per bad question please.
>      CAN I SAY A BAD WORD BECAUSE HOLY FUCK YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM WOW LIKE THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!! I WAS SO CLOSE TO GIVING UP!!! IT WORKED. THANK YOU!!!!!!
>      **** Anyone with answers as this would have pressing reasons not to reveal their real name ...
>      have you tried it yourself yet?  if so have you encountered a problem accomplishing your goal?  Or do you think SO is a
>  do-your-homework-for-free site?
>      All right! Have a good time ;)
>      Who is the coward who downvoted my question without revealing himself?
>      Thanks will figure it out F U
>      i have showed what i have done now tell me and you ****r stay in your limits
>      please fast reply so I can complete my work
>      this is fucking awesome
>      I used CREATE TABLE () to make the table now i'm trying to add another row to the table...  Is my question really that repulsive to
>  you guys?
>      You have a problem counting to three.
>      thankyou atleast some one knows what I mean and isn't a whiner
>      Someone with no idea how to do this might not be suitable to write this app.
>      *..So I would like to know if I can call a php page* ~ Yes You Can Do It.
>      The question on my mind is can you help yourself? If so don't tell me just post the MCVE. Otherwise stop wasting my time.
>      How would you be able to answer your own question if you saw it tomorrow after a heavy night of drinking?  When you can answer that
>  get back to us.
>      This website is filled with a bunch of a*holes who are only great at critiquing instead of helping.
>      every day the same question
>      You can go to hell **** dam ass I am trying to learn not make money of a stupid question why would you think I want to take credit
>  for this code?
>      How the hell do you know if i put effort or not. Idiot
>      It must be a joke. Now it's even worse.
>      Hey smarties. I have java in the PATH. If you never encountered this error then you ain't helping me.
>      Spare me your feeble attempts to think.  You're on your own on this one.  PS - the possessive is its.  Your English is as poor as
>  your math.
>      You updated(after deletion) the answer seeing my one. Better to upvote the answer which is correct.
>      all you asshol** got me to loose points. go suck some cocks!
>      utter rubbish...
>      go go go downvoting :)
>      maybe you should visit a doctor :-{  because we cannot see into your head
>      You don't seem to have any idea about anything. Why would you think you can create something like this?
>      vertical alignment ! similar issue. rest was CSS basics
>      I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort. (One should atlas search stack overflow)
>      i get that your answer is to fuck with the client's website dom which is a bad idea.
>      And why arent you reacting on the other comments? The one with the firewall and other things?
>      And what was the ip of your android device? You cann post the full ips as millions on earth have the same. Dont think its worth to keep
>  it secret now.
>      They are usually evaluated as 'fire this programmer' or 'assign a grade of F- '.
>      And this helps how?
>      Unsized array? Did you smoke pot before asking this question?
>      **** doesn't have comprehension skills.
>      This site is shit
>      What did Google tell you?  There are plenty of articles on how to do that.
>      You literally just copied and pasted that from my answer :) But I guess that's okay.
>      Yeah **** i updated my Post. Its only one question now happy now?
>      what have you tried so far?  You wont' be able to get help until you post some code for others to evaluate.  Also what the hell do you
>  mean by rankings ?
>      Well I appreciate you wasting my time.
>      *Could some one help me as soon as possible with this.* Post a [MCVE] and maybe someone would be able to help you within the next 6-8
>  weeks.
>      Why are you still breathing. Like seriously you're the dumbest fuck wad I know
>      Shut up you stupid idiot.
>      yes above solution not work
>      Thats for your concern i just got a solution...
>      [edit] your question and paste the code in the question - this looks like spam
>      Where is the code you have tried?
>      Wow nice design. What is it by the way?
>      if your instructor told you to use eclipse for android programming change instructor.
>      is there a way to get a textarea to stretch to fit its content without using php or javascript? - English do you speak it?!
>      Are you trolling??
>      Vote down if you are gay or just stupid...
>      Do Not Learn Backand. Its piece of crap. Learn Firebase. Firebase is actually made by a good company(Google). About Backand? Um some
>  trash company
>      Because you don't understand pointers apparently.
>      I posted a solution.  Please check if that helps
>      Buddy if you're not sure and don't know the answer then comment instead of posting an answer !
>      don't fucking downvote if you don't know the answer. If you know the answer then please help.
>      SHOW US .H AND .M OF CUSTOM BUTTON ALSO WHERE YOU USED IT.
>      Why don't you read an introduction to Objective-C? SCNR
>      Why did you give minus to this post idiots. If you have a solution post it otherwise f.ck off.
>      hahahah.....yeh.....copy cat..!!!
>      proble proble yeah.
>      What is this check how to ask a question on stack:-  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
>      baby ? seriously? how about you stop munching curry? i'm a guy.
>      ALT+F4 maybe? ;)
>      Can you propose something reasonable instead of talking?
>      If you dont know the answer  MOVE ON
>      you must have a sad life to sit here to comment on unnecessarily questions :)
>      To the morons who voted it down you haven't even read it in 30seconds that it took you to click the down arrow.
>      this is like a middle school problem please dont post this type of question again
>      cause i do shutup
>      http://www.givemehope.com/beta.htm
>      Another person who can't operate outside Eclipse.  It means you WAR packaging is incorrect or the URL is wrong.
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404
>      stop typing in your Indian accent.
>      Look => `right syntax to use near 'long` <<< *Learn to read those and research the error*. It's part of coding.
>      So the TA is dead?
>      And I want a new car. Trade?
>      Please someone be nice and write all my code for me so I don't have to do anything.  And oh yea contact me even though I didn't leave
>  any contact information.
>      A downvote huh?  cool!  F you buddy!
>      what are you talking about idiot ! we have already established it is less.... get a grip !
>      You normally SAY THANKS around here once someone helps you.  Did you get it working champ?
>      I guess it does not help you. But then again ...
>      I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just silly.
>      He probably meant a lot instead of all could be because English isn't his first language.
>      do you have a program to analyze here dude?? then cut the crap
>      fuck you community and coding and stack!
>      he probably forgot to login with his second user;)
>      Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?
>      Write Good code?
>      If you have problems understanding the question please comment not answer!
>      If you cannot use a debugger IDE or no you cannot develop software and you should stop trying until you have attained that necessary
>  basic skill.
>      if you're stuck in the US with crap bandwidth just move to switzerland or sweden!  mfg.
>      It SHOULD of been posted because its my last option. Go take your 5 points and fuck yourself mate.
>      If it means one less terrible question with the `unity3d` tag then its well worth it
>      If you are going to ask for help with your homework you should atleast tell us what you have tried so far.
>      Even though my comment has been removed (that's too bad). **** my sincerest congratulations I really mean that.
>      Especially because it does not. Seems **** does not read before answering.
>      thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot. I still trying to figure out why my first query didn't worked and why i have this
>  fucking error on the filter operator
>      I think OP can speak for himself if he wants something different. Mind your own business.
>      why the fuck is this marked as solved?!?!?!?!?!!?!?
>      OK now you have (implicitly) told us via the screenshot that you are doing this on Windoiws.
>      Seriously disturbed people vote me down - but this is good code nevertheless. :)
>      Why the fuck someone would close this thread as NOT CONSTRUCTIVE???
>      The example is supposed to be *minimal* don't dump your homework here for others to debug.
>      Because I need to know what that logic is --- so you don't know what you need to implement?
>      Post code. Build a fiddle. Are we supposed to dig through your vague description and just guess what is happening?
>      I HOPE YOU BURN IN HELL !
>      CHILL!!!!!!!!!!!
>      thank fuck I'm an atheist
>      why not i see every one ask about xss  so why the fuck i can't get the answer?
>      bhag ja beta abhi.. ladki ne bhi bol diya abhi ..Google Translate: Be part of girls also launched the beta right now .. now ..
>      The f%#k voted for SuperUser???
>      Ok then you go and help
>      Here is one upvote for you to encourage making good examples in the future.  I am fair and balanced in voting (unlike somebody)
>      It is interesting who is that idiot who down-voted the question?
>      Er how did you post the question? Are you a bot? Answer please?
>      Dont put images of the error message for f*ck sake! Copy/Paste it!
>      Then do it right. OP is not helped with 'almost working' code.
>      Nothing useful in this shit
>      I don't see Java here.
>      What the actual fuck is this?
>      then go to hell bro
>      This is 2016. Don't use `File` use `Path` and `Files`. Also there is no guarantee that this will work anyway. Why don't you just delete
>  the file yourself?
>      Try this link: http://tinyurl.com/gmpeyat
>      What is a shits count? Number of toilet visits?
>      Wrong. Do not post your answers without trying once.
>      Yeah... 'How to access content of a folder's file in c?' as the title then blatantly writing C++ code is not going to go down well at
>  all:(
>      You should pick some more unrelated language tags
>      Very bad code please hire someone or follow some tutorials on google.
>      I'm voting for you guys to mind your own business and let other people get the information they want.
>      My question is very specific and only about a small part of the posted code. You obviously did not read it. Pull the stick out of your
>  ass.
>      Then don't use code highlighting.
>      I'm really familiar with Excel and this logic would be working perfectly in that... don't know why java has to be such a dick about
>  it...
>      HERESY! BURN THE WITCH! :P
>      Buy an Windows computer? It's better anyway ;')
>      So you found the answer but it doesn't fit you? What?
>      and he answered himself so he doesnt give the answer to me! :D great user.
>      What the hell... what do you mean? Please clarify your question
>      put more memory (not into the computer but into your head) if its not clear enough :)
>      I have uploaded whole code...pls help me..!
>      Actually it was a question from the contest held today people who appeared posted their questions. Can you help solve this instead of
>  joking around?
>      YOU HAVE ALL IN THE EXCEPTION(do you know how to read?) notification is not a JSONArray but JSONObject
>      You must be kidding this answer is plain wrong. Returning from one of the functions certainly does not affect whether the next ones are
>  executed or not.
>      `can't quite understand` what part did you not understand? How are you a code junkie??
>      You proclaim yourself to be a code junkie and has been on SO for 4 years yet your last few questions demonstrate no effort on your part
>  so no sympathies from me.
>      `int main()` is the recommended and only official program entry. `void main()` is for losers.
>      not very helpfull ... means only it does not work more or less ! A bit arrogant comments are not nice !
>      Nobody here cares about opinions; state facts or nothing at all.
>      look up a class library.
>      then what do you need mr.know it all?
>      It depends on what you're trying to do with your code mr. know nothing.
>      I'm getting kind of pissed off. No-one knows how to do something so everyone downvotes? Go f*** yourselves. Pricks.
>      Yeah i did!
>
>      But the language files are cached.. This is fuckin shit!
>
>      I have to change the locale path every time I did some changes..
>      This is not learning center or we are not doing here educational projects. Do your own work and if you face any problem then come here
>  to consult by showing us your work
>      https://xkcd.com/327/
>      well no need to be a dick about it. people over validate all the time assuming people dont know their own name etc.
>      Have fun being rejected by Apple =)
>      taught* lol sorry for not saying FUNCTION my bad
>      Obviously you didn't have anything to contribute to this for help so I'm not sure why you're still here............
>      That's the opposite of what he asked! DOn't people read!?!?!
>      are you afraid of new lines and spaces? make your code more readable
>      post some quality answers
>      Nobody accepts the answer if it is OffTopic. I Think you need to consult a good doctor.
>      You ask What am I missing? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve voting to close
>      Can you actually answer the question or are you solely trying to dispute how relevant the question is to django?
>      I don't know.. would it work? :| you should try it before asking here.. that's how you learn programming.. to answer you shortly: yes
>      FUCK JOU *****
>      What the silly question
>      My suggestion is read how to ask a question and get your acts together.
>      I've heard rumors that similar things can be achieved with a language called `JavaScript`  (It's supposed to be the new shit the
>  cool kids use ;)
>      If someone could give me a golden toilet I would be very grateful.
>      Actually you missed an occasion to shut up. If you not going to help you are not obligated to respond. Just disappear.
>      Shit one second
>      My *chief* relief is you not coming to grief with this question.
>      DONT EVER DO BACKEND Guys!!! Its the worst! Try firebase or Node.
>      Why are you even using Backand..... The worst choice
>      Why are you using Backand? Please use firebase or Node.
>      ........ http://tinyurl.com/gtkkmaw
>      Oh yes down vote more. I searched stackoverflow nothing. I searched google nothing. I make a question and now I'm an asshole.
>  Cool!
>      Not sure if I'm more impressed by the cheekiness of the poster or the stupidity to think that someone would answer such a question.
>      With more of them such as `-vvv` :) And if you are no more clever post the output to the edited question.
>      how the f*ck this connect to my question? really...... lol
>      If you don't know the answer just say so or don't comment. don't give empty advice and mark my question duplicate you dumb cunt  ^ ^
>      My Question is above your Low IQ level ; U don't have the neurons to solve it  even after spending lifetime in coding  u snitch
>      So u gathered ur fagot low IQ army and reported my question .... U fucking looser ... You probabily suck in your real life to faggot ..
>      God why is everyone on this site such a dick ! Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth .. well im fucking sorry .. sorry im
>  trying to learn.
>      If this is illegible .. then get your eyes tested. The only waste of time and bandwidth here is your unhelpful unneeded worthless
>  comment.
>      lolllllllllllll fuck you for deleting my answer bitches
>      a) run a clustering algorithm b) get a result.
>      Don't cast your mallocs is something people say on stack overflow to make themselves feel superior.   It's the least of your worries
>  whether you cast it or not.
>      your problem is: you don't care. you blindly copy shit from the internet.
>      Nobody sees your code.  Perhaps what you need is a psychic.  Call 1-800-MYPSYCHIC for an appointment.
>      Read he site rules. Any maybe you should go to the basics - once you get out of school you are expected to know your stuff not cheat
>  around.
>      seriously the SHIT advice you get on git is so much. thanks
>      Enlighten me on where OP states that it is an embedded resource
>      Give a man a fish
>      Please don't try to over smart just by giving a negative. either Solve or stay away.. such a noisy and nasty thing u have done..
>      some code maybe?
>      can anyone help me to solve this asap ????
>      wtf is the downvote for?
>      this site is so fucked.
>      What the fuck is your problem guys? Issue is pretty well documented (visually and in text) just didnt bother copying the
>  longass code here.
>      English must not be disrespected too.
>      I suppose you're not populating it in your garage I mean WHEN and HOW WHEN in the lifecycle of the page.
>      Goddamn. Stop copying and write your own codes. Did you expect to completely understand the codes of someone else if you can't even
>  write up something similar yourself?
>      awesome. if that's the answer you needed pls tick it to keep this damn site tidy.  rock on
>      The question is why the fuck you can't use this??? They inject 'b' on the 'this' in regular javascript it works but on angular no way
>      Dude if I haven't have found your post I would have been jerking off on this issue till i drew blood..
>      No your mom.​​
>      phir tum logo ne apni maa chudai downvote karke :x
>      What don't you test ?
>      Are you all nuts and hypocritical? The OP wrote I want my iPhone5 App to scale (fill the screen) properly on iPhone6. My answer is
>  exactly an answer to the question.
>      do you think i am a slave to you ?
>      Somebody has a huge thirst of reputations no matter the way to obtain them.
>      Please search before posting.
>      thank you  you helped me a lot. unfortunately I can't give you score since some gays give me -1 for all of my questions !!! anyway
>  thank you
>      Strong pong of processed meats...........
>      So you can get 8 upvotes for telling the OP his question doesn't deserve answering. Lots of dicks on this site.
>      So your dummy'ness prevented to read the full Q&A you've already found?
>      ...and who a those people to read that sht?
>      half? are you serious? what is the point of asking a question then? first you are claiming it to be a duplicate and now you are referring half solution.
>      Even that is nonsense.
>      Please make your own homework instead of putting it up here
>      You Sir are seriously lazy and should learn to do your assignments by *yourself*.
>      Thanks for sharing.  Did you have a specific programming question?
>      Go find some work dont waste time here
>      It does not work is a truly useless thing to say. What happens or doesn't happen? What have you done to try to diagnose/fix the problem?
>      Please read my original post before commenting.
>      Alright so I just got destroyed on my third encounter with Stack Overflow. I refuse to believe that I am this incompatible with the community.
>      To gain experience or do you wish us to do your homework?
>      As a moderator I feel like you should know better than to answer terrible questions.
>      you just went and edited your code after I posted my answer and I stand getting downvoted for it. and you didn't mark it as an edit. gee thanks. never mind I deleted it.
>      You're a fucking asshole.
>      sorry if it bothers you...solution please!!!
>      Go back to school!
>      Oh wait... :P
>      Come on then bruv fight me!
>      Meet me market gardens! Me and **** will bruck you up fam!
>      Don't use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  It doesn't really make sense and you are using a MySQL (mis)feature that you probably don't understand.
>      Is this a joke question? Look at the `if` condition!
>      I'm afraid that you need to understand stuff first.
>      Would it even allow me to? And is it that hard to click two links?
>      O yea
>      You are everything wrong with this site and I'm sick of reading your drivel along with your code.
>      NO! FOR GODE SAKE! If i wrote standart swift file it means in a .swift file
>      how should we know? we have nothing to do with this repository you're using...
>      obviously yes. Thats a dumb question
>      stfu bich answer the question or gtfo.
>      GO fuck youself. idiot.
>      Why are you trying to write network code when you cannot handle basic string operations and cannot debug?
>      as well as being syntactically broken
>      delete this comment now wat the f**ck
>      `MapViewOfFile` and `UnmapViewOfFile` -- I suggest you actually read what these functions do.
>      I' m asking how to parse essentially...if you won't help then go.
>      Yeah i hope you email is ready for dick pics
>      `...` Unexpected tolken `...`undefined `...`wtf?
>      Is Google down again?
>      Of fuck that simple.. thanks man!
>      I'd like a toilet made out of gold but it's just not in the cards
>      So you want to avoid a recursive approach to traverse a data structure of arbitrary depth and composition?
>      you know what... why dont you go fuck yourself and edit the question towards closing the account. fucking superfly anyway... the fuck
>      Your momma is a replacement of $nbsp;.  SNAP!!!! :)
>      No because your implementation sucks
>      It would be nice if you marked your own answer as correct so that others can see the solution.
>      The upwork question is a shit?
>      That's also true. BTW I wasn't missing this sh*t really. It took two months after the suspension to get back to the feud :D Gonna downvote randomly pretty soon
>      didn't please check the answers you say is this post an answer? you could ask for more details in comments  not to post something instead
>      Study a grammar book first?
>      Does not change anything from what he said the OP
>      Please leave this site.
>      Have you tried [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)?
>      now who's copying others ....
>      You want to sort an array? Have you tried searching for a solution? There are literally thousands of examples of how to sort an array on the Internet.
>      **** Feel free to not reply again.
>      Uh-oh. He knows about the grey screen.
>      What part of worked for button for me for button Background is not clear?   Were you harmed by giving it a try?
>      Then your task setter doesn't have a fuckin' clue what he's doing and the best thing you can do is to find a new task setter.
>      NO this is YOUR interpretation and it is wrong. The only thing clear is that he doesn't want to code it in the action and don't you dare downvote the answer
>      I'm not gonna answer your question but here's a bunch of shit to read.
>      I can promise that it will break.
>      Actually the questions is for people that know about the topic no for beginners like you man
>      Try this System.out.print(Goat Meat)
>      ik can't except this answer. stackoverflow is a fucking lier. at least tell me something i can use.
>      You're joking right?
>      Let us not.  You've already wasted too much of my time.  Go think of something useful to do.
>      I couldn't give a fuck about bounties they are stupid.  Are you serious?
>      What are you taking about??!? READ [ASK]!
>      Sorry I don't have any more time to feed the trolls.
>      I didn't downvote some asshole did. Anyway thanks man I get it.
>      You should've editted this answer instead of posting twice
>      Are you really want help or just ask a question for entertainment or time-pass?
>      What *is* your question?
>      Alright chill out

Comment: Reading through parts of it, I think machine learning can help here but not precisely enough. Having worked in multi-national companies I've realized when non-native English speakers gather misunderstandings happen easily. Some simply are translating from their native language, and even though it might sound wrong in English, but to them, it's pretty polite. Same might happen if you translate from English to another language. I'm not sure how certain rules can apply here.

Comment: @NasrinShirali I think you're more likely to get responses if this is comment is a reply to the accepted answer. (I think you have a good point.)

Comment: By the way, the code snippet in the accepted answer has been spoilered (so it doesn't show up in searches), so...