# Search for abusive answers to questions with a given tag

Tags: support, search

I'm curious what examples there are on Stack Overflow of rude or abusive answers to Python questions. It's for a talk I'm going to give about how to be nicer to new programmers.

Is it possible to search for flagged answers to questions with a given tag? If this is possible, can I do it or must someone with more privileges than me do it? (I have 15k points on SO.)

Comment: 10k rep is sufficient to *view* deleted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools. I don’t think you can search for questions with deleted answers via the usual search bar, but have a look at https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: not sure what you mean with abusive answers. There are some [bad keywords](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=1&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=3&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) reasons recorded by Smoke Detector but I don't understand how those help to be nicer to new programmers.

Comment: What's your definition of rude / abusive and how are these to help your talk about being nicer to new programmers? Not quite sure how showing bad examples is going to help... I've just done a quick search for `[python] locked:1 is:a deleted:1` and the first page of those results is just vile...

Comment: In [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) some abusive stuff is reported based on [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494/can-i-have-a-dump-of-rude-abusive-comments). You're looking for Queen reports but those are for comments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe deleted posts are not in SEDE :(

Comment: @rene shame... who doesn't want to miss out on things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709638/checking-the-strength-of-a-password-how-to-check-conditions/46588862?s=3|0.0000#46588862) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810055/biggest-python-projects/46580920?s=4|0.0000#46580920) :p (Not for the faint of heart - 10k only and behind a content hidden warning - so be v. careful)

Comment: @JonClements epic examples. Totally wants me to become a mod to see more of that.

Comment: Anyway... I imagine the OPs more after examples of not such extreme examples of people with a tendency to blurt out vile being allowed near a keyboard, but perhaps more along the lines of being a bit blunt, condescending, a little snarky or general unwelcoming/patronising in tone kind of thing...

Comment: Might be able to work your way through: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/33?filter=tp and find some examples...

Comment: This fascination with new SO users that don't know how to behave themselves is unhealthy.  Surely you can better dirt at reddit or 4chan, etc.

Comment: Related, see [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) Its a long standing problem on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

This accomplishes my goal on data.stackexchange.com, thanks for the pointers.

```
select  
CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/', question.Id) as URL
from votetypes 
inner join votes on votes.votetypeid = votetypes.id
inner join postswithdeleted answer on votes.postid = answer.id
inner join posttypes on answer.posttypeid = posttypes.id
inner join postswithdeleted question on question.id = answer.parentid
where question.tags like '%python%'
and votetypes.name = 'Offensive'
and posttypes.name = 'Answer'
order by answer.deletiondate desc
```

Comment: Ahh... the "Offensive" `votetype` - forgot that was available ;)