# Can we statistically detect changes in friendliness from the Welcome Wagon, new CoC, New Contributor Indicator, etc?

Tags: discussion, new-users, welcoming, code-of-conduct, new-contributor-indicator

Can we statistically analyze the success of the Welcome Wagon, new Code of Conduct, and related UI changes?

I did some analysis I'll provide as a self-answer below, but new answers and edits are more than welcome!

Comment: Subjectively, I've noted that the tone is significantly more hostile everywhere now than it was before the changes, particularly on meta (such as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who)). Ever since the first blog post about these changes, the community has been significantly discontent with SO the company, judging by the numerous highly up-voted meta discussions where significant community consensus is opposing the changes. Quality concerned users don't feel particularly welcome on the site. ->

Comment: You can measure that reduced change in friendliness by the current score of +452(!) at the linked post, for example.

Comment: I would think that the most definitive answer will come, over time, from **outside** Stack Overflow. Just watch how many blos/forums/articles/whatever refer to SO as an "aggressive, elitist forum". Once we start seeing less of those we'll know that the changes were possitive.

Comment: @MartinJames For someone who constantly complains about how bad SO is, you sure are here a lot.

Comment: @Clint on meta, maybe. On SO main. not so much any longer:)

Comment: @Alejandro no, that won't happen.  The number of users who get really angry because 'their' homework was not done promptly by the SO drones will not change much.   Likely, most of those external ranters are, well, external because they got banned/suspended from SO.  That must be someone's fault and, since it could not possibly be because of the OP's bad  questions, it must be the 'agressive, elitist' curators.  Lashing out at the nearest target will not stop.  Engaging with those people is like negotiating with terrorists - you just get more terrorists:(

Comment: I spend a lot less hours helping people on StackOverflow in 2018 than I did in 2013 because the new users tend to be, overall, more incompetent, and less careful in asking questions that you can actually answer.  If you want to make a warm fuzzy hand-holding site where the points are made up and feelings are all that matter, I suggest starting over.  icanhaztehcodez.com may still be available.

Comment: @Lundin, I don't think the fact that "the tone is significantly more hostile everywhere now" necessarily supports the claim that "Quality concerned users don't feel particularly welcome on the site". I feel like a vocal minority of people have been acting out in protest, but I don't agree that it's a community-wide consensus. I personally find it perfectly viable to be both quality-concerned and also a nice, civil person.

Comment: @SamHanley That's what I've seen: a handful of vocal posters driving the line that the sky is falling, that "try to be nicer to folks" translates as censorship and personal attacks. I haven't had any trouble telling people their questions don't belong on SO without the snarky quips (which, according to quality standards, shouldn't have been there under the old rules).

Comment: @SamHanley +458 votes on meta is not a minority as meta goes, but exceptional community consensus. The main issue here is that SO the company repeatedly comes up with the wrong focus, implementing peripheral features that nobody asked for, instead of focusing on improving the quality of questions.

Comment: @Lundin the fact that that post got a high volume of upvotes is just one metric. If you look at the actual comments and answers left on it, it's clear that people have a wide variety of opinions. It's clearly not a case where a post was massively upvoted because people just unequivocally agree with its sentiments. I still firmly believe that while the community's feelings span a spectrum, the folks whose feelings are as extreme as the OP of that post are a very vocal minority.

Comment: @SamHanley Up-votes on meta mean "I agree", down-votes mean "I disagree". Currently 580 people (83%) agree and 122 (17%) disagree with the post.

Comment: @Lundin, you can't make that assertion across the board. That's a way that votes *can* be used on Meta, but there's plenty of times I've upvoted a meta post where I don't fully agree with the poster, but I think their post raises something worth discussing.

Comment: @SamHanley I won't even have that discussion. Here's the FAQ:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work

Comment: @Lundin what part of that do you think supports your claim? Here's what I read there, emphasis mine: "**On posts tagged feature-request**, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change in addition to usual reasons based on the quality or usefulness of the post itself. Also, on discussion posts, votes **may** be used to indicate agreement/disagreement with the author's standpoint."

Comment: Are you truly arguing that nobody has ever upvoted something on Meta except in cases where they fully and completely agree with the poster in terms of both substance and level of emotion? If so, I agree, there's no discussion for us to have here.

Comment: One of the main criticisms of welcominggate was that the "observations" (and thus, the "conclusions" that have been drawn from them) have **not** been based on hard facts and data to begin with. Trying to do a statistical analysis now is certainly interesting, but raises crucial (and obvious) questions: How should "friendliness" me measured? And more importantly: **If** we find out that friendliness has *decreased*, will there be a rollback of the changes and the CoC? Certainly not. There is an ideology behind all that, permeating not only stackoverflow but our whole culture.

Comment: @Alejandro Similar to my comment above: If the number of blog posts that call us "elitist" increases, does this mean that the changes will be rolled back? The number of bloggers who complain about "Stuff They Don't Like®" will *definitely* increase, no matter what we do. This does not mean that we're perfect or should not change and adapt, but this should happen through a careful evolution (based on profound insights), and not through aimless activism.

Comment: I would be interesting to see an update of this work. In a blog post by some SO employee from around November 2019 (can't find it anymore) I remember having read that they do something similar and they saw a significant effect. I remember something like a pronounced decrease of unfriendly comments over the last year or so. I may remember wrongly though.

Answer (score 29):

I pulled year over year (YoY) comparison treatment and control data sets using the [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow) portal of [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) and [this SQL query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/890843).

The filters on the data were:

1. Comments made on first-time questions
2. Most recent complete data for treatment ([August 7](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/) - 19, 2018) - assumes most recent 1 week of data may be incomplete, thus I ignored it
3. Same days of week and time of month 1 year prior (August 8 - 20, 2017)

I used the R language to read the data, clean the comments' text, and assign Sentiment Analysis scores from the Bing lexicon-sentiment database in the `tidytext` library.

The full code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/hack-r/stackoverflow_comment_sentiment_analysis/blob/master/comment_text_mining.R).

The sample sizes were similar in size YoY, with a few more in 2018.

I have filtered the words in the list of comments on pre-defined and custom "stop words", which are inconsequential or misleading words (e.g. "and", "if", "stack", "exchange", "overflow", etc, etc). **Update:** I've now included > 2,000 tag names in this list.

When I do so these are some of the most common remaining words:

[image]

The differences between Treatment and Control unfortunately evaporate when I do this:

```
> # Compare Sentiment YoY
> yoy <- sample_sa %>% 
+   group_by(flag_treatment) %>% 
+   summarize(avg_sentiment_bing_scale = mean(score))
> yoy
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  flag_treatment avg_sentiment_bing_scale
           <int>                    <dbl>
1              0                    0.467
2              1                    0.464
```

Stay tuned though as I clean the text further and as more time goes by.

At the end I decided to check the correlation between commend upvotes and sentiment. This part was interesting.

It looks like more negative comments tend to receive more upvotes. This may make theoretical sense, given that negative comments are often calling attention to missing / mangled information in the question, and upvotes signify that other users have the same concern or issue mentioned in that comment. This trend significantly increased YoY (you'll see what I mean if you run the R code).

Comment: It may be statistically significant, but is it *clinically* significant? 0.03 difference doesn't appear to be much.

Comment: Has it been a year yet?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Nope - year over year means that we compare last year (*control* group) vs this year (*treatment* group). Also known as a "pre/post" comparison.

Comment: *"It looks like more negative comments tend to receive more upvotes."* I have pointed this out a number of times.  Unfortunately scathing, negative, smartass comments **are funny**, so they tend to get upvotes.  I fear that far outweighs the pollyannaish view that it is folks helpfully upvoting constructive criticism!  :O  For better or worse..

Comment: It seems like it would be better to do a *monthly* comparison, as the majority of this year was not under the influence of the welcoming push.

Comment: What does `as.factor(flag_treatment)` mean? I don't understand how to read that graph or how it compares multiple years.

Comment: @Draco18s Sorry, yea I should clean it up. My time was a bit constrained. The `as.factor()` is just where I had to do a last second change to the data type for data visualization purposes. It's a 1/0 indicator (aka flag, binary variable, dichotomous, etc) that indicates treatment (2018 - Welcome Wagon) vs control (2017 - no Welcome Wagon)

Comment: Thanks, that helps, although I'm not sure what the graph is *measuring.* Post seems to indicate "number comments" with a filter, but I'm not sure if these are supposed to be "unhelpful" comments or "welcoming ones" or what.

Comment: @Draco18s The first graph just shows the sample size year over year as some background info. The sentiment analysis are the numbers you see at the end. There would be more material there, except that what I found at this time is no difference between test and control, so I didn't go crazy on the visualization / tables. Once enough time has elapsed for us to see more interesting results, I'll definitely add more.

Comment: @Hack-R I think the confusing part is your nice colorful graph is (no offence) a basically useless plot of participant numbers, while the important part is a grey table. Just make the numbers a single sentence...

Comment: @mbrig Done, thanks! You're right, it made more sense in the original version of the question when it was just 1 plot like that in a series. After I cleaned up the data the other plots went away because the gap in the outcome went away.

Comment: This is important guys... when did we change SEDE to SODE? Wasn't it always Stack Exchange's?

Comment: It would be nice to make the comparison not only 2017 vs 2018 but for every year since 2010. Maybe there are natural large scale fluctuations.

Comment: sentiment analysis can be really noisy, users here seldom call each other `stupid` for example, and we use technical vocabulary including  `positive`, `fuzzy`, `naive` ... I'd focus on specific term occurrences, like `lazy` (might be technical too but that's the best "insult" I can think of) , `...`, `!`, `;)`, `:)` `hello` `welcome` `no effort` ...

Comment: see a list of rude comments here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494/can-i-have-a-dump-of-rude-abusive-comments

Comment: @Hack-R nice, looks better now :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You're absolutely correct. You know, I have been trying to blacklist misleading/technical words (~2K of them) but really maybe I should just white list a few positive and negative words? Or maybe I should try 2-word and 3-word ("n-gram") groups instead of just individual words, to get the context.

Comment: I skimmed the comments from the link in my message above, looking for patterns, and couldn't really find any to be honest. There's a lot of sarcasm and traditional sentiment analysis is really bad for this. So maybe `...` would not be too bad.

Comment: Maybe another option would be to study the response of the OP, as new user they watch they're language a bit less, especially if they've been roughed up by a previous comment, they also use the words "sorry" "apologize" etc a lot. Yet another idea, look for these n grams that are associated with comments on posts with a lot of downvotes, maybe interesting things would appear.