# Are deleted comments included in the data dump?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Are deleted comments all included in file `Comments.xml` in the data dump (archive.org), although they have been deleted on the site?

If not, is there a way to see those (e.g., SEDE, etc.)?

Comment: The data dump you get is always outdated.  You'll have to assume you found a comment that got recently deleted on the site.  You can't know exactly when.

Answer (score 6):

Deleted comments are not present in the Datadump nor in SEDE. You can, of course, find comments that are deleted today but weren't at the time the dump was created.

Both SEDE and the Datadump are sanitized for deleted records. The only exception is the PostsWithDeleted table. That only holds metadata for deleted posts like tags, score, createtiondate, deletiondate and parentid

Content that got deleted is done for reasons of moderation. There is no way to get to that data except if you become a moderator, SE Employee with database access or a blackhat hacker.

If you need those deleted comments for "science" I redirect you to [Can I have a dump of rude/abusive comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494/can-i-have-a-dump-of-rude-abusive-comments)