# How did this user raise 5,000 helpful flags in only 52 days?

Tags: support, flags, users, helpful-flags

I was browsing the site, and found that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6655984/zaq) has been on the site for only 52 days, yet has over 5,000 helpful flags.

It should not be possible to raise that many flags in such a short time given the small number of starting flags and limit to the number of daily flags. How did they do this?

Comment: Shot in the dark guess: the account was migrated from another account, or some sort of transformation occurred where most of their account was truncated. Just a guess.

Comment: Could be a bot, where someone uses an algorithm to flag stuff.

Comment: @Rizier123 `5000/52=~96`. That means this user had to have about 96 votes _a day_ since the creation of their account, which is not possible (especially since the max flag count is 100). Plus, that's **helpful** votes, which means the bot would have to be a moderating genius. I'm still guessing an account migration.

Comment: @Rizier123 that's not the problem here; I actually did the math and the most flags that could possibly have been raised is somewhere around 3.5k.

Comment: This is possible with comment flags. Remember, comment and post flags have two different quotas.

Comment: This is not impossible. You get 10 flags per day at the start. For each 10 helpful flags, you get another flag to use per day, with a maximum of 100. Run that for 52 days, supposing they only get helpful flags, you get 4647 flags (if I didn't make a mistake somewhere). And that's only counting post (or comment) flags, to which you can add comment (or post) flags... and get to 5k. Either way, there is a very good automated system out there... or a very dedicated flagger :).

Comment: Well - it looks like you can run a script to flag comments that contain phrases that are automatically marked helpful by the system and get quite a large number of helpful flags in rather short time... Ummm....

Comment: Or a very knowledgeable user @JonClements ...

Comment: @JonClements shouldn't it just not let users post comments with those sorts of phrases?

Comment: @SomePerson While such phrases are black-listed now so users can't post such a comment - before they were users could. So there's comments out there on older posts that can be flagged.

Comment: @Tuna I've got a 3553 flag max just from comment flags... One of us has gone wrong. But yeah, with post flags, it's entirely possible.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I actually wrote a little c program to compute the maximum number of possible helpful flags starting from 0 in n days: https://ideone.com/XCBHHd The result for 52 days is 7486 possible flags, comment and post combined.

Comment: Well if they are helpful, no harm done really.

Comment: This user even has the association bonus of +100 rep despite not having reached 200 and being a member of SO only. How is that possible?

Comment: @FabioTurati he has an account on almost every SE site, including one with 1k rep (see the answer below).

Comment: @Floern But it looks like those accounts aren't connected. Maybe he asked to separate them, though I don't really see why one would do it, especially for an account that is used by a bot.

Comment: @Floern, Users have the ability to [hide which communities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276581/186281) they are a member of.

Comment: @Magisch 7486 possible, and he only has 5359? I guess it's up to him if he just wants to do the bare minimum...

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Note that the user in question has the same username and avatar <sup>(currently [i.stack.imgur.com/MNNJ3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNNJ3.png) but it changes often)</sup> as [**this user**](https://stackexchange.com/users/4412195/zaq?tab=accounts). (AKA, originally-ish, "Normal Human")

I can attest that he (once) had a Stack Overflow account for more than 52 days.

Furthermore, he is one of the lead coders of [the SmokeDetector project](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) and its associated chatrooms -- these are **tools expressly designed to find and help flag spam.**

He also has several userscripts and other (semi) automated tools to assist in flagging bad posts.  I wouldn't be surprised if he had the most helpful flags, across scores of accounts, of anyone on the Stack Exchange network, overall.  (Note that some of his network accounts are hidden.)

Comment: Oh wow. Well, that seems to work then! Would you happen to know if those suggested edits were also automatic?

Comment: Once you go charcoal, you never go back. And you get tons of helpful flags on all sorts of sites most of which you never want to actually participate in, just for the sake of busting spam.

Comment: I feel there should be some sort of badge or status indicator for those who contribute to the SE moderation tools like Smokey... might prevent questions like these.

Comment: No we're going to have to get out the men in black pen...

Comment: It is unfortunate that someone who apparently is very involved in preventing low quality content is now the most influential user in ushering low quality into Documentation.

Comment: @TravisJ, Yikes!  That is very disappointing.  I wonder if his account got hacked or he's going on strike?

Comment: @BrockAdams I've reached out to the user (or maybe automated account - I'm not sure completely). Hopefully we'll get a reply.

Comment: @ArtOfCode How has no one posted the [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/810/) yet then?

Answer (score 18):

If you're running some kind of script (or just happen to fancy logging on to do 25 flags at the same time four times a day) for a while that's getting you 100 obsolete comment flags marked helpful a day (say by focusing on an SEDE query to find comments that the system will auto mark helpful because of keywords/phrases etc...) and also do post flagging - reaching that amount of flags is perfectly possible in the time frame...

Comment: But is this an appropriate use of flags? Presumably the system requires a human flagger (instead of auto-nuking) because the content shouldn't be automatically deleted. Running a script like this defeats the purpose...

Comment: ... or is this in the spirit of [can a machine be taught to flag comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically)

Comment: @user000001 it looks like they're focusing on the old "what have you tried?" comments (which you can't type now but could then) which a single flag can nuke so a moderator never gets to see that flag (we tend to notice when the comment queue suddenly jumps up).

Comment: BTW, for each 10 helpful flags you get an additional flag, so for each day the user got incremental flags each day.

Comment: @rene it's not really causing harm - and it isn't causing moderators to have to handle the flags so bunging up the queue - but it really does seem fairly pointless.

Comment: On the bright side:  you now have some fresh meta reputation

Comment: I spot checked this user's edits - 20 *immaculate* ones, not a single reject! - and don't see anything suspiciously automated about them. There is a possibility a SEDE query was used for common errors such as "Im" and "dont" but it sure seems other issues were addressed as well. So ... "well done so far & keep up the good work"?

Comment: He's not (just) running SEDE scripts.  He's one of the leads in various real-time flagging tools. See my answer.

Comment: @user000001 - please explain how raising helpful flags, regardless of who/what is raising them *defeats the purpose*? What purpose do you think it defeats? The purpose of the flags is to remove useless at best and harmful at worst content, I would like to know what *purpose* you are referring to that this is undermining?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Note that these flags are marked helpful automatically based on a regex, without anybody validating them. In this case the comments probably needed to be deleting, but my concern was somebody flagging (and auto deleting) all comments containing "Thank you" or "accepting", without validating that there was no useful info in there.

Comment: @user000001 if there was something useful, it wouldn't be possible to use one-flag-nuke to delete them.

Comment: Again, this seems like a bad idea.  If a regex would auto-validate the flag, and the flag is being auto-generated by a regex, why not run the regex and remove all the content without a middleman?

Comment: I seriously doubt that string can be deleted with a single flag.

Comment: @Braiam: Why not try it? Here is a comment containing that string: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334774/how-did-this-user-raise-5-000-helpful-flags-in-only-52-days/334775?noredirect=1#comment397414_334775 ;)

Comment: @user000001 those rules don't apply on meta...

Comment: @Braim: Woops, comment gone

Comment: @user000001 good job - only took your single too chatty flag...

Comment: Just to let you know whoever this "person" is they are doing some really bad docs reviews.  They have been called out on meta [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335070/how-should-i-handle-a-poor-quality-documentation-change-that-has-already-been-ap) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334986/rejection-reason-response-to-documentation-or-a-question-about-the-documentatio)

Comment: @RamenChef a little ironic, you also appear to be in the doc review Nathan is referring to.