# Rejection reason: Response to documentation or a question about the documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, review-queues

Yesterday I ran into a documentation review where the changes where asking questions about a javascript function. When I went to reject it there was no appropriate reason to reject it so I had to use the other reason and mention that it was a question, not documentation.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/97472

Also as a side note maybe more instruction is needed on the review page as two people approved the edit.

Suggested rejection reason: This is a response/question about the documentation.

A rejection reason of "Not Documentation" would also work for cases like this as suggested by Kevin B in the comments.

For those who don't know what the current rejection reasons are here is what they are.

[image]

Comment: The 2 people who approved that edit need to be banned from review.

Comment: I don't think robo reviewers read instructions.

Comment: BTW, one of the two roboreviewers has [already been spotted not being entirely human](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334782/1667004) by raising 5000 helpful flags in 52 days...

Comment: I would consider that vandalism. Editing a (non-rhetorical) question into documentation defaces the page and is otherwise inappropriate.

Comment: @Comintern In the case I linked there was nothing there before hand so I am not sure I would say it is defacing it but rather just introducing content that is questions and not documentation. As such it does not appear that the vandalism is a good choice as a rejection reason for that but maybe the wording could be updated.