# How should I handle a poor quality documentation change that has already been approved?

Tags: discussion, documentation, flags, etiquette

Recently, in the Rust documentation, someone suggested [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/98481?filter-tags=rust) to try and clarify an example, but it contained several grammatical errors and changed the meaning to be incorrect (traits in Rust aren't *linked* to interfaces, as the edit would have suggested; they are *likened* as the original text said). Therefore, I rejected the edit as incorrect, but the change was approved overall and added into the documentation.

What is the correct action in this case? I proposed a revert of the change, which is currently awaiting review, but I was wondering whether it would also be appropriate to flag for a moderator, considering that 3 users **approved** the change which was clearly not a good change. In my opinion, if a reviewer doesn't even notice that the grammar is incorrect, then they aren't reviewing very thoroughly at all (perhaps another manifestation of the [robo-reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334387/robo-and-superficial-reviewing-on-documentation)?)

In summary, should I flag in the case of blatantly incorrect reviews, or just resolve the issues myself?

Comment: two of the three i immediately recognize as common problem reviewers.

Comment: One of the users (zaq) is actually the topic of [another](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334774/how-did-this-user-raise-5-000-helpful-flags-in-only-52-days) meta thread, it turns out. I hope it's not auto-approving changes that look OK (but aren't!).

Comment: He's also one of the ones that approved your fix to the incorrectly approved one.

Comment: @Aurora0001 He also approve [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334986/rejection-reason-response-to-documentation-or-a-question-about-the-documentatio#comment397781_334986).  He really needs to be stopped.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Those reviewers won't be doing so for a while. A larger question: why does it make sense that someone with no posts at all on Stack Overflow is able to review Documentation edits?

Comment: @BradLarson that is a very good question.  I think it should be a 2k privilege just like regular edits.  Thanks for handling the reviewers.

Comment: @NathanOliver IMO reviewing doc edits shouldn't have a rep limit that high. After all, isn't everything in Documentation supposed to be sort of a wiki?

Comment: Certainly higher than 1, though @dorukayhan? I would think at least 100 (edit community wiki on QA) would help...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's already set at 100. I personally would rather have it at 500, where the "access review queues" privilege is set.

Comment: But the reviewer mentioned here only had 1 rep @Kendra?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan User is currently suspended, they actually had 130+ when I checked a couple days ago. Edit: 138 rep, check their profile and their rep tab. Association and edits

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about suspension making the rep 1... Nevermind :)