# A New Silver Badge That Robots Simply Can't Win

Tags: discussion, badges, events, not-a-robot-badge

We don't do a lot of socialization on Stack Overflow, or even Meta Stack Overflow. In fact, we really don't do *any* socializing. But, that doesn't mean being social and having informal conversations is bad in any way, we'd just rather that folks do it somewhere else.

Somewhere else turns out to be in person for us. When it comes to getting frank, open and insightful feedback about everything we're building, we've decided that we need to be looking for it in informal, personal settings too. We get an *enormous* amount of value out of discussions that take place here on meta, but there's also something to be said for relaxed in-person conversations where it's way more efficient to communicate than it is through comments or chat pings.

To that, we're introducing a [new silver badge called "Not A Robot"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) that you can earn by attending an event with at least 50 participants where Stack Overflow is the organizer ***or*** where one or more of our employees are actively participating in an event.

This badge is rather unique when it comes to the criteria to earn *and* award it; I'd like to touch on some of the background and technical details starting with:

#### How will you know when the badge should be awarded?

For now, an employee will ask you to put the email address that you use to sign in on Stack Overflow into a simple form. This will either be one to several people working at our kiosk, or the people / person that presented a talk or demonstration.

Because of this, not *every* event will be eligible for awarding the badge. If a single employee is giving a talk at an event we'll make every effort to support them and enable them to award it, but it's not always possible if there's a high number of users attending. This is only a temporary caveat and one that we don't forsee running into much.

We're looking at a better, more automated way of awarding it now. Single use QR codes is one option, where we hand you a physical version of the badge as a sticker with the code on the back. **We are very open to ideas here.** We're going forward with it now because we're really ramping up the number of events that we host or where we plan to participate, and we really hope to meet more of you personally.

#### Can the badge be awarded multiple times?

Yes. The purpose of this badge is to provide any additional incentive that we can to pull you away from your usual Thursday night activities and come talk to us instead if we happen to be near enough for you to consider coming.

If earning another one is *just* enough incentive to pull you away from Magic The Gathering, we'll be super super happy.

#### I just show up and I'll get the badge?

Mostly. Even when we transfer to a more automated way of awarding the badge, you'll still need to get something from one of us in order to claim it. It's totally fine if you don't want to talk or interact much and we won't press anyone to do so. What's important is we're there in case you do, and we're creating a very deliberate opportunity for you to talk with us if you have things to talk about.

#### I'll never get this badge! I'm in [country]!

Hold on there, didn't I just mention that we're seriously ramping up our efforts to get (physically) out into more developer communities? That effort is global. One of the reasons why there has to be at least 50 participants at an actual *event* and not just an informal gathering is to help mitigate some folks having a bigger advantage than others due to proximity alone.

With eligible events coming to the US, South America, several parts of Europe and several parts of Asia, we think we're off to a pretty fair start. Some badges are very difficult to earn and many will not get them; an example being the beta badge that can't be earned at all any longer. We'll do our best to make sure there are plenty of opportunities in as many places as possible.

#### How will we know about events that we might be able to attend?

For now, there will be a quarterly post here on MSO that we'll keep updated. Ideally, this is something you can just find on Stack Overflow (and pull a feed from), but we want to have all of the automation mechanics and stuff nailed down before we go building that.

#### Why "Not A Robot"?

If you're asking this, it means you've never encountered a [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA), which makes you extraordinarily lucky or suggests that you don't use the internet very much :)

We know that *most* of you aren't made of tin and rivets, but we thought the name was pretty playful and would look nice on badge racks.

#### When will this be live?

You should start seeing people earn the badge within the next two weeks. The first round will be awarded at [codetalks.de](http://codetalks.de) on September 29 - 30, 2016<del>; we'll have the rest of the events for the remainder of this quarter posted soon (and linked here)</del>.

A comprehensive list is available here:

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

This shows a list of all past and upcoming events.

#### Is this specific to Stack Overflow only?

Yes, for now the badge can only be earned on Stack Overflow (in all languages offered).

Questions, comments? Please leave an answer.

Comment: April Fools' Day is very late this year ...

Comment: I suggest to rename this badge to ["Not A Dog"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog).

Comment: Looks like Jon won't be able to get this one :)

Comment: Am I the only one to _not_ understand what this is about? What are those "events" and their purpose?

Comment: @Tunaki - It's a badge for attending the same conventions (or workshops or whatever) as Stack Overflow folks.

Comment: It's funny because on the one hand being able to earn a badge for something you do in meat-space seems like a really fun idea. On the other hand, seeing other Stack Overflow users in person would be kind of  like...seeing your middle school math teacher outside of school.

Comment: @BSMP We organize probably 5 - 6 such events in Asia each year (I organize them myself) and they're actually not awkward or weird at all. Most of the conversation starts as "what are you working on" but quickly goes to trading horror stories and eating pretty good food. The feedback *I* get about Stack Overflow is also really valuable and almost amazing how 5 different people can see one UI element having rather different purposes (including the 'flag' dialog).

Comment: Damn extroverts get all the perks...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I will make an exception. If you build a robot that you can pilot to an employee that can award the badge, and said robot is capable of carrying back an item or conveying a piece of information - you'll still get the badge. No drones though, please.

Comment: Damn robot-builders get all the perks ;).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that the events weren't good or anything like that. I have this bad habit of attempting humor even though I should know better.

Comment: The talk starts tomorrow, and halfway around the world :( Still considering flying over there :P Hopefully the next time there is an event we can have a little more warning?

Comment: Gotta keep you on your toes @TravisJ! Last minute trips are the best. :)

Comment: Wait, Stack Overflow has been organizing 5-6 events a year in Asia?  I don't think I've ever heard them mentioned before; was this widely known?  I understand you're branching out now, but why there and nowhere else before now?

Comment: @davidism we've 2 talks in Singapore and 2 talks in the Philippines that I know of. A part from that we've done multiple events in China and Japan.

Comment: Damn you. I am actually a robot and now I can't get this badge.

Comment: Since it requires one to be physically present at an event, I expect to get a physical badge then as well. Silver price is today at $19.08/ounce. ...How big is it going to be?

Comment: For larger events, cycle QR codes on a screen/projector/whatever, have them expire after single-digit *x* seconds (sign and embed a timestamp in it) - that should close the possibility of folks gleaning them off Twitter, while taking the kiosk bottleneck out of the equation. Yes, I could FaceTime a buddy and send a QR to them that way in near-real-time... but at that point, it'd be easier to just go through the line twice and put my buddy's email in.

Comment: Repeat after me... CA-NA-DA. :)

Comment: B-E-E-R. oops I meant AUS-TRA-LI-A

Comment: So, if an Arduino powered drone rolls into one of the events and tries to give its email you're going to turn it down?

Comment: @undo That's precisely the scenario we're working around (people picking up the badge off Twitter / Facebook). When all is said and done, I think we'll give a physical version of this badge (probably in the form of a sticker or a pin), which would come with a single-use QR code that lets you award it to yourself on the site. That's where we were coming to, but it's going to take a while to implement and we've got a _lot_ of events in the interim, so we decided to just do it manually for now.

Comment: I have this great idea. Why don't you make a phone app where you get badges popping up on a map, and then you have to go to that real-life location to get the badges. Maybe make it so that some programming badges can only be found in certain environments, like coffee-stained cubicles or LAN party events. Maybe call it "Stack Overflow Goto"?

Comment: @Sklivvz: I'm sure there'll be a gold "With Blackjack and Hookers" badge awarded to those brave robots who build their own Stack Overflows. After all, you'll be able to put it in yourself.

Comment: Will these be awarded retroactively? I've been to the first Stack Overflow dev conference in London, and a usergroup meeting in Berlin but I don't anticipate attending any other events in the near future…

Comment: I live in Hamburg, but 699 EUR (plus tax) admission fees? No way.

Comment: @z00l we plan to be available at many more events, with many being low cost or free. We didn't want to create a badge just for folks that could pay entrance fees :)

Comment: @Lundin I consider that harmful.

Comment: @Timpost that's dronist.

Comment: The tickets to that round of codetalks have been sold out for a while. Actually when I attended their ecommerce special in Berlin earlier this year, I met some guy wearing a Stack Overflow t-shirt, just like the one I got from the 10m questions award, or the one for 100k rep. I asked him how he got it. He said "they had a booth at some conference. I went and asked. I don't even have an account there, lol." – Somehow I don't think this will be very successful because I think a lot of people don't have accounts. They just consume. You need to get them to sign up and care.

Comment: @Lundin that's called [Ingress](http://ingress.com). :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph we have a SO usergroup in Berlin? o.O

Comment: @simbabque Damn, you mean someone already stole my idea? :(

Comment: @simbabque Seven years ago…

Comment: I'll never get this bade! I'm in Hungary!

Comment: "Questions, comments? Please leave an answer." U W0T M8?

Comment: @BoltClock Just reread that.  Moved my concerns into an answer.

Comment: Do moderator/10k privileges extend to SO-hosted events? Will I be able to bring a large hammer and shutdown off-topic conversations?

Comment: If this goes ahead then perhaps there should be a matching gold badge for people who present at these Stack Overflow events.

Comment: 100 up votes and 48 down votes... 1/3rd is not in favor :)

Comment: Well that's a bit anti-robot.  Making the badge that they can't get silver as well is just adding insult to injury.

Comment: Will you come to _Pakistan_?

Comment: I'm not a robot! Do I need a badge for that?

Comment: @Talha can you suggest some conference we could be at, in Pakistan?

Comment: @SeinopSys why not? I spoke in many Eastern European countries (e.g. Poland, Ukraine, Russia, Romania...)

Comment: @Sklivvz I dont think we have SO community here, not even on social sites, so first thing would be to bring the users on one platform, and set the foundation? Maybe it is the hardest thing, people here are not very open to talk, specially in tech. One notable tech event is [ITCN Asia](http://itcnasia.com/).

Comment: @Talha sure, but it does not need to be a SO event, just an event where SO staff participates. I think in this case the 50 people minimum limit is the biggest issue. I don't know if we can do something, but rest assured that would certainly try to come to Pakistan if something got organized.

Comment: @Sklivvz If SO was to ever come to Hungary it'd most likely be an event in the capital (Budapest) and I live 233km away from that city. There's no way I could get anyone to use up that much gas to get me there & back just for a badge.

Comment: Just my opinion but I feel like this is a deviation from what's stated on the about page: [_"We’re committed to making the internet a better place, and our products aim to enrich the lives of developers as they grow and mature in their careers."_](http://stackoverflow.com/company/about). As with [teams](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions#answer-308814), this idea seems like it has merit but the problem it is trying to solve escapes me. And if the answer is that there is no problem, then I would argue it's out of scope...

Comment: I feel this badge is prejudiced against our robot overlords.  Please report to Friend Computer and/or Skynet.

Comment: I'll never get this badge! I'm in India! :'(

Comment: BTW Robots are helpful too - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334774/how-did-this-user-raise-5-000-helpful-flags-in-only-52-days

Comment: But what if I am a robot and I attend this gathering?

Comment: What I'm seeing here is precedent for [manually-awarded badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122698/134300). :P

Comment: This really seems to run contra to the usual [Being Physically Present Is Outdated](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/why-we-still-believe-in-working-remotely/) mantra espoused by StackOverflow: _"I can’t stress this enough: for every one person who is in your location or is happy to move there, there are 100 more who are not."_

Comment: "there will be a quarterly post here on MSO that we'll keep updated". Where is that post?

Comment: I won! :D [Success](http://www.memes.at/face/261)

Comment: Mission accomplished…  [Why is a robot getting a badge that states it is not a robot?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/why-is-a-robot-getting-a-badge-that-states-it-is-not-a-robot)

Comment: @TimPost any update on the list of upcoming events? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335787/link-to-upcoming-past-stack-overflow-events-via-the-not-a-robot-badge

Comment: Just found this badge and I've got to say, I like it.

Comment: Can I ask why @community has the badge?

Comment: @ItamarGreen A mistake. Somehow the email address associated with the community user (which, surprise surprise is team@stackoverflow) was entered into the tool we use to award it. Probably just a mistake, looking into it now.

Comment: @TimPost, no but it's hilarious

Comment: Turns out, [it was Craver trolling our mechanical overlords](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/why-is-a-robot-getting-a-badge-that-states-it-is-not-a-robot/335765#335765) after all. I'm inclined to leave it because it's quite possibly the most ironic thing on the site entirely.

Comment: I don't know...I flew all the way to New York to meet you guys, but mistimed it. Too soon - you hadn't invented this badge then :-(  Not to worry - have been looking out potential developer conferences in Scotland for you!

Comment: Event update please... its 2019 now and last year..... nothing much. And present at least a list of past event so folks can have their melancholic memory ...(cry a little.. for if they forgot to attend in their neighborhood (+/- 4000km radius).

Answer (score 115):

### I don't like this idea.

All current badges are for site participation. The purpose of badges is to encourage people to be more active on the site and help maintain and keep the site going.

Attending a Stack Overflow event has nothing to do with working on the site. This badge will not in any way encourage people to answer more questions, improve or clean up the site, and so I don't see the point of it.

I like that SO is Q/A driven site, and not a social site, and would like to keep it that way.

Comment: *"This badge will not in any way encourage people to answer more questions, improve or clean up the site, and so I don't see the point of it."* Do you have any statistical data to back this up, or is it just an uneducated guess? My uneducated guess is that it *will* encourage people to do those activities.

Comment: Aha, you're a robot, aren't you? Admit it!

Comment: @Stijn I respect your varying opinion, however, I personally do not see the connection between SO events and site participation. I feel this badge proposal is straying from the original purpose of badges and does not have a place here.

Comment: It's just a damn badge, it won't do a lot when it comes to encouraging people to be more active on the site but  there's certainly no downside to having this badge. It's pointless, maybe yes, who cares. Why does the community here always has to stomp on every bit of fun?

Comment: I don't like people to have fun in ways that I don't enjoy.

Comment: @GillBates I agree that it is just a badge and badges really do not mean much, yet like even you agree, this one is really pointless. And again, I'll emphasis my point that this new badge does not fit with the original set of badges.

Comment: @Stijn Statistical data (whatever that is) is not the only way to reach a conclusion. There is also reasoning and it is quite different from guessing. You earn badges if you ask good questions, if you participate in the website, if you help clean it up etc. So those activities have to be done to earn those badges; they are not the result of earning them. We can speculate all we want if earning the badge will change anything but it is clear that you don't have to do any of them to earn the badge.

Comment: @ayhan Well, my guess is that meeting the people behind SO in the flesh may change the view some people have of the site and have them participate more often. I could be completely wrong, of course.

Comment: In what way is this badge damaging to the site?

Comment: From Tim Post's reply to my comment above: *The feedback I get about Stack Overflow is also really valuable and almost amazing how 5 different people can see one UI element having rather different purposes (including the 'flag' dialog).* So these events do help them improve the site.

Comment: @Sklivvz Stack Overflow has gamification at the core of its system and this introduces unfair advantage. I know it is cool to say badges are not important or reputation doesn't mean anything but if that was the case we wouldn't be having this conversation.

Comment: I agree that it's a silly idea but it really doesn't matter. It's just a badge, that some people will forget, and 99% of the people on this site will either be unaware of its existence, not care about it, or just continue doing what they're doing with no change. The folks who care about it and get the badge, good for them, let them pat themselves on the back with pride. There's no reason to be *anti* this badge, though, it doesn't cause harm, it's just... boring, and its existence is irrelevant. So, whatever!

Comment: @Sklivvz Badges are just electronic awards that make people feel accomplished. In essence they mean nothing and so they can't actually damage the site. I just don't feel this is the place to encourage SO event attendance. To do that, SO can advertise events more. I personally almost never hear about these events and wouldn't mind announcements about them on meta or via email.

Comment: As a non-time-traveler I'm also offended that I can't go back and earn the Area 51 badge for Stack Overflow. Doesn't hurt my contributions in the slightest.

Comment: @Sklivvz it may not damage the site directly but it'll use developers' time which can be used to improve other things(I have no idea how much time it'll take but it will be more than zero). I literally don't get it _why_ we _need_ a badge for it? Just announce events anyway like you are planning to.

Comment: @Lafexlos We need this badge for the same reason why we need any other badge: reward behaviors that we want to encourage.

Comment: @Sklivvz The question is, is this the correct way to encourage SO social event attendance. I don't think it is. Like I mentioned above, I think better advertising is what you are looking for.

Comment: @TotZam Surely one thing does not prevent the other? Furthermore, we don't want to merely boost event attendance with this, we want to encourage interaction at our booths or with our speakers of people already attending.

Comment: In a sense, it encourages people to indirectly improve the site.  I can imagine that a good many SO events would cover a multitude of programming-related topics, and they would be a good way to interact with people who know more about any given member's preferred language(s) than they do, both of which could help members provide higher-quality assistance in the future.  I believe it should be a Meta badge, though, not a main site badge, as Meta SO is more in line with indirectly helping people provide higher-quality answers and/or documentation than with directly providing it.

Comment: @JustinTime `I can imagine that a good many SO events would cover a multitude of programming-related topics, and they would be a good way to interact with people who know more about any given member's preferred language(s) than they do, both of which could help members provide higher-quality assistance in the future` what happens in the event will stay in the event. Those people would help alot more by asking and answering in the site proper.

Comment: If we're all in general agreement that this badge is about participation, why is the badge categorised as "Other" rather than "Participation" on the [badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)?

Comment: I dispute the basic premise.  Although I haven't (knowingly) met any SO employees, I did meet a top-10 contributor and another experienced member at PyCon last year.  At the time, I was well under 5,000 points, but getting the hang of it.  |||  The meeting energized me, and I was more motivated to explore a few areas, in part to contribute better.  Today, I made "Trusted User" (20k points).  Meeting the "inside" people helped me focus ... and I *do* answer more questions and clean up the site.

Comment: I agree, specially because these events are probably never gonna be conducted in south-asian countries and they'll never be able to participate, hence the badge is only for 1st world citizens. Well whatever... we're still "not a robot" ;)

Comment: @Sabah The [past events](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past), shows that two of the events were held in the Philippines and one was held in Singapore. The main reason that the US Midwest is more strongly represented than other regions is that [John Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682840/john-m-wright) (Chicago) does a lot of speaking engagements on software testing.

Answer (score 54):

I think having a badge for something that has nothing to do with making SO a better site devalues other badges.

By making this proposed badge a silver one you are basically stating that if I spend half an hour phubbing in an SO-related event I have been as helpful to SO as someone who has:

- [Reached the rep cap fifty times;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic)
- [Asked a question with a score of 25 or more;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question)
- [Edited 50 tag wikis;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant)
- [Etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=silver)

If you do end up giving silver badges for people who have just been physically in the right place at the right time while their minds are somewhere else, then you should change the text on the [help section on badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) to something along the lines of:

> (...) you receive badges for being <strike>especially</strike> helpful, or for being around us.

Comment: Are you really saying a badge that proves someone is not a robot, does **not** make SO a better site?

Comment: @MrLister the badge proves nothing. I could go to an event and get a text/QR code for a badge, and then use it with a puppet or bot account. I could probably get multiple codes for badges in a single event depending on how things are organized in them, for multiple bots/puppet accounts.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I judge users by what they contribute to the site, not whether they are man, woman, cat, dog or robot.

Comment: @MrLister actually, a robot that got a lot of upvotes and badges would be awesome and would deserve an exclusive badge.

Comment: I think the real lesson learned here is people place too much importance on badges. Who cares? And making the badge silver has nothing to do with how helpful the badge is, it's about how hard the badge is to obtain.

Comment: The "rep cap 50 times" badge is among the *hardest* silver badges on the site.

Comment: @Yakk *The* hardest (Documentation Beta doesn't count). Also, kinda interesting that there isn't that steep a drop off from Epic (584) to Legendary (215). Once you're Epic, what's another few months of slaving away right?

Comment: @Barry I'm pretty sure there is are obscure tags out there where earning a silver badge might be as hard as Epic is for a poster on a popular tag.  My point was, comparing another silver badge to "is it as hard as epic" is just stupid.  Epic is harder than most gold badges on the site!

Comment: @Yakk Sure, might even be practically impossible on some tags. I guess I was just looking at the main ones.

Answer (score 38):

This is not a terrible idea at all. Indeed, this can be quite fun for a significant subset of the community, so it is not really bad.

Yet, it clearly sounded uncanny to some people. So, here is some of the possible reasons it could feel that way to us:

- Social gatherings attendance is *not* what we value here. Think about a person you respect here, who maybe is even a hero to you. Does it matter if this user goes to events?
- This event culture is not as widespread as many people think. Some communities value it a lot (I'd bet SE employees or startup dwellers are into it) but it is not true to a huge number of us. Many users do not have money for that, or live in a place where it is not a thing, or have disabilities, or simply do not like it. Most of my colleagues would rather avoid events. I would like to go to these places but I have a demanding family. Nothing of that mattered before - but now it matters.
- Most events feel kinda pointless anyway: presentations and workshops are in general too limited to teach something concrete, and there is a lot of hot air and vanity. Sometimes I wonder if conferences are a US way to get paid vacations :P
- Events can be good for networking and fun. Yet, we come here to SO exactly for that. It is fun to answer questions, and we get to know people.
- A metaphor: suppose you're attending a college class; some students are introspective and others are quite social. This is *not* a problem: if both get recognition and help as far as they deserve and need, it is fair. Now, if one day the professor congratulates a student for her beer pong match yesterday, it just feels *weird*. The professor can be into beer pong - but does it make sense to bring it to class?
- SO has a culture to value people for what they do, not for who they are. If you post good questions and good answers, and you are civil and polite, you are valued. Many people like the fact that it is what matters. In an event, it does matter if you are easygoing, funny or attractive.
- When you create a kind of extracurricular activity, there is some pressure to participate. For example, I play on my company's soccer matches, and frequently caught myself pressing other people to participate as well. Yet, most people here do not like it. I have to watch myself - is SO going to watch itself?
- Personally, I would like to see some less visible communities receiving more visibility. We have multitudes of users from the developing world, especially from Asian and Africa, but it is like they are just noise, I don't see them modeling the site in any way.
- SO has some real issues that are not addressed and yet we keep getting these solutions looking for problems. Low-rep users still cannot participate on discussions with comments - but what we get is this weird documentation thing. New users have a really, really hard time gaining reputation on SO -  but hey, you can go to some place to get a badge.
- Frankly, if there was a bot that would get all badges, it would be an awesome bot! Create a badge to exclude it is, seriously, the most anti-SO thing ever!

Again, I am not against the badge. However, I suspect its creators have not reflected about these aspects of the SO culture.

Here is a suggestion, then: if this is a badge for physical attendance, why not handing a physical souvenir?

(If you think you can describe another cause of uneasiness clearly, feel free to add it, I've posted this question as community wiki.)

**EDIT**: Oh, crap, they are onto me! This is what appeared when I submitted this answer:

[image: onto me]

Comment: `Now, if one day the professor congratulates a student for her beer pong match yesterday, it just feels weird.` No, that's cool. It's when the professor says "here, have a special reward for being part of my social circles" in front of the class that it gets weird.

Comment: "SO has some real issues that are not addressed and yet we keep getting these solutions looking for problems." pretty much sums up my objection.  All features [start at -100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/); how did this one get over that bar?

Comment: Some people like editing posts, some people hate it. Yet we award a badge for editing. Are we not respecting SO's culture by having it? Of course not. Some people like getting out of the cave and going to events, some people hate it. Yet we award a badge for showing up. Are we not respecting SO's culture by having it? Of course not. Badges are optional. The only two reasons I can think of that people don't want this badge are: 1) that they don't want to encourage people socializing AFK or 2) that they simply don't want changes. I disagree with the first, and ignore the second.

Comment: @Sklivvz Note that the concept of "respect" does not appear in this post. It is not disrespectful, it is just... incongruent, maybe? Anyway, some people like monster trucks, others like poetry, many like traveling and some like controversial debates about programming. We would never create badges for that! The first three are clearly too off the mark, but frankly, opinion-based discussions would be more related to what we do here than going somewhere—although it is rightfully banned.

Comment: @Sklivvz I am against the badge. I encourage changes. I don't care whether people socialize or not. What I don't like about the badge is how it  is about something that has nothing to do with making SO a better site, which is the stated purpose of badges.

Comment: @Renan It's mostly targeted at inactive users, whereas other badges are targeted at already active users.

Comment: @Sklivvz that's still missing the point. I do not think that getting a lot of people in a room makes SO a better site. Will each participant spend their time there with a laptop, tablet or cell phone, editing salvageable questions into good ones, helping with the review queues, ask good answers and give good anwers? I don't think so. What's worse, they may spend their time there dozing off, zoning out, playing games on their phones or texting... They may just arrive at the last minute, and because they successfully filled their names in a form, they get a silver badge.

Comment: @Renan it's users that currently do not participate to the site - the purpose of the badge is making them more active (e.g. visit the site while logged in, being engaged in gamification, etc.), which in turn will induce some of them to long term engagement. Not all badges that we have are related to doing something *directly* useful for the site (e.g. informed, autobiographer and many other participation and moderation badges), as you seem to assume.

Comment: +1 just for the edit.

Answer (score 26):

[image: relevant]

[Source](http://oppressive-silence.com/comic/captcha)

Comment: 'We are what we pretend to be, so we must be careful about what we pretend to be.' — Kurt Vonnegut

Comment: you are right sir,ni agree with you. @GreenReaper

Answer (score 23):

What if instead of badges you started a [pin gig](https://www.penny-arcade.com/pinny-arcade/pins) like the guys over at Penny Arcade? People would be able to collect physical pins that look nice, frame them on the walls, trade at every StackOverflow meetup. It would be a valuable collectible, but you'd have to come up with interesting designs. And it would be separated from the site participation badges in purpose and value.

For the first batch you could simply use the existing site logos:

[image]

Comment: I actually have an item from Stack Overfow, a T-Shirt. I cherish it very much, even though it's not my correct size. But having a badge for going to an event makes me feel even that shirt is devalued.

Comment: Would you also feel like the shirt loses in value every time a new mug, poster or a figurine appears? Then you better get them all :)

Comment: No, no, no... I mean my SO stuff I got loses value when a badge is introduced for going to a party. Other items and material have nothing to do with that.

Comment: You forgot an icon: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/alcohol/img/favicon.ico?v=521af06fc2a6

Comment: These are beta icons, they're all pretty much the same blue balloon with letters, except when they have symbols like anime, lego and chess.

Comment: This is cool! Can we also have patches that I can sew onto my jacket and wear around to impress the girls?

Comment: I don't know for sure but you might want to check the licensing for these logos, it could be free for all non-commercial personal uses. [Contact SE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) to make sure.

Answer (score 16):

In many cases there is going to be some sort of cost to get this badge. Even if the event is free there is still travel cost, lodging, food that the person may need to shell out. Even if it was only a day trip it can still be expensive.  Just to go from where I live to Chicago (which is about 60 miles away) cost $17.00 for the train and either $5 for the bus or subway if it goes there or up to about $40 in cab fare. I do not like that. It is almost like you are offering a premium badge that only the people with the means and opportunity to visit these events can get.

What would be nice if you could offer some sort of web conference/talks where a much greater percentage of the users could participate.  This way the people that cannot afford these cost, unable to travel, or just have an issue where they do not want to socialize or leave their house can still get the badge.  [Agoraphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoraphobia) is a disability and if Stack Overflow is truly open to everyone then even agoraphobics should be able to get this badge.

Comment: If I attend, I'll be selling my one-time-use physical badge code for only $20, let me know if you're interested. (/s, though I can see this happening until the process is automated)

Comment: There is cost associated with getting *any* badges. First you have to buy a computer, then you have to buy an Internet connection, then you have to buy a keyboard and mouse...

Comment: @meagar There does not have to be one.  Someone could use a public computer at a library and have no cost at all using SO.  Also the cost of the PC is something almost anyone who is doing programming need regardless if the they use SO or not.  This goes above and beyond.

Comment: @NathanOliver And then you've got to travel to the library, and eat while you're out for the day, and then travel home, and the expenses just pile up!

Comment: Apparently "library anxiety" is [a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_anxiety) too.

Comment: There will be plenty of free / low cost events all over the world where people will have an opportunity to earn the badge. If you think about it, most folks are _much_ more likely to earn this one than Generalist (speaking as a systems programmer that has knowledge in at most 6 or so tags). So I definitely think heading to a meetup is cheaper than all those darn books I'd have to buy :P

Comment: Books? What is this thing called books?

Comment: There is _always_ a cost to any badge, you are assuming your time is not worth anything. We are going to offer this badge at both pay for and free conferences.

Comment: @TimPost - Where is this list of planned events you allude to? :)

Answer (score 12):

So people don’t seem to like mixing real-world badges with the ones earned on the site. And they have a point - the current badges are arguably pretty egalitarian in that anyone with a computer and the skills can earn them, at least in theory.

If meetups might become a bigger thing again, why not create a second „Meta“ site for in-the-flesh Stack Overflow gatherings?

- Name it „Stack Overflow Meetups“ or whatever
- It would be coupled to the main site like Meta is: rep is synced with the main site
- On-topic questions:

  - Meetup announcements (promoted on the announcements on the main site as events come up)
  - communication regarding specific upcoming meetups (what will X be talking about on Meetup Y; how to find place to sleep in X, anyone from Y going to Z etc... although that is a slippery slope, one’d have to see where to draw the line and say "go away, go to couchsurfing / craigslist / zipcar etc.")
  - questions about how Meetups work in general, how SO organizes meetups
  - Feedback, criticism, questions about past meetups
  - feature requests for future meetups, discussions about how meetups should be organized
  - planning/voting threads for future meetup locations, talk wish lists, speaker wish lists
- You could always display Meetups.SO badges on the main site in users’ profiles, to promote them outside the subsite, underneath the current badges or wherever. Badge descriptions should also be relatively easy to teleport into the main site if so desired, maybe in a separate area so as not to mix them with the regular SO badges
- Similarly, Meetups.SO badges should be relatively trivial to incorporate in the main SO flair, etc.
- The „went there“ badges could be silver or gold badges on this site; or a different model: gold badges for contributors / speakers, silver badges for folks who help organizing a meetup, bronze for attendance?
- Its scope could (optionally) be expanded to cover the podcast, given that it’s arguably a very community-oriented feature and the only way to experience SO employees in person on a regular basis (for better or worse, ha ha). That would make the following types of questions on topic:

  - Questions about something that was said in the podcast
  - Suggestions on future podcast topics, feedback, etc.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I have presented at several local meetups, some found by word of mouth, others by meetup.com, and at almost every event there has been a least one SO user (aside from myself), sometimes even with a significant amount of reputation. Building local community to support developers is an important aspect of "making developers lives better" in my opinion, and facilitating that at Stack Overflow seems only natural.

Answer (score 6):

> Single use QR codes is one option, where we hand you a physical version of the badge as a sticker with the code on the back. **We are very open to ideas here.**

Sounds wasteful.
Why not add some API to the site that allows display of the user ID (which is unique, right?) as QR code?

Then people at the event can simply pull this up on their phones or computers and the employee can scan it. Like in a super market. Should be efficient.

---

Alternatively, a local wireless network that users can connect to might be a good solution if there are a lot of people. However, I'm not sure how to identify users securely and make the connection to their account.

Answer (score 5):

> Single use QR codes is one option, where we hand you a physical version of the badge as a sticker with the code on the back.

That seems like overkill (although those physical badges could be collectibles if they're rare enough).  If you're going to assume we have smartphones anyway (because who's going to scan a QR code without a smartphone?), you may as well use something like NFC to do this without needing to hand out a physical token.

Comment: I think you can probably also use a webcam to scan a QR code(?) You can certainly print the URL below it.

Answer (score -7):

I think this is a very good and fun idea.

How exactly it is implemented isn't all that important.  It encourages participation.

Go for it.  Give out an imaginary internet off-grey circle a few times a year.

(This answer added because all of the existing answers where some variant of criticism.  This one is for people to be able to say "looks good!" with a vote.)

Comment: People can already upvote the question if they like the idea. This is already quite common with [feature-request]s.

Comment: @Glorfindel - And they can downvote the question if they don't. By your logic, Meta posts don't need answers.

Comment: @SomethingDark Meta posts don't need answers that don't add any additional value to the discussion. There are other answers to this question which do support the idea, but take some interesting points to the spotlight. That's fine - that's [how Meta works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @SomethingDark also, I've seen cases where the question was a community poll (initiated from the moderator team), with three or more options, each in a separate 'answer'. I think it's ugly, but maybe [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335563/4751173) was inspired by that.