# Why is a robot getting a badge that states it is not a robot?

Tags: support, badges, community-user, not-a-robot-badge, events

With the first batch of people to receive the [Not a Robot badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot), I was surprised to see [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1) receiving one as well. Does this mean I will be able to meet the fabled Community in person?

[image]

Comment: Plot twist: Community user is secretly Jeff Atwood.

Comment: Maybe it has passed the Turing Test?

Comment: Looks like the AI project worked and the bots are now smarter than us.

Comment: An anonymous user attended a real life event and the badge was attributed to the Community user.

Comment: THE SYSTEM IS RIGGED!

Comment: Plot twist: Community user is secretly me.

Comment: Jon Skeet is the one who introduced Community to Jeff Atwood

Comment: [Another one?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=5970048)

Comment: @BenVoigt what in the... what the?!

Comment: @BenVoigt [Flips desk](http://www.memes.at/faces/desk_flip.jpg)

Comment: I've been to many meetups hosted at the NYC headquarters, how do I sync real life to StackOverflow?

Comment: May I have a "Not a Human" badge?

Comment: just waiting for Community to show up and post saying *"who said anything about me still being a bot"*

Comment: The real problem is that there's no [Voight-Kampff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner#Voight-Kampff_machine) test administered during this process...

Comment: I somehow remember a movie... what was it called again....  I, Robot! Hope Will Smith will show up at SO and rescue us.

Comment: @Qix is Community really Jeff Atwood?

Comment: @Community can you get pings too?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Aaaannndddd... Community edited this question and one of the answers last May, I'm dying laughing.

Comment: @Qix Considering that [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) is user 1, and [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is user -1, I would say that the Community user is the _opposite_ of Jeff Atwood.

Comment: I'm tempted to change my screenname to "Community" so I can comment.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED The plot thickens: your suspicion has been [confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356864)!

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Amazing.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

> Somewhere on Stack Overflow is an easter egg I inserted directly in SQL today. I wonder how long it’ll take people to find it…

I was wondering [how long it'd take meta to notice](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/783101082780205056). About 21 hours, not too shabby.

Comment: If you did it then it was more of a sock puppet than a robot. Still funny tho.

Comment: What does @Adriaan win? Surely worth a t-shirt?!

Comment: @Liam He wins the "Noticed the Easter Egg" gold badge.

Comment: But it's not even Easter yet... :|

Comment: It will be awarded at christmas

Comment: But will take 6-8 weeks to arrive.

Comment: @Liam - well, if nothing else, he has already won a gold badge on meta for his efforts.

Comment: Wearing a badge is difficult when you don't have a shirt to pin it to though @Simba

Comment: This easter egg made my day.

Comment: Now that @Adriaanhas found this, does community keep the badge? It seems strange to me that the badge is still there.

Comment: @Nick okay, we noticed months ago. Isn't it time for the joke to end? **I think it's time to manually remove that badge from her**

Comment: Now give it a "I Am a Robot" badge.

Answer (score 27):

That's because community looked up our [list of upcoming Stack Overflow events](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) and came to one to get the badge. You can do that, too!<sup>†</sup>

---

<sup><sup>†</sup>Only available at selected events. Your mileage will vary based on distance. You might need to wait until someone shows up at a meeting near you. You might need to leave your house to get the badge.</sup>

Comment: How could he come to an event if he's not a real person?

Comment: Has there ever been a time when the list of upcoming events was not empty?

Comment: Oh look, upcoming events. All on the other side of the world though; very funny. Munich I could have managed, had I only known.