# Not a Robot badge events

Tags: discussion, support, badges, events, not-a-robot-badge

List of events awarded the new [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge:

1. **code.talks** in Hamburg

   - took place on September 29 - 30
   - awarded on Oct 3 at 14:49
   - awarded to 61 users
2. *unknown event*

   - awarded on Oct 13 at 13:39
   - awarded to 7 users
3. *unknown event*

   - awarded on Oct 17 at 13:01
   - awarded to 2 users

What are the last two events?

Comment: @Stijn Thanks, but the question there isn't answered?

Comment: Indeed it hasn't. I've pinged @TimPost on the announcement post and asked for an update.

Comment: Those 9 users attended the Hamburg event. However their replies were not quite coherent and were made to take a Turing test. The test results came on 13th and 17th and subsequently they got their badges.

Comment: @BhargavRao Can we expect these events in India? I am eager to take Turing test.

Comment: @ManojKumar That is just what a robot would say.

Comment: What I want to know is how @Community was one of the 61?

Comment: @CWilson http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335736/923847

Comment: All those badges were awarded for code.talks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comprehensive list is now available here:

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

This shows a list of all past and upcoming events.