# How is it possible that Community User created a question?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I saw lot of posts that are edited by the Community user. I know that is a background process that helps keep this site clean.

But I can see a question [Sandbox archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive) which is raised by the [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community.) user

How did that happen? And what about the reputation count? The community question has many upvotes, but it's still showing 1 reputation in that profile.

Comment: This question obviously belongs to meta.stackexchange.com, not meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Tom How can i migrate it to that?

Comment: There is [evidence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335736/812149) that Community is not a bot at all :-)

Comment: well here is another question in an Workplace.SE for you https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57500/how-can-i-deal-with-being-told-i-ask-too-many-questions :p

Comment: Community *doesn't do anything*. It is only *blamed* for things that happen. The post is assigned to the user ID `-1`, aka Community. The account never posted it, the post was created by the site developers then assigned.

Comment: @SurajRao Okay. But my question is how is it possible? I didn't see any details about **Community can create question and answer** in there profile. :(

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does that mean an SO employee posted it, and then had the ID reassigned? Or do they just put it in the database, along with an ID? Just curious.

Comment: It's the "Catch-all" account for orphaned questions, votes, flags and whatever... What else would they assign that archive to?

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I don't know. There is no 'asked' entry in the timeline for the post, so it may well have been the latter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Does make sense

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough, thanks anyway! The [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296077/timeline) isn't informative there either. Just one more mystery that us non-SO-employees can only guess at :-)

Comment: @RameshRajendran Because that's how things were programmed. The Community bot doesn't get rep points. It's a bot, it doesn't make sense to give it points. (Well, there once was a bug where it did get a few points, but it was soon fixed).

Comment: ... Ramesh, please _think_ before asking. You are already aware that Community isn't a normal user. (Otherwise you wouldn't have posted this question). What explanation could there be for the `1` rep? Because that's how it was designed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there certainly is an asked event in the timeline: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296077/timeline#history_a6227b8a-a441-4ff1-b1b8-73ccff471f8a

Comment: @rene duh, of course. All those moved answers threw me off.

Answer (score 3):

This is [probably](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6658396#6658396) what happened:

The [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) question got so crowded with answers that it became no longer usable / caused performance issues on the server / annoyed enough users, got [auto-protected each time a new answer was deleted](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5940273#5940273), etc.

[Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), a Community Moderator and Stack Exchange employee, <s>impersonated himself as the Community User (IIRC SE Developers have an option to do that so they can in case of bugs experience the site exactly as if they are you, but worst case he has the password for that community user</s> (this only exists on private dev builds)) clicked *Ask a Question* to create a new question, as can be seen from the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296077/timeline#history_a6227b8a-a441-4ff1-b1b8-73ccff471f8a). After he posted the question he manually assigned the Community User as the owner of the post which is an option available to SE staff as part of the dissociation tooling (as explained by [Animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362858/how-is-it-possible-that-community-user-created-a-question/362862#comment554179_362862)).

He then merged all the old answers from the original Sandbox to the just created new question. (or he used his fancy [Move answer](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6031927#6031927) tool)

Last but not least he locked the new question. That prevents any voting (closing, up/down), flagging, editing on the question and its answers. That is observed by the post notice:

> locked by Shog9♦ May 16 '17 at 19:56
>   This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

You are mistaken that there are votes on that question. Its score is 0/0. However 9 users favorited the question.

Here is evidence from the Community Manager after he made that change and some side effect it had:

[Fix links to moved sandbox posts and comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301788/fix-links-to-moved-sandbox-posts-and-comments)

And in the Tavern he gave some [feedback](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6031888#6031888) after he was pressured by some regulars to do something about the regular Sandbox.

Comment: Martijn Pieters noted that the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296077/timeline) did not have an entry for when the question was asked. So although it looks as if Shog9 is indeed responsible, he apparently did not impersonate himself as Community.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Martijn didn't check correctly then, the question is asked by Community, and that sits nicely in the timeline, only not at the start of the timeline.

Comment: Well, he's not the only one... either both he and I overlooked it, or the timeline was updated. I'm guessing the first. For those curious, the timestamp for when it was asked is: May 16 '17 at 19:55

Comment: It's actually not that complicated. All he did was ask the question and then reassign it to the Community User (essentially change the owner ID manually). There is no impersonate feature on production builds, that's only something devs can do on the private dev build.

Comment: @animuson cool, how *manually* is that? Is that a mod option, a CM option or a *needs developer with SQL cmdline skills* option?

Comment: @rene Uhh I believe it's a staff + moderator combination option (as in you need both privileges, not just one of them). It's a part of the disassociation tooling.