# Does the Community user really only have 649 profile views?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I was in the suggested edit queue and one of the posts was rejected by Community, which I've seen a few times around the website. I was intrigued to see that it only has 649 profile views yet it's an automated process account that appears in a lot of places, is there something funky going on here?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Its meta profile has almost 5k views

Comment: It does a lot of things that should push that profile up to the high rep level of views, seems broken or maybe the 649 is a memorable number maybe.

Comment: It probably had 649 views on Aug 26 '08.  The day they decided that updating the account metadata was pointless.

Comment: [Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)

Comment: The poor thing doesn't even have a "people reached" stat... while it's the most active user on the network! :-)

Comment: It has a remarkable low view count across the network: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/884805

Comment: I suppose I'm even more curious as to why it was deemed pointless now if that was the case.

Comment: @rene Looking at that, the amount of meta views really stands out.

Comment: Is there any estimation of the real rep of this MVP? How many JSkeets (The astronomical unit for User Reputation) does it has?

Comment: More importantly: Should it have the "Not a Robot" badge?

Comment: It has cast more than 1.2 million votes, and given away close to 250k in bounties! How?!

Comment: @Vlad274 check [Why is a robot getting a badge that states it is not a robot?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/why-is-a-robot-getting-a-badge-that-states-it-is-not-a-robot)

Comment: I wonder if there's an easter egg for whose older jeff or community where the community is older than jeff to show that we were here even before the website was started ;-) Both 10 years.

Comment: @NisargShah read its profile info , Community Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted , that explains 1.2 million votes

Comment: The profile views went up so fast that the meter needle (it was an analogue meter in those days) hit the endstop and wrapped round it, thus fixing it in position. The end of the needle just happened to end at 649.

Comment: I second user3717023 comment about machine discrimination whole heartedly.