# Why does the Community user still have a 'Not a Robot' badge?

Tags: discussion, community-user, not-a-robot-badge

The [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge has the following description:

> Met a Stack Overflow employee at an event where Stack Overflow was an organizer or participant with 50 or more attendees. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

I wondered how the [Community User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) had the 'Not a Robot' badge if it's a background process. Then, I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/why-is-a-robot-getting-a-badge-that-states-it-is-not-a-robot) post which states that it was an easter egg inserted by a user named [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver). This was 7 years ago. If the badge really was an easter egg, why does Community still have the badge?

Comment: "If the badge really was an easter egg, why does Community still have the badge?" I'm not sure I understand the reasoning. It seems like you are reasoning about the term *easter egg* based on your understanding of Easter tradition, i.e., figuring out the metaphor from scratch. But in the programming world, "easter egg" is [well-defined jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)). Since it normally appears in end-user media, there is no expectation of it being removed when found, because there would be no mechanism for doing so. Nor is it time-limited or specific to the holiday.

Comment: "_This was 7 years ago. If the badge really was an easter egg, why does Community still have the badge"_. Maybe your confusion stems from thinking that "Easter Eggs" happen only during Easter, and are seasonal and should "expire" or something? If not, it's completely unclear why you think the badge should have been removed. Your second question is actively answered in the same post you link. So that's weird.

Comment: Anyway, the idea behind it is that giving a badge that says "not a robot" to a background process (i.e., the closest thing to a "robot" actually in the system) is deliberate irony.

Comment: For you! If it had been removed, you wouldn't have been able to discover it.

Comment: Can a robot have a sense of humor?

Comment: A robot has no more of a sense of humor than a piece of paper with a joke written on it does.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no specification for [Easter eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)). Thus there is nothing that requires one to be removed once found.

Comment: It's kind of misleading. It's a good joke no doubt, but isn't it illogical for a background process to have the badge?

Comment: That's the joke.