# How will we know about events that we might be able to attend to receive Not a Robot badge?

Tags: support, badges, events

From [A New Silver Badge That Robots Simply Can't Win](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335432/1529630),

> **How will we know about events that we might be able to attend?**
>
> For now, there will be a quarterly post here on MSO that we'll keep updated.

I can't find that post, but the [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) has already been awarded to some people. How did they know about the event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A comprehensive list is now available here:

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

This shows a list of all past and upcoming events.

Comment: Any way to subscribe or get notifications for new events?

Comment: @Stijn not currently, but you are welcome to open a feature request

Answer (score 5):

From the same post that you linked

> When will this be live?
>
> You should start seeing people earn the badge within the next two
>   weeks. **The first round will be awarded at codetalks.de** on September 29
>   - 30, we'll have the rest of the events for the remainder of this quarter posted soon (and linked here)

The next events will (probably) be posted as separate new posts quarterly.

Comment: Oh, I read that part some days ago but forgot. I thought some post had already been posted somewhere else.