# When is the next Stack Overflow event for developers?

Tags: discussion, events

When is there going to be a Stack Overflow event for developers and not for [businesses](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/uk/talent/events)?

I saw there was one in [2009](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/12/stack-overflow-developer-days-conference/) only and one cancelled in [2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/06/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/). Is there a relevant site for this? Is it the [badge events](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events)?

Comment: Possibly related: [How will we know about events that we might be able to attend to receive Not a Robot badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335747) and its link to https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

Comment: but did you also read: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/06/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devdays

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks, I think?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can you share? I'd love to see something in Northern CA.!  Sadly, I don't see any upcoming events at https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=current.  Thanks.

Comment: @SherylHohman Sure, just wait 6 to 8 weeks. ...But on a serious note you should look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514).

Comment: I think I should change my title to When is the next party? so I'll get even Great Question ;)

Comment: [418 badges awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot)...that went well.

Comment: @Liam Keep in mind that one of them was awarded to Community ♦, a user who seems to act very much like a `cron` job.