# Link to upcoming/past Stack Overflow events via the 'Not A Robot' badge?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, events, not-a-robot-badge

I [recently noticed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335736/1075247) people have started getting the new badge, [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot), and immediately wanted one myself, and wanted to know where it had been acquired.

Would it be appropriate to link to upcoming events via the [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) page? Obviously that shouldn't be the only place it's displayed, but might be a nice addition.

Also, is it possible to put the event that you attended on the badge somehow? I really don't know how it would be best displayed, perhaps in a tool-tip?

Thoughts?

Comment: @Gothdo Seems Pureferret is asking for the community's thoughts on whether it's a good idea before making a formal request for the feature.

Comment: @Gothdo I've been [burnt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248468/175002) too [often](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145471/175002) by requesting a feature. I'm happy to just discuss this.

Comment: Asking the community for thoughts is tantamount to a feature request and will already be voted on as if it were one.

Comment: "Don't ask to ask, just ask the question". This is a feature request. Also, this is Meta.SO, where there is no reputation *to* burn.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll relent, this is probably popular enough to be a [meta-tag:feature-request] anyway

Comment: I bet Community is a robot, but it got the badge :-)

Comment: @DaniEll And the [first one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381?page=2) who get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comprehensive list is now available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events).
This shows a list of all past and upcoming events.

Comment: No, it doesn't!