# Will there be any future events for users to earn the Not a Robot badge, or is the badge retired?

Tags: support, badges, not-a-robot-badge

It's been [more than a year](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) since the last "Not a Robot" badges were awarded. Also, there are [no current events planned](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) where users can earn the badge.

I understand that SE employees and users can't physically meet due to the ongoing pandemic, but users can still (theoretically) earn the badge by virtually meeting an employee in a virtually organized conference. (The badge description doesn't say that you have to have *physically* met an employee, just that you have *met* them in some way, which by definition includes virtual meetups.)

However, there have been no virtually-organized meetups which SO has organized or participated in.

Is the badge retired, or will there be any virtual events where users can meet SO employees and thus earn the badge? (Or am I wrong about the badge criteria and that it indeed only applies to physical meetups, in which case it can't be earned until after the pandemic?)

My request is that the team either:

1. state that future events are being planned or will be planned, and that the badge will continue to be issued, or:
2. officially declare the badge as retired if no future events will be planned at any point.

Comment: it is corona time,so in worst case there will never ever be an event anymore

Comment: I like the virtual meetup. I thought most of those conferences were to get more engagement from users. Or get new users to join up. Not sure a virtual meetup is going to help with that.

Comment: @nbk In that case, SE should declare the badge as being retired.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the "Not a Robot" badge is SO specific. I didn't realize that.

Comment: @cigien Do you have a locked downvote that you need to remove?

Comment: No actually, I upvoted the question already :) It seems a reasonable question, I just mentioned that it should have been posted on MSE (in a comment I've deleted) because I hadn't realized it was an SO specific badge.

Comment: I wonder what happens if 50 Stack Overflow members decide to have an online event.. and invite some Stack employees :)

Comment: I'll start making the snacks.

Comment: *"Hmm, it seems the "Not a Robot" badge is SO specific."* - Yea.  On SciFi it is the "This is not the droid you were looking for" badge.  (Or "Not an Inhibitor" ... )

Comment: SO on clubhouse would be fun.

Comment: Well... With current deepfakes/speech generating AI I wouldn't trust a virtual event to prove someone isn't a robot ;)

Comment: I want a "I'm a robot" badge, because sometimes I feel like I am, especially when reviewing.

Comment: Why would anyone want to meet a SO employee? Aren't we hate them? =D

Comment: @Sinatr That is *so* last year ;)

Comment: Wait, in that case I have a badge!

Comment: I want a "Is an AI" badge too. I'm sure I'm sufficiently unadvanced to have a chance at failing the Turing test.

Comment: hang on, let me pull out my crystal ball

Comment: @nbk, the CDC is starting to come out with relaxed recommendations for fully vaccinated people. As more people continue to get vaccines, the guidelines will likely become even less strict, so there's apparently a light at the end of the tunnel after all. https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/fully-vaccinated-guidance.html

Comment: @computercarguy i get evry year a vaccine against the flue and still i get sick,  because here nobody uses masks,w hen tehy feeö a cold comming. Vaccination can be a solution, as klong as 80 % get vaccinated, but that number is fluent, depending on the incarnation of a virus. As more pople get vaccinated, more vorulent starng where it does't work will comei don't know the future and will wait and stay n home offce as much as pssible. simpmy yu need ne suer spreader and a hole region ges dwn.

Comment: @nbk, I totally get that. We may never completely get rid of Covid-19, let alone all viruses, but we can make them rare, like the measles. The flu was cut down considerably this year, because of what we did for C19. Fortunately, these vaccinations are showing good response to the variants of C19, too, so while it's not over tomorrow, an end seems at least possible now.

Comment: If I were a robot, the "Not a Robot" badge would make me feel unwelcomed.

Comment: @kjhughes In that case, apparently the Community user [doesn't have feelings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=badges)

Comment: This question sounds like a question a robot would ask....

Comment: What if a robot created an android that attended an event?

Comment: Wouldn't a virtual meeting be a great place for robots to participate? If I were a robot, I'd certainly participate a virtual meeting to earn a badge, the purpose of the badge would be thwarted.

Comment: Suggest a "Social Distance" badge in an online meetup.

Comment: @kjhughes, have you seen my avatar? Lol.

Comment: Is the "Not a Robot" badge a virtual badge or a real one ?

Answer (score 19):

I'm... I guess really confused by your request. We're in the middle of a pandemic that's showing no signs of stopping and we don't know what the future holds. I'm also not really sure why it matters whether it's retired or not - **now**. It would be unsafe of us to try and get people to meet in person and we can not predict when or if it will be safe to do so in the future.

We also have no way of knowing whether events will ever go back to "normal". Most of these badges are given out at conferences that our Marketing team goes to. There's at least two factors there that are unknown - will there be conferences? Will the Marketing team go to those conferences?

Who knows?

This is quite possibly the least important thing for anyone to be worried about right now.

If it's safe and if there's conferences and if the company wants to spend the money to send people to them, it's likely that there will still be ways to get the badge, sure... but me saying that doesn't mean I can see the future.

Comment: The way I read the discussion is that there has only been one known event in which this badge was awarded, and then the hype engine around getting people together in person lost most of its steam around 2019, and didn't really have that much of an international presence in 2018 compared to a North American presence.  There was also [timely feedback given](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335506/1079354) on making these events more virtual before...virtual events started becoming the only real way to have them, which might be worth revisiting.

Comment: Otherwise, there's not a lot of a point of having a badge that you simply can't get because of external, real-world factors outside of everyone's control, unlike the other badges (of which there was *also* [timely feedback on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335501/1079354)).

Comment: My understanding is that we were regularly giving them out at conferences and that sort of event as well as on sites for in-person events (Ru.SO and Ja.SO both have had events where the badge was given out)... But I don't really follow the argument that retiring it *now* is in any way necessary. I understand the push for virtual but I don't see the tie-in to this specific badge. If there's some interest in a "probably not a robot" badge for virtual stuff... fine... but that's not what this question is asking for.

Comment: The thing is, hosting events, whether in person or virtual is not something we've ever really done and we have no "prior art", if you will, on doing them. They're also extremely expensive and require many people hours to plan and build. We don't have the people or the expertise to do anything of that sort, we mostly just do informal sessions with mods from time to time and we have done sessions in the past on MSE, that Philippe has hinted at starting up again. But in most cases, we're not hosting the events, we're just going to a conference to advertise products.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  So your point about this being dependent on the future of conferences given the pandemic makes a lot more sense now.  Still brings up the point of the constraints on a real-life badge, though...

Comment: Sure. And I understand. Heck, I've been to our office twice and I still don't have the badge. :D I'd hope I'm not a robot at this point but... who knows. ;) I understand that there's people who want a chance to collect all the badges and that's a lot of fun. Maybe there should be something different than a badge - a different class of achievements that are situational rather than based on site participation directly... more "fun" stuff... but we don't really have that concept as of yet.

Comment: @Catija https://www.linkedin.com/posts/nicholas-morgan12345_get-over-to-the-stack-overflow-stand-at-cloud-activity-6904724871184809984-Ohyb

Comment: I just noticed today that a user was awarded the badge on May 30 of this year. Has SE started up the events again, or was it a reward for a long-ago event where they initially forgot to issue the badge? (The past events list shows no events since early 2020, so if the former, why is it not listed on the events page?)

Answer (score 18):

The badge specifically refers to in person meetings. Perhaps you could suggest a different one for virtual meetings, but that would be different; "Not a Deep Fake" for example?

Clearly there are issues with meeting in person right now, so it should hopefully be obvious why there haven't been any in the past year.

I mean, Vegas isn't even fully open... There are no fans at basketball games. We still have a ways to go, and on top of that Stack Overflow doesn't exactly derive any revenue from in person events. I would assume we don't see any in person until 2022 unfortunately, with regards to low priority conventions.

Comment: I think instead of making a new badge an exception should be made with the Not a Robot badge.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody knows...

And I don't think that somebody is planning a meeting right now. (But it would certainly be a nice idea, so we definitely should not forget it.)

Comment: This should've been a comment.

Comment: @Adriaan the comments are full, highly doubt anyone would notice it.

Comment: Although the line between answers and comments in meta is very blurry.  I think this is an answer...

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, the brevity definitely feels like a comment. But on the other hand I think this answers the question to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Adriaan I agree with Trilarion here, this is possibly the *only* answer to this question, as literally no humans on Earth know whether or not there will be other events to gain the Not a Robot badge.

Comment: @Adriaan, short, sometimes one line, Answers are allowed on other Stack if they actually answer the Q, like this one does. They are rare, sure, but this A definitely works for this Q.