# How did a user earn the Not a Robot badge earlier this year despite no events planned since the pandemic?

Tags: support, badges, not-a-robot-badge

For context: the "Not a Robot" badge is awarded to users who meet with a Stack Exchange employee at an organized meetup.

Per my [prior post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405839/2157772), since the beginning of the COVID-19 pandemic in March 2020, there have been no events for users to earn the badge, and for more than two years, there were no awards of the badge.

However, I noticed that on May 30 of this year, the badge [got its first award since then](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot).

The [page listing planned events to earn the Not a Robot badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) has always stated that no events were planned ever since the pandemic began, and never changed to list an actual event. The [list of past events](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past) says that no events took place since the pandemic (the last couple entries are for those in early 2020 that were cancelled).

If there were no events for users to earn the badge this year, why was the badge awarded on May 30? Is it a case where the user attended an event long ago and the team forgot to award the badge at the time? Or is it that the badge was originally awarded to a profile whose account was merged into one without it, as what happens with [users who earn the long-retired Analytical badge today](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical)? (Or are there "secret" events that aren't published on the page that the user participated in?)

Comment: I'm starting to think that this badge has a lot more baggage than it's actually worth.  It'd be kinda awkward if someone staff said, "Oh yeah, a Stack Overflow rep was at X conference on Y1 day to Y2 day, and this person walked up to us and provided us the claim check we needed to get them the badge."  Without communicating it to a lot more people, then the chance/opportunity to actually earn it is overlooked.  [Maybe this person had it right all along](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335501/1079354); *maybe* these badges should be limited to site participation only.

Comment: SE staff isn't locked up, right? You might actually run into them at a 7-Eleven ...

Comment: Can't be that hard to earn. Freaking community has the badge.

Comment: @rene The badge criteria state it has to be an event with at least 50 attendees.

Comment: What the badge states, and how the badge is awarded, don't necessarily align when it is more or less a manually awarded badge.

Comment: @user4581301 That was an experiment by a developer to see how long it would take for users to notice. In other words, a prank.

Comment: The experimental result was, "Not long."

Comment: The [main list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188733#188733) says *"As a result of the COVID-19 pandemic, the badge is de facto retired"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was the one who edited that information in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. We (I) forgot to award the badge. Kind of.

There is an ambiguity in the way we award the Not A Robot badge. Particularly, when a user gets the badge on one of our international sites, we do not say anything if they should get this badge on another site or even network wide. While, I think, we still do not have a clear answer, we talked among the CMs about this particular case and decided to award the badge.

Comment: They took part in [one of the two events organized in 2017](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past) on the Spanish SO site where they also have the badge, right? If so, if the event took place in 2017, why was the badge not awarded until two weeks prior to them earning it here? If not, which other "secret" event did they take part in?

Comment: @gparyani It is not a secret at all! :) I think there were some events prior the ones on the list. There was no badge at that time. The user contacted us recently and we did the thing.

Comment: What in the name of utterly unfair is this??  Someone showed up to an event even well before this badge was an idea and then they still get it?? Y'all need to give me credit for when I went to the Stack Overflow event in Downtown Denver in circa 2012 for which I still have the t-shirt for, or simply *not* award badges for past events under ***any*** circumstances.