# The Stack Overflow events page only include events until 2020. Besides COVID-19, what else I am missing?

Tags: discussion, badges, not-a-robot-badge, events

The not-a-robot badge has a link pointing to the Stack Overflow Events, which have two views, current and past events -> https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events. No events are listed for 2023, even though there was a big event this summer, WeAreDevelopers Conference.

From the Meta Stack Exchange post

> We wanted to let everyone know that Stack Overflow will be at [WeAreDevelopers World Congress](https://www.wearedevelopers.com/world-congress) in Berlin, Germany on July 27 and 28!

Is this page obsolete?

This is not a duplicate of [Will there be any future events for users to earn the Not a Robot badge, or is the badge retired?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405839/1595451). That question was posted in 2021. [Catija](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4548692/catija), who was part of the CM Team then, answered that they didn't know if there would be more events because of the level of uncertainty at that time.

Is there any possibility of earning the [not-a-robot] badge in the following months?

Reference

- [Stack Overflow at WeAreDevelopers World Congress in Berlin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391338/289691) asked Jul 17 at 20:10.

Related

- [Revive the Not a Robot badge on other sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374214/289691) asked Dec 18, 2021 at 10:52.
- [How did a user earn the Not a Robot badge earlier this year despite no events planned since the pandemic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420127/1595451) asked Aug 29, 2022 at 20:04.

Comment: With two exceptions, [all the badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) were awarded pre-COVID. I suspect those two that were awarded since are the result of merging profiles, which causes badges to be re-awarded.