# Enhanced heuristics for moderation: where is our line?

Tags: discussion, moderation

There are lots of methods you can use to semi-automate your moderation activity on Stack Overflow, it ranges all the way from review queue hotkeys to having an automated bot cast flags in your name.

We're mostly programmers here, and above all we tend towards automating things. Between the vast array of moderation automation available right now, you could conceivably automate so much of near-everything you can do with your privileges that it starts to become somewhat scary to me.

Between all this, and between the discussions about it that keep popping up, is there a line we draw for these? **Is anything that results in sufficient quality of moderation actions taken okay?**

Traditionally, the opinions on these discussions vary wildly, so ideally I'm looking for some sort of concrete guidance here.

If not, where do we draw the line on self-automating moderation?

Comment: I know that SE is not happy of bot's casting flags automatically (they want manually review) and that you should avoid screen scraping and instead use the open api

Comment: for all it needs a human to judge content before an action is executed.

Comment: Related: [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/3853934)

Comment: The crux of this question is: what counts as "sufficient quality"?

Comment: and another thing that is always appriecated, make your application **public**, [stackapp](http://stackapps.com/) is a good place to post what you are doing

Answer (score 36):

How well do you trust these heuristics? In particular, what's their false positive rate?

The reason moderators tend to caution against automated actions without any user oversight is that even in the best cases they tend to have way too many false positives. The heuristics that SE itself applied to find low quality posts to send into review ended up tagging many good posts as being bad, to the point where it was cluttering up review. Even the spam-detecting Smoke Detector frequently identifies non-spam posts due to some unfortunate combination of keywords or the like. Most people aren't that careful with their automation, running simple queries for common phrases.

Don't just use automation to shift the burden to moderators. We'd like for you to meet us halfway and not blindly flag things based on queries, etc. Inundating us (or the review queues) with flags on items we don't need to act on or that are full of false positives can slow down the whole process and can distract from more urgent matters.

Because of the high rate of false positives, and the potential consequences for misidentified posts, I prefer to have human oversight on at least the last step before action is taken.

I have little problem with "augmented" moderation combining some form of automation with human decision-making. Automating the identification of potentially problematic posts can be extremely useful, as can userscripts to speed up common human-initiated tasks. However, be aware that any close vote or flag that you cast via your automated system is still attached to your account, and you're responsible for it.

I think there's a lot of potential in some of the machine learning that people have been experimenting with, but the performance isn't there yet to trust them for many tasks. It's definitely an area worth exploring, and something I have my eye on.

Comment: So you are fine with the bots sending us the data and a pair of human eyes taking a good look at it and flagging it after that?

Comment: _"Even the best heuristics have way too high false positive rates"_ thats actually not always the case. Andy's bot is one of the instances where he successfully taught a bot to flag better then the vast, vast vast majority of users.

Comment: @Magisch - That's a fairly low-stakes area, though. Whether or not a "thank you" comment is removed isn't exactly something I worry about. It was already an area where 95% of flags by people on these comments were accepted. Where the site really needs help is in identifying spam, terrible questions, non-answers, and abusive behavior, and doing so quickly. The consequences of false positives there can be more significant, and all of the attempts I've seen have far too many false positives to be blindly trusted. There's more work that needs to be done.

Comment: @BradLarson  I'd go further: if a bot is generating lots of flags for a "thank you" comment, then that's lots of flags for a moderator to review - so they aren't spending time deleting spam etc.

Answer (score 10):

Do what you like, but **remember: everything is still getting done in your name.**

If you want to write a bot using stupidly advanced AI and machine learning techniques that automates literally all of your moderation activity, *awesome*, go do it. But it's still gotta use *your* account to vote, or flag, or comment, or whatever else it does.

If it does those things well - close votes the right things, flags helpfully, comments constructively, etc, then it's a bonus for you because your account accumulates all those good numbers.

If it does those things badly, you're still equally responsible for it; if it gets your account review-banned, there's no recourse just because *"I was testing a bot!"* Your account gets the bonuses, but your account also takes the consequences of any misguided actions your automations perform - up to, and including, suspension and/or account destruction if necessary.

Comment: I disagree with your first words already. Do **not** do what you like, you could create a whole bunch of work for moderators that could have been avoided.

Comment: @Stijn If you do that, you'll quickly find yourself banned from said activity. That was my point - yeah, in reality of course you shouldn't do *whatever* you want, but if you did it would either go fine or you'd get a ban.

Comment: The point I try to make is that you can not only hurt yourself with it, you can also "hurt" moderators if they have do do cleanup.

Comment: Would it preferable for bots having automated moderation capibility to run under the account of their "owner" instead of a dedicated account?

Comment: @Stijn Trust me: if a moderator has to spend any significant time cleaning up after you, they'll also do something to stop that happening again.

Comment: @Tunaki Debatable. Ideally, I'd say yes - it's not always possible (for example, I shouldn't run chatbots under my own account because it's a mod account) - but where it is possible, running under the owner account allows aggregation of stats and bans.

Comment: @Tunaki, The [automated flagging I do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically) is run under my account for exactly the reasons ArtOfCode lists here. It's my responsibility to test and train the system. If I am not comfortable using it under my name, I shouldn't be flagging things automatically. I spent *a lot* of time getting things right and even more time fine tuning it since it went live and since I made my initial post. Even with automation, I have to monitor it to ensure it doesn't go crazy, or that some policy didn't change.

Comment: @Stijn "you can also 'hurt' moderators if they have **do do** clean up", rofl, but don't moderators have do do clean up all the time?