# Are comment flags handled on the version at the time of flagging or the current version?

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags

I recently had a comment flag declined, I believe incorrectly. The user lashed out against me after I pointed out that his answer didn't solve the question OP asked. I flagged it as unfriendly/unkind, and informed the user that I was done responding due to his personal attack.

The situation (I think) comes down to one thing — **are comment flags** (or all, if it's the same for posts) **displayed to moderators as they existed at the time of the flag, or as they currently exist?** I know moderators are capable of viewing a comment's edit history, but presumably wouldn't unless they had a reason to (which a normal flag certainly isn't).

Comment: Just managed to take a look at the flags, I didn't handle that in particular, and Bhargav's answer sums it up well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The comment flags are displayed as they currently exist. This has always been the case, [and has troubled users in the past too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/4099593).

The usual route that I used to follow in order to get over this problem, was to just wait for a full 5 minutes and then flag. If the rude content is still present, use the unfriendly or the rude flags based on the situation. If the comment has been edited, add a custom comment flag telling that the user was being rude, and the moderators will look into the history.

(I would certainly not recommend going with a custom flag at the start itself, as the unfriendly flag does have other built in signaling mechanisms, which should ideally kick in when a user is being rude. Using a custom flag prevents this.)

Comment: Under "Comments that were flagged but declined" @RyanfaeScotland

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I can save you the read -- I had the same issue with 7 or 8 flags that went unhandled for a long time, and then after a mod election the mod flag queue got handled quickly, including my long-standing flags. Only problem was, my flags were all obsolete for various reasons at that time (e.g. posts were edited or deleted), leading to declination and thus a flag ban where otherwise I wouldn't have received one. That's one way flags being 'current' can be problematic.